# Why the minimum of 5 seconds between comment votes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, voting, rate-limiting

[image: "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds." - Rageface]

I often times will read through a string of comments, evaluating how I feel about them as a collection, and then go back through and sequentially up-vote the ones I decided I agree with.

The problem is, I can do this *much faster* than once per 5 seconds. It is exceedingly frustrating to have to sit and count to 5 before up-voting the next comment *that I already read and evaluated*.

Can we lower this to something like 500 ms?

**The other thing to remember is that *deleting* a comment counts as a "vote".**

Comment: Comments are second-class citizens. The number of up-votes on it should not matter, only the questions and answers. This delay makes you stop and think, about the content of the comment and if you should even bother.

Comment: cross site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds

Comment: All actions on the site are rate limited. Comment votes are no exception.

Comment: @gunr2171 My whole point was that I already did stop and think.

Comment: Related: [Can we get x comment votes per x minutes rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382)

Comment: As reference, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/168244).

Comment: A similar example (that I run into), is someone writes a similar (but better) comment then I do. So, I delete mine and then I have to wait five seconds to vote on theirs.

Comment: Just enough time to wipe that tear from your eye, take a deep breath and then rejoice in the fact that there is an excellent comment to upvote.

Comment: @Bart Too true, or I could just upvote their comment. And then wait the five seconds with my shame visible to all.

Comment: I keep running into this and find myself counting off the seconds. I tend to read the comments, sort the chafe from the wheat, and then do to the voting, if any will be done. Thus I've already taken all the time I need and do not require a delay. And some of us have had training to process content very quickly and react on it. Just a few years ago myself I took a speed reading course and managed to read the entire novel **War and Peace** in just twenty minutes. It involves Russia.

Comment: [I made a feature request to change the way we interact with comment votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230706/153542).

Answer (score 34):

If treated in the general StackExchange context, this is a duplicate of prior discussions. However, I think the issue has special implications for StackOverflow, appropriate for discussion in the shiny new Meta StackOverflow. I am hoping the "status-declined" is a reflex reaction in the general StackExchange context, based on prior discussions, and can be reconsidered taking into account StackOverflow-specific issues.

Many comments in StackOverflow are quite technical. A comment-on-comment may change my opinion of the original comment by introducing points or references to materials I had not considered. I prefer to base my voting not just on my own prior knowledge, but also on what I learn from the combined wisdom of everyone who has already written on the question.

Often, at the end of reading the comments I identify two or more comments that are particularly useful, technically accurate, and well written. At that point I have finished with the set of comments except for possibly voting. I would really like to be able to just upvote those comments and then go on to the next thing. I know 5 seconds is not long, but in user interface terms it is long enough to be a noticeable distraction and annoyance.

Please reconsider the 5 second delay in the specific context of the comment sequences that arise in StackOverflow, and the strategies that some StackOverflow contributors, myself included, would like to apply to those comment sequences.

**As a specific suggestion, change it to no more than 12 upvotes per minute.** That would be just as effective for throttling unconsidered or automatic voting. A user following my strategy will have spent over a minute reading and thinking about a set of comments. They will have 12 immediately available votes at that point.

Comment: I'm neutral here, but it's worth noting that your '12 per minute' approach flies completely in the face of [Jeff's initial motivation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10141/200582) for the upvote throttling, which is to reduce the total amount that people upvote by making upvoting irritating, thereby ensuring that only the truly best comments in long comment threads get upvoted, thereby making the comment score filter more consistently effective. 12 upvotes is enough to upvote *every* correct and potentially useful comment in most threads, which is exactly what Jeff wanted to avoid.

Comment: @MarkAmery One could reduce the maximum rate, and still get the major benefit. I think comment upvoting is very important and beneficial, at least in StackOverflow, because it gives the benefit of more readers' opinions much more compactly than writing comments of their own. I'm a touch typist, and sometimes tempted by the voting limit to just type a comment repeating, in my own words, the comments I agree with.

Comment: I sympathise and sometimes find myself in the same position. The difficulty is that comment upvotes serve two purposes - they signal users' agreement with a comment, and they determine which comments in long threads should be shown in the filtered view before showing more comments. Optimising for the former purpose, we'd want SE to remove the rate limit completely. Optimising for the *latter*, we'd instead want something like an all-time per-post restriction to two comment upvotes that could be moved around. The current system is an awkward compromise between two objectives.

Comment: By the way, it occurs to me that The Establishment's refusal to implement comment downvoting - which is another form of compactly conveying opinions without needing to type a comment - is relevant here. It seems that The Establishment does not value the information conveyed by comment votes.

Comment: "The Establishment" has long indicated they consider comments as secondary. The idea here is to NOT be a forum that requires extensive reading to parse out useful information.

Comment: @Chris I am now totally confused. Is the 5 second rule because we should think about comment votes, or because we should not think about them? Either way, it is a silly waste of contributor time, and should be eliminated or replaced with something more sensible, but I would like to know the intent.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The question of should or should not think about comment upvotes is hearsay, based on what someone thought they saw Jeff say "somewhere". The concept that comments are secondary items, subject to removal without notice and without community input is the bottom line. There won't be any downvoting comments, and changes to make comment voting "better", none of it, because comments are window dressing. They are regarded as a necessary evil, a byproduct of the web platform. The questions and the answers are the focus. I am not making value statements, just observations.

Comment: @Chris I understand, but I still feel contributors should try to make the site better, by calling attention to silliness in its user interface. In practice, it is often difficult, for the more interesting StackOverflow questions, to go straight to a correct answer without finding out more about the constraints etc. Similarly, an answer might be almost right, but need a clarification that is too much of a change to be a good edit.

Answer (score 8):

The limitation has now been lifted, see [Can we get x comment votes per y minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-y-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds), where Jarrod responded with:

> Yeah, this throttle doesn't make much sense any longer, so it will be removed in the next build.
>
> You still have a combined 30 upvotes and deletes per day, though.