# Meta hasn't changed at all

Tags: discussion, meta

Yesterday I've received the [following reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit?noredirect=1#comment2774_251232):

> **Meta StackExchange actually recommends that most questions, even ones that are network-wide, are asked on child metas first.** Then, if it makes sense for them to be moved, the OP can move up to Meta.SE. So while this wouldn't be off-topic at MSE, I don't think it's off-topic here, either.

And I was astonished. So I checked my last flags that I've sent to the moderators for migration (from meta.SO to meta.SE) and apparently they [have all been rejected](http://oi59.tinypic.com/3308zs7.jpg). Specifically [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251264/daily-reputation-cap) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251263/what-happens-to-the-authors-reputation-when-you-flag-his-work).

I understand the whole fuss of having a "real meta stackoverflow", but a part from the technicalities (reputation system changes), meta stackoverflow is exactly the same as before. Question that should be on meta.SE are being posted on meta.SO. Not only that but it seems like moderators are *recommending* this behavior.

I'll try to explain to you why, in my honest opinion, this is just plain silly.

#### Cross site duplicates

The huge and main problem I can see is cross-site duplicated. Not only cross-site duplicated between the "old meta.SO" and the "new meta.SO", but also between metas of every other website. If this kind of behavior is recommended on every meta website, how many "Should I comment or just downvote?" do we really need?

Duplicates in general are a huge problem, and I think we all know the reasons for that: we are splitting answers in difference places, making them harder to retrieve.

Just as a clear example of what this causes, I'll list few cross site duplicates that I've just noticed:

- [Comments can't contain that content - "What have you tried?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251309/comments-cant-contain-that-content-what-have-you-tried)

  - ["What have you tried" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)
- [Should I comment or just downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251299/should-i-comment-or-just-downvote)

  - [How should I handle possible revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106704/how-should-i-handle-possible-revenge-downvotes)
- [Why the minimum of 5 seconds between comment votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250174/why-the-minimum-of-5-seconds-between-comment-votes)

  - [Allow more than 1 comment upvote in 5 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds)
- [Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250129/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-suggested-edit)

  - [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)
- [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie on Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in)

  - [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

These are just the first five top questions in the main page stream right now, I'm sure you can find *many* more since the first day of the new meta.SO.

#### meta.SE is just useless

If "network questions" are generally accepted and "dealt with" on "local" sites, then what do we even have meta.SE for?

#### This question has already an answer somewhere

That's right. This question is a cross-site duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229870/could-we-allow-child-meta-questions-to-be-closed-as-duplicates-of-meta-se-ones/229875#229875) about cross-site duplicates.

If moderators will take this personally and move it there and close it as a duplicate, then, why not all the others as well?

#### My answer to the "accepted answer"

> For the amount of support we could feasibly build into this, we're not really getting much in return beyond what we get by just posting an answer with a link in it. In fact, we're getting less than that, because with an answer we at least get the chance of offering site-specific guidance in addition to linking in the network-global discussion.

Then why even beginning this whole fuss? Meta.SO was well known to be the center of meta stackexchange-related questions. It never generated any problem at all.

The only problem was that it wasn't symmetrical with the other websites. So what? Who cared? I read that as "we wanted this huge change for no practical reasons, but we are not doing it right because it would require too much effort" (please take that with an happy tone) (don't ban me please :)) (I love you Jeff).

> You see where I'm going with this? Even though it's a network-wide feature, the actual guidance for interacting with it must necessarily be customized to some extent per-site. There are a lot of questions like that...

I see where you are going with this. Those are clearly corner cases (not in the sense they don't happen many times, but in the sense that they are *too localized*), and it really doesn't matter where they are dealt with because it won't likely be helpful to anyone else.

The kind of questions you just mentioned are not the ones that would benefit from rethinking this. Take the 5 example above as an example of real SE specific questions.

---

#### More duplicates as we speak

Given the popularity of the question, I'll add 22 more examples of the problem:

- [How should I flag a literal plagiarism of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251587/how-should-i-flag-a-literal-plagiarism-of-a-question)

  - [Should I flag plagiarism for moderator attention?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122056/should-i-flag-plagiarism-for-moderator-attention)
- [When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism)

  - [Reviewing Edits - what counts as plagiarism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114312/reviewing-edits-what-counts-as-plagiarism)
- [Suspension till 2027](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027)

  - [Why would a user be suspended for almost 7 years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134409/why-would-a-user-be-suspended-for-almost-7-years/134432#134432)
- [Questions that have more upvotes than views](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251286/questions-that-have-more-upvotes-than-views)

  - [Views indicator inaccurate, shows one views on question with two close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote)
- ["Mortarboard" continues to be awarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251249/mortarboard-continues-to-be-awarded)

  - [Bad notification for the Mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181831/bad-notification-for-the-mortarboard-badge)
- [Why does downvoting an answer cost reputation while questions not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not)

  - [Should downvotes on questions be "free"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)
- [Can I block/hide activity of a user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251833/can-i-block-hide-activity-from-a-user)

  - [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)
- [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

  - [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)
- [Why can't I accept an answer in the first 15 minutes after asking the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250132/493122)

  - [Allow me to accept an answer immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately)
- [My question never got answered, what can I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251422/my-question-never-got-answered-what-can-i-do)

  - [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)
- [How should accepted link-only answers be handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled)

  - [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)
- [How to respond to late answers that are duplicates of accepted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250883/how-to-respond-to-late-answers-that-are-duplicates-of-accepted-answers)

  - [Duplicate answer as late answer from new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171494/duplicate-answer-as-late-answer-from-new-user)
  - [What is the policy on very late exact duplicate answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150154/what-is-the-policy-on-very-late-exact-duplicate-answers)
- [How are flag limits calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251621/how-are-flag-limits-calculated)

  - [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)
- [Unable to comment as a new member - what about unclear questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250977/unable-to-comment-as-a-new-member-what-about-unclear-questions)

  - [New users can't ask for clarifications except as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers)
  - [What's the justification for the commenting reputation requirement?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66140/whats-the-justification-for-the-commenting-reputation-requirement)
- [What does +0 bounty earned stand for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251973/what-does-0-bounty-earned-stand-for)

  - [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
- [Should we downvote, flag or leave comments on Spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252362/should-we-downvote-flag-or-leave-comments-on-spam)

  - [Recent Mass Football Spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam)
- [How should questions containing proprietary code be handled when OP asks for deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254493/how-should-questions-containing-proprietary-code-be-handled-when-op-asks-for-del#comment19248_254493)

  - [Is it ok to use Stack Overflow to ask questions about a proprietary framework?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194686/is-it-ok-to-use-stack-overflow-to-ask-questions-about-a-proprietary-framework)
  - [Questions with proprietary or confidential information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information)
  - [How should you ask questions that involve proprietary data/code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140847/how-should-you-ask-questions-that-involve-proprietary-data-code)
- ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site?cb=1)

  - [Is correcting a common misspelling too minor an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147946/is-correcting-a-common-misspelling-too-minor-an-edit)
  - [Why can suggested edits be "too minor"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/why-can-suggested-edits-be-too-minor)
- [Is it OK to downvote questions because of bad grammar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar)

  - [Should others downvote my posts for "grammatical" reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/should-others-downvote-my-posts-for-grammatical-reasons)
- [What do I do when I run out of flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255343/what-do-i-do-when-i-run-out-of-flags?cb=1)

  - [What to do if I run out of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143510/what-to-do-if-i-run-out-of-flags)
- [How should we handle edits adding unnecessary `code` tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256333/how-should-we-handle-edits-adding-unnecessary-code-tags)

  - [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)
  - [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/152998)
- [Why is the accepted answer not on top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261634/why-is-the-accepted-answer-not-on-top?cb=1)

  - [Accepted Answer not on top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212196/accepted-answer-not-on-top)
  - [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
  - [Accepting own's answer does not move it to the top of the answers list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128421/accepting-owns-answer-does-not-move-it-to-the-top-of-the-answers-list)
  - [Accepted answers don't float "on top"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/accepted-answers-dont-float-on-top)

All the questions linked above have an high score at the time of posting. I'm ignoring cross-site duplicates with `< 5` score points.

Comment: As for duplicates, that also applies to extended help, I feel. [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/) vs, er, [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @Shog9, trying to ping him because it feels wrong to "talk" behind his back.

Comment: Imagine if you could just ping anybody from any post, _en masse_, and how annoying that would be! Lol. @Vlad

Comment: You haven't actually identified the specific problem of "cross-site duplicates". You wrote *"Duplicates in general are a huge problem, and I think we all know the reasons for that: we are splitting answers in difference websites,"*, that "we are splitting answers in different websites" isn't a reason that it's bad, it's just a restatement of what it is. So the same help question is on more than one site. What is the *actual* problem with that? The network sites are independent of each other and are self-contained. It's OK if there's a "Should I comment or just downvote" on each one.

Comment: @JasonC If I understand the post correctly, Jeffery is basically saying that everyone is still using the new MSO like the old MSO, and so the new MSE is not getting the attention it should... So MSE is useless and MSO hasn't actually changed (except now you only get rep on MSE). Not saying I agree with this or not... I haven't spent enough time on the two new sites to have an opinion. Just trying to clarify my understanding of the OP.

Comment: so where would you ask a question about whether a question should be asked on MSO or MSE?

Comment: @david.pfx, in the OP's opinion (and mine) on MSE. MSE is for common concerns; MSO is for SO-specific ones.

Comment: Is "What have you tried?" banned on all sites, or just Stack Overflow?  That was a problem specific to SO, so I think it belongs here, not on Meta.SE.  They're still in the process of migrating questions from Meta.SE back to here, so that cross-site duplicate should be fixed.

Comment: What is the actual flag and rejection message you have got? According to the blog, moving to meta.se should definitely not rely on the asker. The guy whom you have quoted is not a moderator. There's still a difference between closing (happened in the linked post, should not have IMO) and migration (should be granted if valid)

Comment: Disturbing if true. It's as if the easy way is being taken instead of the necessary way.

Comment: "This question is a cross-site duplicate of this question about cross-site duplicates." So... meta.

Comment: @JanDvorak, see [here](http://oi59.tinypic.com/3308zs7.jpg).

Comment: Maybe it's because the "don't migrate crap" rule kicks in? If so, then this might need some more dev attention...

Comment: +1 (although it does come across as a bit of a rant), but I don't think anything will change - from the multitude of cross-site duplication and site scope discussion I've seen, the SE team officially doesn't seem to have a problem with the fact that two identical questions can be on topic on two different sites and exist there concurrently (as long as the same person didn't ask it, at around the same time, which seems very inconsistent).

Comment: I'm the guy who posted the comment that the OP disagrees with. I got the idea from a comment by @Shog9 on the main "Split the Metas" thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014#comment750910_228903 I haven't seen the idea voiced in many other places, though, so I may have ran with it too quickly...

Comment: Duplication is bad, m'kay?

Comment: FWIW, you could've posted a comment with a link to this on that answer you're quoting here. Y'know, if you wanted to be polite about it.

Comment: @Shog9, It stupidly didn't cross my mind. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries; you got some good answers, glad you posted this.

Comment: @Jeffery what part of "answering on meta" and "talking about shog behind his back" go together? One does not simply sneak something by shog by posting it on meta. That's like sneaking bacon by me by craftily putting it on my hamburger. I will notice and love the bacon, every time.

Comment: Man (or woman), you got my upvote just for that long amusing list...

Comment: @560648 does this ping anyone?

Comment: @Yakk It pings me

Comment: Wait a sec... Isn't this Meta-Meta-StackExchange, not Meta-StackOverflow? Please stop before my mind is blown :)

Answer (score 56):

Can we drop the cross-site angst here? MSO is the opinion-cauldron of *this one unique community*. MSE over there is a far-away place where they have to think about all the different communities and how bugs and features will affect all of the many sites. But here, we can and *should* think insular thoughts.

The regulars here are still trying to think with a central government (MSE) mindset and it is easy to forget that there may be thousands of Stack Overflow denizens here that have their *own* thoughts on the issues and whom do not have a network-wide perspective. They have an up close and personal view of how *Stack Overflow* works and ideas of how it *should* work, and their voices **have** to be heard here. Not shunted away and told they need to go post on a far-away centralised authority that is MSE.

So we **do things here** and find a unique Stack Overflow voice. Hopefully MSE will then finally find its own voice. **And in the meantime there will be many echoes of MSE here on MSO**. That's because we get to have the classics out of the way early. Yes, we'll have a local 'downvotes suxors, make them comment!' post. And it'll sound a lot like the MSE versions of yore. We'll get those out if the way and in a few weeks time we'll have a well-primed MSO Q&A repository for those things and focus on the **local** voice that **will** emerge from that.

If we sent each and every old-hat feature request and bug report back to MSE instead we'll *never* find a unique voice and MSE will *still* be dominated by the Stack Overflow crowd (which is the biggest and loudest of the network).

It's a wild and exciting time. Sit back, enjoy the ride!

Comment: So you're saying we're going to inevitably waste the next few weeks or months rehashing discussions that were already entertained long ago? And that this should be fine? Wow that seems like a good use of time

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Who says you have to do anything? Flagging everything we once discussed on MSE is *not* going to be taking time, is it? And those discussions will come back here *over* and *over* and *over* again and we won't even be able to close them as dupes.

Comment: Who says I have to do anything? Not me personally no but since your answer pertains to every Meta contributor, your question can be just as meaningfully reformed to "who says anyone has to do anything?" and the answer to that is quite obvious, because if nobody did anything, then there would be no activity on MSO. So, I'm not really quite sure what you're getting at.

Comment: This is a new, empty Meta, of course there is going to be a lot of work filling it. Just like any new meta on new beta sites, only some of the MSE regulars have a lot of experience with the classics. *There are not that many 'classics'* though. And no, I don't think that that is a waste of time, either.

Comment: Hurray pointless content duplication

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: we'll have to agree to disagree on that. And the content on MSE is CC-licensed. Copy it over here if you feel it'll improve MSO.

Comment: I think I've been quite clear that I don't feel copying it will improve anything ;p

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm bit slow but I don't understand from your answer nothing more than "we don't really know what to do now". How come this got so many upvotes? :0

Comment: @BartoszKP: We *do* know what to do now. We keep posts here, not migrate the crap out of everything telling everyone that they shouldn't be using their local Meta because there is a central authority with all the answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But some (lots of them?) posts already have been migrated - what was the point of that then? I don't get this, but all right - I won't repeat what Lightness already wrote above. We can agree to disagree :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: those were posts that were now a) off-topic on Meta SE and b) still actionable (still relevant). The type of posts that we are discussing here are not off-topic on Meta SE, but not off-topic *here* either.

Comment: I agree that I don't get the point of duplicate content. It's only going to amplify the bikeshedding.

Comment: @Romoku: the point is that it won't be duplicate, not exactly. Stack Overflow has a unique community, a unique perspective, and unique problems. We cannot ever discover that uniqueness if we shunt everything over to Meta.SE. And the regulars are (justifiably) fed up with the unresearched rehashings of certain feature requests, sure. We'll have to bite that bullet and get those over with.

Comment: Why have a Meta.SE then? If every question is to be addresses everywhere then Meta.SE questions might as well be integrated into every Meta so it is visible globally.

Comment: @Romoku: That's to be discovered still! Meta.SE is the central government. I see it as the place where the opinions from various different child Meta sites is *aggregated*. Meta.SE *right now* is mostly Stack Overflow people hashing things out, and that's not right either.

Comment: As a software developer I'm quite shocked to see that duplication is accepted and even welcomed here. Haven't we learnt anything from our profession?

Comment: This is the correct answer. If programmers were all that strict about avoiding duplication, we'd all still be using Mosaic, @Karoly: sometimes, you need to re-invent a few wheels before you find one that rolls the way you want it to.

Comment: @Shog9: looks like you guys are experimenting with a rectangular one at the moment ;)

Comment: We're working our way up from a bare axle.

Comment: Ahem, regarding ["downvotes suxors, make them comment!" posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814)...

Answer (score 50):

You are dealing with four years of ingrained culture, where meta.so was always the "network hub".

That kind of culture does not change overnight. It is unreasonable to expect it to change in a week. Or even a year!

It is a process.

Over time meta.so will acclimate to its new role as a meta for Stack Overflow, THE SITE, not the whole engine. This will take extra diligence from the moderators here and leading members of the community. That means you.

(And yes, it is absolutely more correct for the only people who have rep here to be those that legitimately participate on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: **In short** - based on what the SE team wants us to ask on child Meta's, MSO's scope kind of stays the same. **In long** - the SE team still recommends that we ask questions on MSO if we use SO, even if it's a network-wide problem, and I presume this will never change, as it seems they wish for us to behave similarly with regard to the more established child Meta's, unless the ultimate plan is to have these network-wide questions only exist on MSE, but [Tim doesn't seem to agree with that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251428/1711796). **In conclusion** - I think one of us misunderstood OP.

Comment: So is the idea that really solid, important, good questions asked on MSO about network-wide issues might be moved to MSE for discussion?  I too am a little confused on what MSE's purpose is at this point.

Comment: MSE is for things you don't really know where else to put, or perhaps for things where a broader audience is desired than just your child site.  But mostly it's for very little, is the point.  Almost everything should be on the child site metas.

Comment: @jeff-atwood OT: I thought you retained from the site finally ;), good to see you're still active!

Answer (score 28):

Don't worry about cross-site duplication. How many times did small groups of people have the *same* conversation about the Affordable Healthcare act while it was being scoped? Each town or small city on the map is afforded the opportunity to talk about how something is going to affect *them*, everyone else be damned.

If fifteen of our child meta sites are on fire and buzzing about the potential impact of certain changes we've announced, that's *much* more significant than fifteen up-votes on a couple of answers reiterating those concerns. By doing this, we're *increasing signal* - not noise. We're in a much better position to listen to what folks have to say from a perspective of individual communities.

I can't emphasize this enough - bucketing and organization of things has fallen *squarely* on our shoulders now, we get *paid* to do this so that you don't have to worry about it. As we figure out *how* we're going to go about this, we'll open the process more to the community. Until then, it's our problem - we welcome your input, but please appreciate that we've taken it off your shoulders.

All you have to do is participate. Give your thoughts regarding ideas, propose new ones, help out with the upkeep of the *main* sites. We're not going to tell folks they can't have a local discussion because congress is currently debating it; we're going to harvest the fruits of *all* discussions when it comes to taking everyone's thoughts into account.

[As pico points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251426/839601), it's still *very* early. Just relax and enjoy participating.

Comment: If (carefully chosen) Meta SE posts show up under Community Bulletin, possibly Hot Network Questions or somewhere else, I don't see why putting network-wide discussion there instead is worse. Having the same points brought up 15 times, and having to read it 15 times (the SE team will, as I read the answer), is downright inefficient. Your town/city similarity seems flawed - at best the highlights are collected locally and reiterated higher up, not collected by the higher ups. If you raised the point that MSE answers will accrue too many answers / comments, that might make more sense.

Comment: Does this mean that user's shouldn't voice their opinion in "congress" and instead stick to their localized communities? If a user would like to voice an opinion about a trending topic, does it now include posting that in both their local and now centralized venue?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, it does.  You don't see every politically active citizen speaking on the senate floor.  They discuss the issues locally with their representatives, who bring it up to the broader venues.

Comment: @Servy - While the insinuation is that it does, it actually does not mean that. Otherwise you wouldn't have the "active citizen" neither asking nor answering on meta SE. Coining these terms in a bureaucratic nature, while convenient, only adds obfuscation to the meta system.

Comment: This is having really silly side-effects though. At least, Meta.SO users should get a chance of discovering what's already there. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252290/meta-se-content-should-be-discoverable-in-meta-so-search

Comment: I found it very weird and wrong at first to have duplicates on both sites, only now I begin to see the reason. Still feels weird, but guess it's not so bad as I thought. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 11):

**Take a beer, chill. We are just having the launch party started.**

I mean seriously, Meta.SE is not even in orbit yet, it's just taken off.

So....

You don't force these changes overnight. The ideal world and idea, is that all network wide questions are asked, and magically migrated to Meta.SE. But this creates the following problems.

- Master Programmers who went into a cave in a secret mountain to train their Google-fu. Come back and post on meta.SO.
- NOOBS who don't even understand what meta is for, let alone Meta.SE.
- You may not want to migrate everything, reason being, you can't stop noobs from not searching Meta.SE, and posting a duplicate in Meta.SO. Leaving some in Meta.SO, give them an outlet.

([Searching in any meta site should include results from Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230105/searchings-in-any-meta-site-should-include-results-from-meta-se): an alternative idea to leaving certain crap unmigrated.)

So what are we going to treat the 100's of genuine voices that come in for now?.

- Hey, This is irrelevant, closing and migrating. NOW. CLOSE.
- Or, this is better in "meta.SE". But never mind, let's chill and talk it out, discuss it out. We can migrate it once everyone gets a better idea of you question or even as we conclude it.

I'm sure the above is kind of obvious?

- And lets face it Meta.SO has way more eyeballs, and people as of now then Meta.SE. People takes time to make that shift.
- And many ideas start off being site specific and eventually graduate network wide. An example would be the spoiler tag. Which started off from "Science Fiction & Fantasy"/gaming/codeGolf/etc requesting such a feature. And such ideas are a perfect example on starting out in site specific network, and gradually moving to network.

> This does not have a use in SO. But it has in "Science Fiction & Fantasy"/etc.... and is in use network wide

**So, is Meta.SE is useless?**

- Yes, it is now, sort of, it's an ideal; it's not fully made into reality. How about checking back in a year's time?
- Merging cross-site meta questions across the whole network is a huge task.
- Oh and the Stack Exchange answer you provided has its own answer too!

So yes, there will be lots of confusion and cross site duplicates now... Just chill, it's too early to judge if this is a hopeless attempt or not...

Take a beer, and chill.

Comment: Had too much beer lately. ;)

Comment: I thought the spoiler tag started on Science Fiction & Fantasy.

Comment: @TRiG i really cant recall which requested the feature first (gaming, or sci-fi&fantasy). Oh well added it in =P

Comment: The problem is, nobody knows what Meta.SE is the Meta site _for_. I believe we need a main SE site, so that Meta.SE will finally have a function. So, who will support my proposal for main.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to address the problem of cross site duplication.

Aside from other good points made: Some questions would have different answers for different communities.

Matter of fact, a single person may have different answers for the same question on different communities.

Examples:

- Welcominess towards new and possibly less than perfect content. I'm in the "Burn the suckage out" camp on SO, and in the "Can't we all be about 1000 times nicer?" camp on SFF, which is both significantly smaller - meaning we don't drown in crap - AND more "squishy" in subject area.
- Rep caps. I think they are fine on SO where there is always the next popular and great question to answer. They are significantly more annoying on SFF, again due to the size.
- Specific measurements required for various badges. Yes, again SO and SFF get different answers for me, based on sizes and volumes.
- Moderator behavior. Different site have different mod styles (Compare History to SFF to Skeptics) AND more importantly different moderation style needs (Compare Skeptics of SoftRec to SO).

Comment: +1 for Some questions would have different answers for different communities; a concept illustrated by http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/what-are-the-arguments-against-or-for-putting-application-logic-in-the-database/2467#2467 and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/what-are-the-arguments-against-or-for-putting-application-logic-in-the-database-l/71570#71570