# Copy-pasting the contents of another answer to the same question — with attribution

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I know about this question: [When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism)

The wording of my question is only slightly different, but I think it depicts a rather different situation:

**Is it ok to take material from another answer on the same question and re-use it <strike>with</strike> *without* modifications, but with attribution?**

This is what just happened to me: I see this:

> Q: How do I foo the bar?
>
> A1 (User X): Do this: [*somewhat helpful but overly complicated answer that misses the mark a little bit*]

I know there's a better answer, so I go ahead:

> A2 (Me): This is the way to do it: [*simple, correct, and tested answer*]

Then User X edits his answer to look like this (changes in **bold**):

> A1 (User X): Do this: [*somewhat helpful but overly complicated answer that misses the mark a little bit*] 
>  **Or, better and simpler, like @Me suggests: [*simple, correct, and tested answer, copy-pasted*]**

This peeved me. (Never mind that User X's answer was the one that got accepted [eyes rolling].)

I know that technically, it isn't plagiarism, because there is attribution. But seriously! Doing this seems to me completely absurd. Why on Earth. If everyone starts doing this, we'll end up with massive intra-question duplication, triplication, dodecaplication of information — and peeved users. So I'm thinking this should be discouraged.

- Is my peevishness misplaced? Or am I right in thinking that this is really unhelpful behaviour on the part of User X?
- If the latter, should I flag User X's post? How else should this be discouraged?

Comment: At least it's better than "[_their completely wrong answer_] But I guess you actually want: [_my simple, correct, and tested answer, copied without attribution_]", and theirs gets accepted without even correcting the wrong information.

Comment: How is this any different to one of your answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203173/fully-reference-a-worksheet-by-codename/25203351#25203351 - much of the original content was incorrect but edited and you have the answer accepted?

Comment: @ooo : It's different in the following way. I'm going to try to explain this as clearly as I can, but if I'm not being quite clear, don't hesitate to ask. I didn't ["*copy-paste the contents another answer to the same question — with attribution*"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution).

Comment: Without commenting on whether one should be copying large parts of an answer into one's own, I'd say that I've noticed it happen quite a bit on SO.  I have even seen users copy/paste from other answers in the same post and add something like: "Or as user foo says, you can do ...".  This almost sounds as if the other answers are invisible to the human eye.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - if I remember correctly, some your answer was incorrect. A user pointed this out in the comments and you amended your answer by copying the comment into your answer. Seems very similar to me. It's just a shame all of the comments were deleted.

Comment: @ooo: Yeah, someone helpfully pointed out my mistake in a comment, and I said thanks, you're absolutely right, I'll fix it right away — thus improving the information available on the page. Then comments were deleted, as they should be (comments are [second-class citizens and transient](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Comments+are+second-class+citizens)). So that situation isn't similar at all. In this question I ask about folks who duplicate (not improve) information by copy-pasting it from one answer into the neighbouring answer. Why would they do that? Does it benefit the site? No!

Comment: I'd suggest downvoting the answer that copies connect and leaving a content asking that what has been repeated already exists and is readable/visible.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef: Yeah, but I'm not going to do that, though, because the answer as a whole isn't "not useful". The original content did contain a decent attempt at answering the question. There just doesn't seem to be any appropriate action for me to take. BoltClock suggested I ask someone reverse User X's edit that copied my answer. Maybe someone will feel like doing that...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: you might want to review the help topic for this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing  From the looks of it, me how was within the rules.

Comment: It just means that User X thinks your answer is better, and is not confident with their answer.  So in attempt to get upvotes (or avoid downvotes), they borrow your suggestion.  Has happened to me many times and is **very** annoying.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the content is readily accessible in an existing answer to the same question, it should certainly not be duplicated.

I would roll back such an edit, as even if the original author didn't mind (I know you do, and I would), it's still considered noise. Your answer is right there; there is no need to repeat it.

Comment: Should I roll it back myself? Or let someone more neutral roll it back?

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to stay out of trouble, you can ask someone else to roll it back. I'm not sure if this kind of situation warrants moderator attention, however. (I didn't answer the part of your question about flagging.)

Comment: Here's me asking you to roll it back. If you look at my most recent answer history, it will be pretty easy to find.

Comment: I think I see it. Actually, I don't think that is worth rolling back. The user did not copy your answer in whole or a large part of it.

Comment: He copied the key part that directly answers the core question. That's what he didn't have before. The rest is extras. I disagree, but okay, I'll let it go.

Comment: What do you do in situations wherein a user answering the post would add something on her own, then copy/paste significant part of other responses by adding: "You can also do it as mentioned by user foo ... <quote>something</quote>"?

Comment: Maybe you have missed the `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numRows,numCols)` which definitely **was** there before. Added YOUR way of solving it to my already accepted answer so your answer also gets noticed and you get some upvotes...

Comment: I have actually had people tell me that my answer was more complete than theirs, and that if I incorporated the material from their answer, they would delete it. Completely up to a user's discretion, though.

Comment: If an answer credits another user's answer, perhaps upvotes on the new answer could automatically grant some number of points to the original poster as well.

Answer (score 18):

Ok, I believe this question is aimed at me for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409175/declare-a-range-relative-to-the-active-cell-with-vba/25409205?noredirect=1#comment39664822_25409205) so let's clarify a few things.

So here is what has happened (as far as I can remember):

1. a new question gets posted - [Declare a Range relative to the Active Cell with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409175/declare-a-range-relative-to-the-active-cell-with-vba)
2. I have noticed that the user is overcomplicating things by calling the `.Column` property of a Range object and then adding an integer(longs) to it. The correct way is to achieve this same effect is to use `.Offset` property instead.
3. I have posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25409205/1) to the question and then within less than a minute the OP clarified his question by commenting on my answer. I have [edited my answer and added the "follow up" section.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25409205/2)
4. I leave the post convinced that the question should now be properly answered and solved.
5. A few minutes later I get a notification that someone has commented. It was the Jean-François Corbett trying to tell the OP that the answer I gave was exactly was he was looking for. So I ignore the comment and I am off once again. Say it was 15:55
6. I get a notification that my answer has been accepted so I open up the post. It's 6 minutes after I answered.
7. I notice a new answer has been added from Jean-François Corbett which demonstrates an alternative way to achieve the same thing. I combined two `Range(rng1, rng2)` while he uses `ActiveCell.Resize()` - in this example it achieves the same result but we could have an hour long discussion which solution was actually better. Anyhow, since I am familiar with his solution too I also mentioned it in my answer and gave the attribution so his answer also gets noticed and possibly some upvotes. Honestly, I have **not** seen anything wrong with doing it that way.

Today, I see that all other comments have disappeared from below my answer ( I think I even marked one as obsolete ) and I see a new comment which lead to this Meta question.

I have removed YOUR answer from my answer...What else can I say?

Comment: Ok, I can now follow your train of thought, and in fact it's quite understandable. Thanks for laying it out.

Comment: I think there was nothing overtly wrong with your approach, me how.  However, I would have probably just mentioned Jean's answer by suggesting readers examine his for an alternative.

Comment: I agree with Kirk.  Whenever I come across a question in which there is an alternative I'll often reference the original answer by the users name.  Sometimes this requires copy / pasting and injecting my changes.  Sometimes I'll just comment on theirs with a bit more info.  It's situational.  Regardless, having looked at the change history for both answers, I'm really not seeing the problem here.  Your answer followed the proper guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score -2):

How about have a option to reference existing question?

It would made it better and more simple.

As user :
I often do not search long enough or find the existing answer.

As person who answers:
I find the answer after quick search which is already posted and would like to link it, instead of providing link to the answer.

Comment: If you're copy-pasting an existing answer, clearly you've already found it. And then it is not difficult to simply *link* to it. Otherwise, the "option to reference existing question" is to close the question as a duplicate of another question. The only time you'd need to link to another answer is if the question is related but not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray I failed to distinguish between user and person who answers. your fact about the duplicate is valid.