# How should an answer be edited if a lower scored answer has an important improvement in it

Tags: discussion

Declaration of interest: this concerns an answer I wrote.

In [PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations/21536800) there is a very highly voted answer, it's the top answer, and it is, in my opinion, quite a good answer. However, it has a shortcoming, and so I added an answer explaining how to resolve those shortcomings should they apply to you ([PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations/21536800#21536800)).

Recently, someone (crediting me with a comment and in the edit notes) changed the original answer to incorporate the code variation in my answer.

It seems to me that this will now confuse incoming readers as there are a number of comments and other answers which don't quite make sense anymore. It would seem to me that, if the answer should be edited at all, it should simply include one extra line noting the potential issue and with a link to the alternative answer, or encouraging the reader to read a number of the other answers before coding for their situation rather than picking one particular answer, and changing the code in the answer.

However, I may be wrong here, and I wondered what the correct approach to such a situation was?

Comment: Comments becoming obsolete is the norm, simply flag them for cleanup. That's not a hindrance.

Comment: I correctly predicted, before looking at the post you linked, that the top answer would have a "EDIT" moniker in it, and I was right.

Comment: This happened to me when I posted an answer mentioning a recently introduced SQL Server function to a highly viewed question and it was then incorporated into the top voted answer by a moderator. [some meta discussion on that here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103059/145673).

Comment: Related: [Copy-pasting the contents another answer to the same question — with attribution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm not wild about the unnecessary "EDIT:" moniker which was added to the top-rated post (which I have now removed), the principle is sound: take information that is buried in a lower answer, and integrate it naturally into the top-rated, accepted answer so that all of the information is easy to find and naturally incorporated in one place.

I've added a link to the top-voted answer so that your contribution is now properly attributed.