# How to handle answers which copy its whole content from another answer with proper attribution

Tags: discussion, answers, disputed-flags, plagiarism

Today while browsing the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317932/2310866) which essentially just copied its whole content from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957775/android-asynctask-vs-service/6957909).

The text from the other answer is quoted and there is a link to the original answer so it is ok from a plagiarism perspective, but it is still basically the exact same answer copied and pasted without any additional information or clarification.

In my opinion this is not an appropriate answer. A comment with the link to the other answer would have more than sufficed. I realise that it is technically a correct answer, but I assumed that answers like this are not wanted on Stack Overflow so I flagged it as "not an answer", yet to my surprise the flag was disputed. Now I am wondering if there is something else I should have done. Should I have flagged it as something else? No other option seemed appropriate.

So how should I deal with something like this in the future? I very much doubt that answers like this are actually ok and wanted on Stack Overflow since they involve no effort from the answerer and are basically just glorified links.

---

This question is not a duplicate of [Copy-pasting the contents of another answer to the same question — with attribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution)! This question is about how to handle answers which have been copied from another question and not what to do about edits which contain copied content from answers to the same question.

Comment: Technically, it is an answer. However, to my understanding, the user should have voted to close (in this case, flagged) as a duplicate rather than copy the answer, attribution or no.

Comment: "I very much doubt that answers like this are actually ok and wanted on Stack Overflow since they involve no effort from the answerer and are basically just glorified links." You're not alone.

Comment: @sphanley I look at that question before posting this one and I don't think that my question is a duplicate of this one. It's about a similar but still different situation. And also the answers from there don't really apply to my situation.

Comment: One might further argue that "this answer is taken from **link**" isn't actually [proper attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Best_practices_for_attribution).

Comment: If someone is just copy-pasting an answer from one question to another without adding any additional content, you can be *almost* certain that the answer 1) doesn't answer the question appropriately 2) the questions are duplicates, and the person who posted the answer should have voted to close, not copy-pasted the answer.

Comment: I'd also like to take a moment to say that the question in this example is asking, "What do you guys like better, Foo or Bar?"  Such questions are inherently opinion based and shouldn't really be answered in the first place.  The question should be closed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476/165773

Comment: @sphanley: The question you've linked concerns copied answers to the _same_ question, which precludes the possibility of duplicate closure. For that reason, it's not quite the same thing as copying an answer from another question.

Comment: That scenario is covered in comments on the linked question - if a question is a duplicate, it should be closed as one, not duplicate-answered.

Comment: @sphanley Still this question is about something different and the answers from the other question don't apply to this one.

Comment: @sphanley: I am so very tempted to copy the answer to that other question and paste it as an answer here ;)

Comment: With no additional effort, I think it is a bad practice.  I have, however, linked other answers to similar questions if I felt that they provided additional insight to what I was trying to get across.

Comment: @BoltClock Could we please get this question reopened? It's obviously not a duplicate.

Comment: Done. Funny how that other question was one I answered.

Comment: How about making such answers community wiki answers  (if that is even possible)?

Comment: "A comment with the link to the other answer would have more than sufficed." Some people would vote to close that as a link-only answer.

Comment: @Kenster that's why that quote speaks about *A comment*

Comment: Hmm, I think you could have deleted my question instead of cry like a kid, If you see that I've copied the answer (**I PUT ON BOLD WHERE I'VE TOOK THIS ANSWER**), but whatever, instead of do this, you could have warn me, or just delete my post... I just wanted to help.

Comment: @JoanColmenero Nobody says that you ever had any bad intentions and nobody accuses you of plagiarism. The simple truth is that answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be more than just a link or copied content for various reasons which have been discussed here and in other questions on meta. What happened is just part of the ever ongoing quality control process here on Stack Overflow and you shouldn't take it personally.

Comment: Another example (wholesale copy, but with attribution): *[Running a self-contained ASP .NET core application on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226032/running-a-self-contained-asp-net-core-application-on-ubuntu/60193226#60193226)*

Answer (score 1):

If the answer is the same then the question is a duplicate.

So handle it as a duplicate question.

If the question is *NOT* a duplicate but the same approach applies then the answer is *NOT* the same because in addition to citing, it also has to explain how/why a solution to a different problem applies here, too.

---

That specific post was also very poorly written so it could be downvoted for that.