# How should answers that are cited, yet exact copies of other answers be handled?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged an answer yesterday that was cited as an exact copy of an answer to the duplicate question as "not an answer", but my flag was declined as there was "no supporting evidence". The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577640/5021321) reads:

> Copied verbatim from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737296/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-compile-ruby-rails-app):
>
> try this,
>
> remove `Gemfile.lock` file and do `bundle install` , then `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.

While I appreciate that the answer was cited, why was my flag declined? I had already close voted the post as being an exact duplicate, and aren't copies of other answers considered bad form?

Comment: [How to handle copy-and-pasted Answers from dupes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320351/how-to-handle-copy-and-pasted-answers-from-dupes), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-of-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribut, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285349/how-to-handle-answers-which-copy-its-whole-content-from-another-answer-with-prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer that is an exact copy of an existing answer elsewhere might effectively be a link-only answer linking to that other answer, and a link-only answer is often thought to be effectively "not an answer", but honestly that's *really* stretching it.

It's an attempt to answer the question. By quoting an existing answer verbatim. That's a much easier way of interpreting the answer, and one I suspect the moderator chose when declining your flag.

Just raise a custom flag and state explicitly that it's just a copy of an existing answer that does not need to exist given that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: That's fair. I guess a custom flag would have better explained my intentions.

Comment: such custom flags get routinely declined as well

Comment: [Expectation met](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320351/how-to-handle-copy-and-pasted-answers-from-dupes#comment329645_320352). BTW, you repeat yourself a lot :-)