# How to handle a copy cat that eventually edits their way to an "original" answer?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, attribution

I've read [When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism) and [Copy-pasting the contents of another answer to the same question — with attribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution). While they address the ideas of plagiarism, my question involves  a slightly different case.

See my answer to this question -[Index 0 Requested with a size of 0 Error in SQLITE DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085666/index-0-requested-with-a-size-of-0-error-in-sqlite-db/29085919#29085919) and compare it to the **'unedited'** version of the accepted answer. You'll notice a striking similarity in the code block that was used. Sure, 95% of the code was from the OP's code, but because of the comment I added to one of my new lines it's very clear that the code was taken straight from *my answer* and not the OP's.

#### Just so we're clear:

I am admittedly not particularly proud of this answer nor am I wondering why it wasn't marked as the accepted answer. I didn't put more than 5 minutes into it and to be honest I stopped working on it as soon as I saw that someone else had decided to use it as their own and expand upon it. And yes, **only 1 line of code** shows that his answer was clearly copy-pasted from mine, but as a wise man named Bob from Bob's Burgers recently said, **"It's about the principle of the thing!"**.

In this case it made sense to just accept that this was a rare and trivial case but in the future if someone runs into a similar issue, **what's the best course of action to take if someone initially copies your answer and then changes it through subsequent edits? Or better yet, is there anything to do?**

As suggested in one of the posts I mentioned in the beginning, rolling back an edit doesn't apply because it only **began** as mostly a copy-paste job (not to mention I don't have the privileges to work that kind of magic on my own).

Also, I've seen this quite often where one answer will build off another (which makes sense IF you've got something else to add that the first answer missed) the only common factor that's missing in my case is no mention of attribution.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Even if he did copy your answer, there's still 2 differences on his original revision compared to yours (might have been edited in the grace period but that we can't see). He's got a `myDBHelper` and he added an `if` . I doubt attribution for the closing and comment is needed.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau My **only** changes or suggested answer to the OP was to set his db equal to writableDatabase() and then close() the connection to that database when he was done - both of these lines were used in his answer (so he changed 'this' to 'myDBHelper', but it's still clear that he took this directly from my answer because of the missed comment).

Comment: May I use the comment *"close your db connection when you're done with it"* somewhere in the future? Or it's under the license?

Comment: Isn't the idea of giving an answer to the question? If the other answer is better then yours then it's not a copy, it's an improvement. The question is answered, that's all that matters.

Comment: @TLama I think you're missing the bigger picture here, but no please feel free to use it it's definitely not "under the license".

Comment: Copying an existing answer partly (or fully) to expand on it somewhere the other answered did not should be ok, however courtesy (and the licence used by the site I believe) says to attribute who's work you are expanding on

Comment: Yeah @nico because if you didn't have 20K+ you wouldn't be bothered! That aside in this case he's copied at best a comment, probably liked the wording better. That in my book is not plagiarism, they still had the `db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();` in their "unedited version", so your argument is kind of pointless in this case. But I can understand the frustration of providing an answer and feeling as though you have been *pipped to the post*, but that's life on SO I'm afraid.

Comment: @Lankymart I didn't always have 20K+, and I have never really been bothered by that. Many times I had someone taking code from my answer and making it better. I actually appreciate that, the question gets a better answer and I may learn a trick or two as well. It's obviously a different story if the answer is completely copied, but it seems not to be the case here...

Comment: @bwegs : If I'd seen that question I'd have probably closed it as a duplicate (there are plenty of `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` questions out there with similar answers). One thing I would say is just wait untill you have 2K rep and roll-back the other person's answer to the original version then update yours. ;)

Comment: He could have edited your original answer instead, in multiple steps. Would that be an acceptable solution? I think it's technically correct, as long as it clearly makes the answer better. But that is subjective. And if it is not clearly better, I would consider it rude.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel He doesn't need to edit mine because he did have a number of additions to make, if he has a more complete answer to share then by all means he should use my answer in his own to solve the OP's issue. **If you're going to use someone else's answer along with your own just give credit where credit is due, simple as that.**

Comment: Regarding changing your answer instead, there is the problem of who gets the rep for the final version. It is pretty relevant as you are both below the 2000 rep (I consider direct editing an important privilege). He would get none at all, an you would get the rep for added content; Like it is now, he draws part of your potential rep increase, plus gets rep for his added content.

Comment: @bwegs Ok, for this question and answer, I fully agree with you. (In a routine case, I'd put the attribution in small print on the last line like <sub>Expanding on answer from @bwegs</sub>. Note I actually never had this situation). It is not the case here, but the problem would be more difficult if your answer already had many votes, so that the augmented answer would not be able to ever catch up, even if it's better in some objective way.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/905/2133): Where a new answer on the block (which has the opposite answer) gets copied and appended to the existing accepted answer.

Answer (score 65):

Very sorry for not giving credit where credit was due initially.
@bwegs, I just updated the answer to give you credit for the piece I included in my answer.

Yes, I did copy your answer and used it as a starting point for my answer, but it was a "time saver" move more than anything, I had no bad intentions.  The main thing that I wanted to tell the OP was to check the return value of `moveToFirst()`, and to close the cursor.

Again, very sorry.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I appreciate it. Just trying to turn this into something that everyone can learn something from.

Comment: No problem!  I should have given you credit to begin with, and again, sorry for not doing that.  I'm fairly new to posting answers on SO (been lurking for years), and learning as I go, so this was definitely a learning experience for me!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is say "hey, can you attribute the copying you did from my answer?" in a comment on the question, or words to that effect.  Especially if the poster is inexperienced with SO, they might not know the etiquette.

If they fail to do that, then they are in violation of the license you grant other users to the content you post (they are copying without attribution).  So you can flag it.

Comment: What would you flag it as?

Comment: @TravisJ plagerism without attribution?  I guess simply editing in attribution would be another approach rather than involving moderators.