# User asking the same question in order to answer the original

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

This is a bit of an odd case. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287521/name-attribute-should-be-defined) earlier today. Simple enough, a user asking how to change the color of text in Android. I proceeded to answer the question, and have the user thank me for providing the correct solution.

For no specific reason, I decided to take a look at this user's profile. I saw that a few minutes after he saw my correct answer, he used it to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286320/change-android-text-color/33287814#33287814), which was basically the same as his own.

The original version of the first question was slightly different, but after an edit, the user was left with the error `name attribute should be defined`. This is the same error that the author of the second question encountered (and not by coincidence, I'm assuming)

Would this be considered plagiarism?

I want to make it perfectly clear that I'm not upset that this user may have used my answer. It was a simple question, and probably a duplicate at that.

Comment: It's on the Android tag, so it's almost certainly plagiarism.

Comment: Both of his answers provided are to the same person. And [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33066571/73226) he also asked a question about http://stackoverflow.com/q/33057124/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith That actually appears to fly both ways. Two of the three accepted answers by the other user are to questions by the user in question here... It looks, to me at least, like they potentially know each other outside SO. (I'd hate to accuse sock over four total questions.)

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting. The two users interacting with each other on different tags on multiple occasions could just be coincidence, but I would dare to call the two instances of asking the same question to post an answer plagiarism. What do you think the best course of action would be in this situation?

Comment: Bring it to a moderator's attention probably. They can have a quiet word if need be. Maybe they are work colleagues working on the same project or maybe something more misguided going on.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I wouldn't call the second instance, that Martin Smith pointed out, _plagiarism_ exactly. Even the one you point out really is more a rewording of your answer. In both cases, however, the user _still_ should have cited the sources, or, preferably, not asked the questions in the first place. But I agree with Martin Smith that this might be a good time to flag for mod and explain the situation. Be sure to tell them as much detail as you, and even post a link to this question if you feel you need to. The mods can at least let the user know they're going about this wrong.

Comment: @Kendra you could very well be right. I have flagged the answer I cited in my original question for moderator attention. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: Shouldn't simply one question be marked as a duplicate of the other, then?

Comment: @MartinJames [speaking of plagiarized Android answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374751/droid-hunter)...

Comment: So this guy basically copied someone else's question *an hour* after it was asked (even used the same screenshot), then answered the original question after getting an answer? That's just bizarre...

Comment: By the way, before people start going flag-crazy with my Droid Hunter (tm) query, please note that it picks up a lot of instances of code-only answers, which may just be Android boilerplate, and is difficult to verify as plagiarism. I'm not an Android guy, so I can't tell what is boilerplate and what's not, I just dig this stuff up with a massive drag-net, not a fine sieve...

Comment: Isn't it written into the rules of this site that no one has any claim over any of the code written here? The whole point is that it's reused. Using it to answer another question and get points seems dirty but is it really against the rules?

Comment: User @john seems to have deleted his original plagiarized answer, can someone with >10k rep verify and post a screenshot?

Comment: @Noodlemanny the SO license requires attribution to the original author so yes, it is against the rules.

Comment: @Magisch So if I attribute it, I can use it to answer other questions?

Comment: @Noodlemanny Yes, but you may get downvoted if you add nothing but an attributed quote. If you think another question is similar enough to copy an answer verbatim, flagging as duplicate is the proper option. That said, using other's code as part of your answer (with attribution) is accepted commonplace on SO.

Comment: Really sorry about that.. We both are mates and doing the same project.I will delete this account as well.  Sorry for any inconvenience caused...

Comment: No worries friend! I don't think you should be worried about deleting your account, I don't think you were trying to be malicious in your intent. (Android pun not *intended*) Just realize that people take plagiarism pretty seriously. I know it's frustrating, but it's not really suggested to vote on your colleagues posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers

Comment: No need to delete your account. Just ensure that future interactions between the two of you are above board.

Comment: Just my 2 cents here but I would rather have an answer to every question in the site than a link to other questions that could (for many reasons) end up deleted. It's not like the reputation on this site transfers to any real world value, so I say plagiarise away. The best way to learn something is to teach others. A link to your answer in his might be good etiquette but certainly not required.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg unfortunately, as noted above, plagiarism goes against the license you agree to when you use this site, so it is not allowed, and besides that is looked upon very poorly when discovered. The purpose of this site is **not** to have an answer to every single posted question, instead it is to form a knowledge repository where all questions can be answered. This is why so many questions are closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be considered as plagiarism. The user should have marked the question as duplicate, or at least should have given attribution to you in his answer. Looking at his profile, the user seems to be a person who is trying to earn bounty.
Also note that most of the questions and answers revolve around these two users:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5398173/john

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5261462/hoo

i.e. if first has asked the question, second has answered, or vice-versa.

I doubt these two user profiles have some connection.

Comment: Really sorry about that.. We both are mates and doing the same project.I will delete this account as well. Sorry for any inconvenience caused

Comment: @John I don't think you should delete the account. You've been quite active on the site and can be a valuable member of the community. The duplication mistake discussed here looks like the sort of things that happens when learning how a new community works. Please stay and continue contributing!

Comment: we probably should avoid direct exposure of user profiles in meta posts.

Answer (score 7):

I would most definitely consider this plagiarism, as there was no attribution given. The user in question has now also deleted his plagiarized Answer without comment.

Not sure what he was trying there, but in my point of view that was entirely premeditated and thus a lot worse then usual instances of plagiarism. He asked this question with the *specific* purpose of plagiarizing the answer, then.

Comment: Really sorry about that.. We both are mates and doing the same project.I will delete this account as well. Sorry for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 4):

Based on the opinions of most everyone here, this can indeed be classified as plagiarism. I flagged the user's answer for moderator attention, describing the situation and linking to this meta post.

Since then, the user has deleted his answer, and commented here, acknowledging that he and the other user in question are working on the same project. I do not believe that his actions were done with the intention of plagiarism, but it is still behavior that is frowned upon.

Here are a couple additional reading links for this subject:
[When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism)
[How to vote on friends / colleagues ' questions (or answers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers)

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Should the user have marked the question as a duplicate? You *could* argue that s/he should have but community moderation is voluntary and not an obligation. It also evens itself out. The user contributed an answer to a question, meanwhile you flagged the question as a duplicate. So the question was both answered and prohibited from cluttering the site, win win. Does his answer constitute plagiarism? Hardly. In fact, the answer was so trivial that you yourself didn't cite your source (presumably you weren't born with innate knowledge of android and had to learn it yourself). Plagiarism denotes taking credit for someone else's original work... not passing along helpful bits of trivial knowledge.

Comment: I actually did link directly to the documentation in my answer. Even if it doesn't fall into your definition of plagiarism, intentionally asking a duplicate question (with or without the intention of "copying" the answer, let's put that aside) is obviously not productive.