# Stealing someone's answer

Tags: discussion

Some weeks ago I found a great answer for sharing JavaScript files across [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) projects.

Some time before that I was looking to do the same with ASP.NET MVC files (common views, controllers, etc.).

Again today, I revisited the latter question and found myself at the same answer as the first round. **The accepted answer from another question is perfect for this, so I stole it and posted as another answer**

I figure I've landed there twice via Google, and the answer I stole is really such a great fit, it must benefit someone else, right? And, link-only answers are frowned upon, yet it's not really a duplicate (despite the answer fitting both questions), so...

Is this acceptable? Here's [the answer I stole and posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631538/sharing-razor-views-across-projects/37370333#37370333).

Please advise if I should handle differently. Thanks.

Comment: If the question you're looking at would qualify as a duplicate, then just simply do that. Otherwise, I would probably just post the links to those answers as a comment. If you just copy and paste an answer as your own, even with proper credit given, it doesn't really add anything to the community. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions

Comment: Without knowing much about the topic, these questions look like they could be duplicates. If two questions have the same answer, the less-broad one is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: The tricky part here is that, at a glance, it looks like the "less-broad" one is the one with the good answer. Also, the broader one isn't *really* a generalization of the other one; rather, they're both asking about different specific instances of what turns out to be a general problem with a general solution. And the good answer, while presenting a solution that works for multiple cases, really only talks about the specific case (JS files) that the question it answers directly asks about.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you could also consider making it a community wiki so it doesn't look like you're trying to get rep by ripping off others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to somewhat disagree with Alexei here, and say that **you did the right thing** by finding an answer to a related question that also solves this other similar problem, copying it, and **clearly** attributing the content of your answer to its original source.

Copying, *where appropriate* and *with correct attribution* is explicitly encouraged on Stack Overflow.  See e.g. [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism) and its answers, which say:

> > Is it considered plagiarism on StackOverflow.com to take material from another answer on the same question and re-use it with modifications?
>
> No. You are expressly permitted to do so - as long as you give attribution.

<sup>— [Original answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251390) by [Pekka 웃](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%ec%9b%83) on Apr 20 '14 at 16:00</sup>

In particular, all posts on SO are licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which permits redistribution of any so licensed content in both modified and unmodified form, provided that the original author(s) are attributed and that any modified content is released under the same license (which posting it on SO implicitly and automatically does).

---

Now, all that said: **Whenever you see two questions that can be answered with essentially the same answer** — whether yours or somebody else's — **that's a sign that there might be a deeper issue involved.**  In particular, it's possible that:

- The questions are asking about the same problem, and one of them (preferably the one with fewer / poorer answers) should be [flagged as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) of the other.  (If both questions already have excellent answers, and the questions really are identical, you can flag them for moderator attention and [ask them to merge the answers together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69504/how-do-i-merge-a-question-into-another-on-stack-overflow) under one question.)
- One of the questions is asking about a specific instance of a general problem, and this general problem has already been asked and answered in the other question thread (e.g. "*How do I frob a red widget?*" vs. "*How do I frob a widget?*", where the color of the widget doesn't really matter when frobbing it).  Again, unless there's something that would make the answer to the specific problem different from the general one, the more specific question should be closed as a duplicate.

  This does tend to require a bit of careful judgement and domain knowledge.  In such cases, in addition to casting your close flag / vote, you may want to leave the asker a comment such as:

  > We already have [a question about frobbing widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175545) with some good answers. Do they solve your problem? If not, please edit your question to tell us why your problem is different.
- The questions are both asking about different special cases of a more general problem (e.g. "*How do I frob a red widget?*" vs. "*How do I frob a blue widget?*").  **This is what seems to be the case with your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631538/sharing-razor-views-across-projects) here.**

  This is a slightly trickier case to handle.  If one of the questions can be easily edited to generalize it, you can do that and then vote to close the other one as a duplicate of it.  Otherwise, it may be a good idea to ask (and, if you can, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) the general question yourself, and (once the general question has a good answer) suggest that the specific questions be marked as duplicates of it.

Still, even when several questions have effectively the same answer, it may not always be easy or even possible to come up with a single general question that would cover all the possible variations of the problem, at least not without the question and its answers becoming so abstract that it's hard to understand *how* they answer the specific problem unless you already know enough theory to see how the problems, deep down, are really the same.  In such cases, [it's perfectly fine to have some duplication](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) if it means that the specific answers are easier to understand for people facing that specific variant of the problem.

---

So, getting back to [your copied answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631538/sharing-razor-views-across-projects/37370333#37370333), could you have handled that better?  Sure.  In particular:

- Instead of copying the entire answer verbatim, you could've only summarized the relevant parts of it, and provided a link for more details, e.g. like this:

  > This is really the same problem as [sharing JavaScript files among projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution), which Erik Philips has already provided [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution/8541764#8541764) for.
  >
  > The solution (which Erik describes in more detail in his answer, linked above) is to create a new solution folder, with a correspondingly named directory, to store the common files in.  You would store the files you want to share in the directory, add them to the new solution folder (using *Add > Existing Item...*), and then also add them **as links** to any project that needs them (using *Add > Existing Item...* and selecting "Add As Link" from the drop down menu in the file selector dialog).
- Alternatively, you could've copied the answer in full, but edited it (while retaining attribution, of course) to apply to all kinds of files for which this general solution works, instead of just JavaScript files.  That way, you'd end up with a generic answer that (especially if the question was also edited slightly to mention that it's an instance of a more general problem) could be used as a duplicate target for later questions.
- In either case, if you were concerned about people thinking that you were "unfairly" earning rep by copying another user's answer, you could've marked your own answer as [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (which would stop you from earning any rep from it, and make it clear that you consider the answer a collaborative effort, as opposed to your original contribution).  You don't *have* to do this, but voluntarily eschewing rep like this from answers that heavily lean on someone else's content can sometimes make them better received.
- Finally, since [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209259/erik-philips) is an active user, you could've just left a comment on their answer linking to the other question (possibly after briefly answering it yourself, as I suggested above), and suggesting that they might want to generalize their answer to apply to both questions.

But still, the way you handled this was by no means *wrong*, and you shouldn't feel ashamed of it.  Copying answers with attribution, like you did, is perfectly within the rules, and you didn't do anything to disguise your actions or to mislead users into thinking that you had written the content when you hadn't.  If anyone still thinks that it would be unfair to award you rep for that answer, they can just, you know, *not upvote it.*

Comment: How do I mark an answer as Community Wiki (I don't see any option for such).  Also, is there no messaging system here to notify Erik, or is a comment the only way?  Thanks

Comment: and how do I ping someone in comments when they have a space in their name?

Comment: @jdl134679: When you're writing an answer (or editing your own answer), there *should* be a checkbox labeled "community wiki" below the edit box. See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) for a screenshot. Your do need 10 rep points to access that feature, but you have plenty more than that on SO.

Comment: Also, to [@ping a user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) with spaces in their name, just leave out the spaces (or just use their first name; almost any prefix of the username will work, as long as it's not ambiguous). When you start typing the username after the @, a tab-completion menu should pop up; at that point, you can just press tab and it will autocomplete the username for you. See the linked FAQ post for details.

Comment: I wiki'd it, but don't think the comment thing worked (I usually rely on autcomplete, but because he's not active in the question is doesn't come up).  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @jdl134679: When you comment on a question/answer, the author of that post is always automatically notified. Thus, you don't need to ping them, and the autocompleter won't show their username in the list. Conversely, you *can't* ping someone that hasn't posted, edited or commented on the post that you're commenting on. So if you want to write someone a comment that isn't part of an existing discussion, you basically have to post it to one of *their* questions or answers.

Answer (score 10):

Such behavior is not welcome.

If question is not duplicate feel free to provide link to answer and brief summary in your answer preferably in addition to your own content - this policy covered in  https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

At least you've provided attribution - otherwise it will call for some action from moderators and immediate removal of content.

Comment: While summarizing sources that you quote is indeed a good idea in general, it may be worth noting that the prohibition on the page you linked to against copying the complete text of a source applies specifically to "external sources" &mdash; that is, to sources *outside* Stack Overflow. Copying another SO post, even in full, [is permitted as long as you properly attribute it to its original author.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism/251398#251398) It may not always, or even usually, be the *best* choice, but it *is* allowed.

Comment: Your link says to 1) provide a link to original, 2) quote relevant portions only, and 3) provide the author's name, which is what I did.  In any case, I've made it a wiki answer per @IlmariKaronen answer and have tried to ping the author just for good measure.  (I'd have felt it was more plagiarism to have "reconstructed" the answer the question any other way, and now if OP wants rep for his answer he can add it himself and remove the wiki'd answer I left... seems fair?  This is why I ask (and receive 13 downvotes for it... S/O doesn't follow the "no stupid question" philosophy!)