# How is posting a partial quote of another answer an acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575060/1778421) as [VLQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/63550) (and flagged the question as duplicate) - since it is nothing but a link to another answer and then a partial copy of code from that answer. But somehow enough people found both acceptable.

Comment: Just flag it for moderator intervention.

Comment: Related: [When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251389/3853934)

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me - the problem is the way we handle duplicates on the site. They stick around, even if they get "closed". Often with useless answers. I have taken to doing exactly this sometimes, in order to get a proper answer (since the post is going to live on our site for ever...). Admittedly, these days I often press "community wiki" when doing it, but I still believe it is better for a duplicate to have some useful info.

Comment: I just downvote when I see that.  The question should get closed as a duplicate anyway, so why worry about flagging the answer?

Comment: @Tab Alleman: We don't want duplicate answers (i.e. answers with *no original content*) sticking around earning unwarranted reputation for the poster. It is an insult to both the original contributor, and to the user duplicating the content (unless they're happy being seen as that guy with no originality whatsoever whose only ability is to reference - or worse, copy and paste - other people's work).

Comment: But once the question is closed, what is the likelihood that the answers will get upvotes?

Comment: @Tab Alleman: You'd be surprised.

Answer (score 23):

Let me address the fact that you flagged [this now deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHDxu.png).

That answer is not utter garbage nor is it link only, so it doesn't qualify for being low quality. Hence the reviewers chose the correct option.

Use one of the other moderation options: editing, commenting, down voting or close voting the question. The latter has been done by now.

Comment: is it now deleted?

Comment: @techspider it is

Comment: Deleting that answer for the lack of proper attribution feels similar to getting Al Capone for tax evasion. You seem to be saying that with proper attribution that answer would have been totally acceptable.

Comment: If the only thing wrong with the answer was *attribution*, then why not post a comment to the answer, suggesting that the poster should edit their answer to add attribution, or, just go ahead and edit the answer to add the attribution, instead of deleting the answer?

Comment: @KevinFegan editing attribution in is perfectly fine - if you know whom you should attribute it to. Now, if the answerer reverts, we might be talking about a flag.

Comment: @AlexP. you didn't ask that question. You asked why your flag wasn't followed up by reviewers as you would have liked. I answered that.  If there is anyone who is in favor of sending crap to the garbage bin you can count on me. By now that is effectively done.

Comment: Rene. I'm confused... In your answer, you say the *"answer is not utter garbage nor is it link only, so it doesn't qualify for being low quality. Hence the reviewers chose the correct option."* indicating the answer should have remained. But now, in you comment, you speak like you are glad the "crap" is in the garbage bin. Unfortunately, since the answer has been removed, others can't view it and form their own opinion, and, the answer can't be edited to make everyone happy.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what happened here and what the actual issue is. It doesn't help that the "suspect" answer is gone, but I do see a very curious thing. You said, *"What is missing is proper attribution of the original author".* But, in the original post here, @AlexP. said the answer contained a link to the other answer. What more attribution is required than that?

Comment: @KevinFegan I have added the screenshot for the now deleted answer. My point is that the question asked is: *Why is my flagged declined*. I explain that the answer should not have been flagged but I do recognize that *something* might be wrong with that answer, if it is not plagiarism then it is attribution. That is, however, not the question asked here. I understand that everybody loves to have an extended discussion about what proper attribution is and if I have a too strict interpretation of that but that is not what I intended to answer. Anyway removed all that fluff.

Comment: Thanks for posting the image. I still question why attribution is an issue since the author posted a link to the other answer. And now I'm wondering why the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574875/how-to-click-on-a-specific-coordinate-android-screen) was also deleted rather than remaining marked as a duplicate.

Comment: 1) We can't post answers that add no new info other than "Hey look at Jimmy's answer over here:" link ... 2) Duplicates get deleted all the time (in fact one might be well guided toward deleting only dupes cuz [Roomba](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) won't)