# Flag was declined on low quality answer, IMO

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364938/8560567) as low quality. A moderator declined this, but I do not know why. The answerer clearly did not put any effort into answering, and just stated what he/she had thought. Does anyone know why my flag was declined?

Comment: It looks like an answer to me.  If you disagree with it, you should be downvoting it and not flagging it.

Comment: My understanding is that the Low Quality flag on an answer is treated the same as the Not An Answer flag: it will get declined if it looks like an attempt to answer.

Comment: Flagging answers on Meta as VLQ or NAA is an exercise in futility. There are very few things that will cause a flag to be deemed helpful on Meta. Basically, only if a question is completely, wildly off-topic. You're better off just letting bad answers get downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that an answer is not useful you should be downvoting it, not flagging it.  There is no "low quality" flag, and for good reason.  The appropriate course of action for a flag that is of low quality is a downvote.

Flagging is for things that *aren't even answers*, which isn't the case for that post.