# My question never got answered. What can I do?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Sometimes I ask a perfectly legitimate, well-formed question. It gets viewed 50+ times, and gets no answers, upvotes, downvotes, or comments... What can I do to attract people to view and respond to my question?

Comment: Related: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Maybe it was too hard. :)

Comment: Well, hey. At least you'll get [a badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) out of it ;)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat - he won't if it gets views...

Comment: I'm sorry if the wording wasn't clear, I already saw the help center question, but I was looking for a way to make my question more attractive to answer in the first place. Not to re-attract users to it.

Comment: The flipside to this is that if nobody can answer your question, maybe the best thing is to do the research yourself so that you find the answer. If you do, then post it back pls. Of course that's easy for me to say, since I deal with Android, which is OS, so I can always get the answer one way or another.

Comment: @user16320675 How useful of you to revisit an 8 year old comment and make corrections. However I entirely disagree with your sentiment that a question poster should not return if they ever find an answer to an unanswered post of theirs - that would really go against the spirit of this community.

Comment: "Nothing more to research" is very much a sliding scale though. There are lots of questions that I've posted over time (since my 2014 comment) that I'd look back on and think "old Richard didn't know very much", because of what I've learnt by now. It is entirely acceptable to post a question before learning more, and it is entirely hoped that one will learn more after posting. If one posts something without any response, and later finds an answer, I was just hoping that one would come back and fill in their answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you have the privilege, setting [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) are a great way to accomplish this.

I've also found the following useful:

- Sharing a link to my question on Twitter (might be more useful to some than others)
- *Politely* asking folks in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms) related to what you're working with if they know the answer to your question (*but make sure to read their local rules first, if any, usually indicated in the room description*)
- Linking to the question in other places you're communicating with other programmers about your problem
- Blogging about the problem and linking to the question

I'm convinced that the Internet can answer *any* sound question, it becomes a bit of a game of opportunity when it comes to getting it in front of someone that has some particular nugget of rare knowledge.

For the *most* part, if one of my questions went unanswered, it was because I was doing something either completely new or rather unorthodox - which often meant too much of an ask for folks as far as the time needed to answer went, even with a bounty.

If you're asking good questions, this should be a pretty rare phenomenon.

Comment: I would like to add that editing the question to improve, clarify, or add additional information might be an option. Maybe the question has not had enough activity because it was not quite good enough to elicit a satisfactory response yet. Editing the question will bump it up to the top of the [active tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=active&pageSize=50) for that question's relevant tags, which may draw the attention of an expert in that tag.

Comment: Just make sure that every edit actually improves the question, and don't abuse edits by making them unnecessarily, just to bump your question up in the active tab.

Answer (score 21):

You can [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the question. This puts it in the featured tab and may encourage others to answer it.

Answer (score 21):

[Directly from the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers):

> ### What should I do if no one answers my question?
>
> First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on any question more than two days old.

Answer (score 3):

If the question isn't getting any attention (positive or negative), then these are some of the likely possibilities:

1. It's very esoteric and you just haven't attracted a viewer who actually knows about your topic.  50 views is a small sample of users.  As an example, you may be asking a question about how to use an API that just isn't very popular and there aren't many people who know about that.  Or it could be some super technical aspect of something like a database that most people wouldn't know about.
2. Your question may appear on the surface to be properly written (so no downvotes or clarifying comments), but isn't actually a good question and doesn't actually convey what you're trying to ask such that nobody thinks they know the answer, but doesn't immediately think it's a bad question.  For your purposes, it may actually be a bad question, it just isn't recognized as so.  As an example, you might be using the wrong names to describe something that allows it to appear to be a proper question, but nobody recognizes the wording used so nobody thinks they know how to help.
3. Related to point #1, you haven't tagged it appropriately to bring it to the attention of the right viewers.
4. You may have posted something that just too daunting for someone to tackle in an answer.  Sometimes this will attract "too broad" comments or close votes, but sometimes the question doesn't necessarily seem too broad, it's just too difficult for many to find the energy or expertise to tackle it.

When all else fails, put more effort into the question.  A meaningful edit that adds a more complete description of the problem, more examples or more relevant code may both cast a broader net for who might be able to help and may give a fresh boost through the front page where the most people see it (avoid trivial edits just to try to "bump" it).

If that still fails, then try to find a simpler subset of your question that might be easier for someone to answer and post that.  If you get engagement on that, you can post a comment that links your other question and then ask those who participated if they can have a look.

Also, make sure to describe the top-level problem.  There are many questions on stackoverflow that are down-in-the-weeds questions where a user got stuck deep into an implementation of some solution to some higher level problem.  They're asking for help with that implementation, but if they describe the actual top-level problem, there's a much better way to solve it than what is being asked about.  This is often referred to as the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Describing the top level problem may attract a much wider set of people who could help than the specifics of your issue with your solution.

Imagine you're having some problem with some specific function in a database API and you ask a very detailed question about that specific API.  But, really,  this code is part of a solution to some higher level concurrency issue and the best solution is to design the solution differently in a way that doesn't even use the API you're having problems with.  If all you post is the XY problem, then nobody knows the higher level problem so they can't help you with different/better solutions to the top level problem.