# How should accepted link-only answers be handled?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, declined-flags, link-only-answers

Is the accepted answer of the question [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/119473#119473) not a link-only answer?

I have raised a flag about it. A moderator has declined it.

Here is a screenshot of the reply from the moderator.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209144/highly-upvoted-and-accepted-link-only-answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer and recent: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227293/why-were-my-flags-on-accepted-link-only-answers-declined

Comment: Also related to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: Just because it's an _accepted answer_ isn't a good reason to keep the post.  Neither does that imply that the community should work upon improving the post.  Weird logic!

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Such answers are nothing more than comments.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png

Comment: [Similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/119835/2235132) to the same question was deleted and converted to a comment by a moderator.  Do not expect consistent response from moderators.  The reactions are whimsical at best.

Comment: @devnull, Moderators are not always correct. There are no of similar link only accepted answer with high upvote are deleted. An example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247439/c-sharp-autostart-automatically-add-application-to-startup-folder/4247644#4247644 We have to accept it.

Comment: @Satpal I know that.  I have flagged numerous answers, including highly upvoted and accepted answers.  It seems to me that the moderators lack a sense of consensus as to what constitutes a good post or not.  As such, it is inevitable to run into the sort of issues that you describe.

Comment: @Satpal: You use an old example as a counterargument of a recent change.  The less-punishful (yeah, I made that up) reaction to LOAs is a recent thing among mods.  Not sure why that change.  Anyhow, downvote, vote to delete.

Comment: I find it especially adorable that someone commented directly at the author of that answer not realizing the author hasn't even been on the site in over 2 years.

Comment: From now on, don't remove any stupid answer. Even if it's a spam, __fix__ it.  You have the tools, don't you.  If an(y) answer is wrong, the community shall __fix__ it.  No downvotes or votes-to-delete on incorrect answers, link-only answers, not-an-answer answers, only __FIX__ it.  So says the community manager, @Shog9

Comment: @devnull: You seem upset.

Comment: @BoltClock No, not upset at all.  I feel _educated_ now.  I just upvoted a few posts (questions) that I'd have previously downvoted and voted-to-close having being _enlightened_.  Moreover, refrained from flagging a couple of link-only answers that I ran into; couldn't manage to _improve_ those, however.

Comment: @BoltClock BTW, could you please undelete [a very useful answer to the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/119835/2235132) that was deleted by a moderator?

Comment: Oh, give it a rest, @devnull. Down-vote, flag, delete, edit... You have PLENTY of tools at your disposal. If you can't figure out when to use them, that's your problem - but I highly doubt you honestly think 13 hours bitching at moderators for not doing your bidding is a more productive use of your time than using ANY of them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There has been years of debate around this issue.

The [introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to Stack Overflow has always said that it is a “questions and answer site” — not a link repository. The [guidelines on how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) contain

> Provide context for links
>
> A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

However, until recently, this was not enforced on Stack Overflow. (Many other Stack Exchange sites do enforce this.)

Today, **there is an [official policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)**.

> this sort of response is not an answer. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, delete it.

Noting that this sort of response, usually called “link-only answer”, is a post that does not contain any content that answers the question, but contains a link to a web page where an answer may be found. A post which contains a terse answer and is formatted as a link is not a link-only answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/119473#119473) (in its first revision, it has now been edited) is a non-obvious case: it says “use this particular library”, with a link to said library. When the library in question is referenced from a well-known, stable location, this kind of answer is a generally poor answer but an answer nonetheless: it says “use this”. On the other hand, when the library is “the code on Joe's blog”, this is not an answer: you have to read Joe's blog to find out what is meant. The way to tell link-only answers is: if you didn't have hypertext links, would the post still be useful? If the answer is yes (e.g. because the answer gives a name of a module from the standard library), then the post is an answer. If the answer is no, then the post is a sign that says “there's an answer over there”, it is not an answer. Here, we're in a “read Joe's blog to get something useful” case, this is not an answer.

Thus your flag was correct, and the moderator should have deleted the post in question.

Comment: If a policy would end up deleting a lot of 50 upvote accepted answers, it's the policy that needs to be deleted, not the answers.

Comment: @WarrenDew This answer has been around for 6 years. Presumably the code on that blog is useful. But the day the blog poster goes offline, poof! No more answer. That's why link-only answers should not be left around in the first place. Now someone's posted the code, so it's all good. If the policy had been applied in the first place, we wouldn't be here to argue about it, so your objection is irrelevant.

Comment: "That's why link-only answers should not be left around in the first place" -- then SO needs a mechanism for flagging them to subject matter experts (SMEs) for repair, rather than deleting them. Once the link is indeed broken, deletion may be the best course of action. However, until that time, the answer adds value, just on a tenuous basis. I don't expect mods to fix the answers, as they may not have the domain knowledge to do so. Nor do I expect SMEs to wade through 498,832 questions looking for accepted link-only answers that need help. A mod->SME channel would help here.

Comment: "Today, there is an official policy." no, there isn't. You know as well as I do that [discussion is still ongoing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).

Comment: @eis There *is* an official policy, which I linked to in my answer. Robert opposes this policy, which is why he opened that new discussion.

Comment: @Gilles if it were an official policy, it would be published as such (a blog post, an FAQ entry or equivalent). The topic you linked is how Shog views the state of things to be - Robert and George, both moderators as well, have disagreed him on that. I don't see anything supporting your claim that it would be an official policy. On the contrary, the post I linked says "I am asking if you want the policy to be changed, because right now we don't delete these answers.". So the policy is *not* to delete them.

Comment: Furthermore, I strongly object giving an illusion that something is a policy when there is no strong evidence to support the claim. That's downright harmful. Shog makes no reference of it being a policy, there is no word "policy" in his post. The only place where the post policy is mentioned there is in a comment, "I'm not trying to come down hard on you, just trying to pre-empt the many questions and finanglings we'd get **if** this were policy." by George Stocker (emphasis mine). It is directly saying **it is not the policy**.

Comment: @eis “So let me be clear: this sort of response is not an answer. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, delete it.” Signed, the Community Manager for Stack Exchange, Inc. That is a policy, and with a score of +109/-1, it has community consensus. Robert's post mentioned a policy of (some) SO moderators which dates back from the time when there was no official SE-level policy. Your quote by George Stoker is not about Shog9's announcement but about a reply to it.

Comment: Facts are that there are several replies and posts saying that the consensus currently is *not* to delete link-only answers, a post that I linked and comments to the post you linked to. There is no source whatsoever, except your own saying, that there exists a *policy* that link-only answers should be deleted. As of this date and time, I haven't seen anybody from the moderators claim that would be the policy. Please stop spreading rumors if you don't have facts to back them up.

Comment: It was not an announcement. It was tagged as *discussion*. You should be able to differentiate the two.

Comment: @CBauer For years, that policy wasn't enforced: some [moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251569) (especially on SO) disagreed with it, the charismatic founder of SO (Jeff Atwood) was inconsistent about it. It was only [Shog9's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) that made it clear that the policy that answers be answers should be enforced. eis's statement that the consensus was not to delete is false, but it isn't fair to say that there was a consensus to delete either. Now there is — it's a policy, and as you say it's built into some tools.

Comment: Weird - this came up as a hot topic in my sidebar and I didn't think to check the date on it. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 26):

Y'all are idiots. You're really gonna spend 13 hours arguing about this instead of just editing the answer (as someone presumably less interested in arguing has now done)?

If a moderator isn't willing to fix a problem, go ahead and fix it yourself. You have the tools; if you don't care to use them, then you're as much at fault as anyone else.

Comment: "Y'all are idiots." ***FLAGGED***

Comment: Welcome to __idiots__ gang :), now you are one us.

Comment: +1 because it contains a grain of truth. Also because a moderator just called us all "idiots". Now I feel kinda dirty :P

Comment: This is meta. It's just as it is with mathematics: numbers make equations more difficult and less general. Discussing any case is more meta than solving a single case.

Comment: Shog I am trying to figure if we can stop beating moderators who try to keep old valuable link-only answers. Spoke to some folks at [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32395606#32395606), they seem to like the idea. Would appreciate if you help to get some stats for that: [How may old, accepted, high voted link-only answers are there?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332862/839601)

Answer (score 13):

The flag was cast correctly... it is indeed a link-only answer.

However,

1. The question is five years old.
2. The answer has 50+ score.
3. It is the accepted answer.

Under these conditions, no moderator in their right mind would delete the answer, which is the action you are asking for when you cast a "link-only" moderator flag.

The moderator who declined the flag probably thought that *editing the answer to make it non-link-only* was a better solution.

Comment: Sure _editing the answer to make it non-link-only_ is a better solution. So moderator should have left a comment to OP and that would also helped me. Also, Where is consistency? When dealing with LOA. And moreover Is comment _ flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention_ justified

Comment: There are currently nearly 1200 moderator flags in the flag queue.  You'll forgive us if we don't always give each flag special attention.

Comment: Its not about me, I have encountered the question in moderation queue(20K plus, you know that) others also flagged for the same. So no need for special attention.

Comment: `There are currently nearly 1200 moderator flags in the flag queue. You'll forgive us if we don't always give each flag special attention.` -> I always see this excuse instead of getting new moderators on board. IMHO, this is not helping anyone. If the more work force is needed, you could get more moderators on board. It is unfortunate to see the excuse of "we do not have enough man power, so unfortunately that is it" reasoning all around as an excuse for some bad result.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: The OP came here to meta to find out why.  That's how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @Robert: 1 and 3 are moot as such answers do get deleted. I think the moderator decided not to delete due to the high number of upvotes, even though they had happened in the **past** before the new policy entered the site. When people see such highly upvoted historical answers, they usually will not downvote it because they know moderators would not care anyhow. It is a sad state of affairs for historically poor posts that were top posts in the past, but not anymore, and people do not upvote it anymore. Past upvotes really should not defend it from a different policy world.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I'm surprised I have to explain this, but I'll give it a try anyway.  *Removing an answer with 50 upvotes is tantamount to rep stealing; moderators simply will not do it.*  That goes double for accepted answers.  Converting to comment doesn't work either; too much information is lost.

Comment: Except that rep is preserved for old posts (>60 days). Wait, what? Too much information lost for a link?

Comment: Yeah, I knew you were going to bring that up.  We're not going to run the answer through a flowchart to make these kinds of decisions.  Fifty upvotes, game over.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: If you genuinely think we're handling these incorrectly, make a meta post about it, so that the community can discuss a possible change in policy.

Comment: Huh?! The whole point of Stack Overflow (to me and many) is that we find **quality** solutions resolved the last couple of years. When I look up for a solution with google, I will not care when it was answered. If it is an almost no-value rubbish post, high upvotes will not get me saved.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Write a meta post.  This one is about why the flag was declined.

Comment: `If you genuinely think we're handling these incorrectly, make a meta post about it, so that the community can discuss a possible change in policy.` -> Please re-read the topic: **How should accepted link-only answers be handled?**

Comment: *[sigh]* Are you genuinely advocating that any answer that has 50 score that the op has accepted on an on-topic question is subject to deletion?  I really don't think so.

Comment: `Are you genuinely advocating that any answer that has 50 score that the op has accepted on an on-topic question is subject to deletion?` -> The whole discussion is about **not any, but very poor**. And yes, some people seem to have an agreement here that what moderators do is incorrect, indeed, including me.

Comment: If a very poor answer got a score of 50, the community seriously screwed the pooch.

Comment: I can only re-quote myself: `When people see such highly upvoted historical answers, they usually will not downvote it because they know moderators would not care anyhow. It is a sad state of affairs for historically poor posts that were top posts in the past, but not anymore, and people do not upvote it anymore. Past upvotes really should not defend it from a different policy world.`

Comment: Why would you downvote it when you know moderators will not care anyway? How do you get 50 people really caring? You may get 5-10 which should still be *dominant* from this world since we live in this world, and you know, things have changed since the stone edge when people living in a cave? Those 50 upvotes from a completely different world have no value with today's rules.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted

Comment: Please read the [official policy on link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). I fail to see why a “moderator in their right mind” automatically would go against policy, with no good reason to put forward other than implicitly saying that the flagger is not in their right mind (which is [not nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)).

Comment: @Gilles: That would indeed be rude, had I actually said it.

Comment: _"no moderator in their right mind..."_ hm per my recollection, mods at Programmers and Workplace delete stuff like that, with comments like "expand your answer then flag for undeletion". I never could grok why SO mods are so afraid of doing so. Such deleted answers won't even go to audits, because of their positive score, there's nothing to loose

Comment: @gnat: I doubt very much that any of those answers were four year old, accepted answers with 50 upvotes, posted to on-topic questions.

Comment: It's amusing to me to imagine someone trying to figure out how to solve some programming problem, Googling it, breathing a sigh of relief that a perfectly worded-SO post is result number 1, clicking, and being aghast—AGHAST—that the top answer therein is a link-only answer.  Sure, it has 50 upvotes, is accepted, and perfectly solves the problem, but it's a **link only** damnit.  The user angrily wonders why has nobody deleted this post that clearly violates the FAQ, while going back to the Google results to find a more palatable answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis are you for real? I would claim just about any user that is actually searching for an answer would actually click the link, find the information and be happy about it. All the answers google gives are links as well, why would the user care if it's a link on google or a link on SO? Sure, it's better to have the answer directly in SO. That's the correct course of action, to add it there. That has also been done, the answer we debate on now contains the code.

Comment: @eis - no, not for real.  Was being sarcastic; we definitely agree :)

Comment: sorry, there's been so many opinions on this that my sarcasm detector is apparently broken. :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Are you aware that the owner of the website the answer linked to changed the code to include malware, once they noticed that their code was linked to from a popular answer? That is *precisely why* link-only answers are not acceptable, because *you have no idea what will be at that link, after you posted the answer*.

Answer (score -10):

You made a mistake.  You should:

- downvote the answer
- flag it as "Not an Answer"
- don't flag it as "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)"
- let the community handle it

Such low quality posts, whether accepted or not, ought to be deleted unless improved by the OP.  It's not a community wiki that everybody ought to work upon improving it.

Such answers ought to be converted into a comment by the moderators.

### --------------------------------------

It seems that [correct and complete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209873/why-was-a-correct-answer-deleted-and-converted-to-a-comment) answers can be deleted and converted to a comment by the moderators but if a *link-only* answer is accepted, then the community must improve it!

Comment: How do you expect the community to handle it? Even if you accumulate 52 downvotes, it'll still be pinned as the accepted answers. Non-moderators can't VtD accepted answers either. Without moderator intervention, that post ain't going anywhere.

Comment: What good does deletion at this point in time do? Is deleting an answer from 2008 just to make a point really worth it?

Comment: @Bart I'm not specifically talking about an answer from 2008.  It's something that you do run into often.

Comment: Yet part of the motivation to not do anything about this case seems to be "old, accepted, significant score". Which I can understand and don't necessarily disagree with.

Comment: @Bart All I can say that I have raised fair bit of flags for moderator attention and the responses to those seem rather inconsistent.  (Different mods, although I don't know who, seem to act differently in similar situations.)

Comment: @Bart "Which I can understand and don't necessarily disagree with."... I am a big fan of careful wording ;) And I agree with that wording.

Comment: @devnull You are correct, they have been handled somewhat inconsistently, historically. But recent Meta posts (now likely on Meta.SE) have been tweaking things there.

Comment: @AndrewBarber _somewhat_? _somewhat_?  Sorry, must disagree with the not-so-careful wording.  It almost confuses one how to or when to flag or not.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't necessarily disagree... ;)

Comment: NAA flags on accepted answers go to mods, just like custom flags, so the difference in flagging isn't really changing anything meaningful.  Also, for all you know the OP *did* downvote it.

Comment: @Servy All I know that mods are quick to delete [correct and not even containing a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209873/why-was-a-correct-answer-deleted-and-converted-to-a-comment) answers.

Comment: @devnull So long as they're not accepted, because apparently if the person least qualified to judge the correctness of the answer thinks it's correct then it couldn't possibly be of low quality.

Comment: @Bart [An answer from 2008, similar in quality to the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/119835/2235132) to the same question __was__ deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Your point being? That they are inconsistent?

Comment: @Bart Not consistent, it seems __whimsical__.