# Recommending off-site resources when questions don't ask for it

Tags: discussion

Every now and again, I see text similar to this in a question (**in an otherwise valid question**):

> ... or if anyone can recommend a library to do this, I'd appreciate it.

Since we have this close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I figure that the above part of the question is off topic and should be edited out.

Is this the correct course of action?

---

And then there's answers that recommend off-site resources regardless of whether the question asks for it or not, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/119473#119473) (recommending a highlighting plugin as an answer to a question asking how to highlight a word).

Now [people call it a link-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled?cb=1). Okay, but you probably can't really edit it to include context from the link, unless you add something like:

> This plugin highlights various parts of text such as ... and allows you to ...

But that doesn't change the fact that you're recommending an off-site resource and, since asking for it isn't allowed (as per the above close reason), presumably recommending it shouldn't be allowed for the same reason.

So, is this answer unsalvageably invalid for this reason?

---

This does use the same example as the above-linked discussion, but asks a different question altogether, so I don't believe it's even remotely close to a duplicate of that.

I realize that is an old answer and should maybe be treated differently for that reason (sorry, I don't really have a newer example on hand), but the general question should hold regardless.

**However**, while it makes sense to do this from the link-only-answer aspect, it doesn't seem to make sense to do it from the recommending-an-off-site-resource aspect, much in the same way an old popular question asking for an off-site resource should be closed (except that closing doesn't imply deletion, so ... convert the answer to a comment instead?).

Or am I just misunderstanding the motivation behind this close reason?

Comment: Surely there is a lot of useful information on other parts of the interwebs. I don't see that it would make sense to ban us from referencing the web. Surely that can't be the logic behind this "close reason"

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier If I'm following your argument, you're essentially implying we should get rid of this close reason completely. Otherwise, I'm not following.

Comment: No I'm saying answers should be allowed to reference the net. I agree with most of the words on this post that when a question asks for just a link it is wrong. So I guess - I support the "close reason" for questions, but also support allowing us to provide answers that reference useful info.

Comment: eg if I may be so bold ... ;-) I think this answer of mine is "OK", and I feel the links I put in it add value which would otherwise be lost. ymmv http://stackoverflow.com/a/23154946/383414

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I'm all for answering the question and additionally providing links (as you did), but I am (or at least tried) focussing specifically on off-site resources **as** answers in my question - ones where no amount of editing gets around the fact that you're saying "Use this library / tool / plugin / whatever" (you can explain why it should be used, or how it solves the problem, but you're still recommending an off-site resource).

Comment: aha - I would be against banning such answers as a base rule. A link only answer is poor, however an answer that provides the most useful info as a link, with an explanation; I would support that. my 2c

Answer (score 49):

### tl;dr;

There is absolutely nothing wrong with tool recommendation answers when done correctly.

The specific close reason that your are referencing has nothing to do with the answers that provide recommendations, but everything with the level of moderation that is needed to keep the site clean.  **Questions** that ask for these things attract a significant quantity of poor quality answers, but a general question that can be solved by a tool (without explicitly asking for them) doesn't require the same level of attention, and restricting the answers to eliminate any and all recommendations would deprive a many askers of perfectly valid solutions.

---

> Or am I just misunderstanding the motivation behind this close reason?

I believe you may be misunderstanding the purpose of the close reason.  The issue isn't really the answer recommending the tool, or the recommendation itself.  The issue is questions explicitly asking for *something* (tool, library, book, etc) turn into popularity contests as well as magnets for spam and other low quality answers.

This issue is somewhat mitigated when the question doesn't actually ask for a tool.  If the answer is a good quality answer and recommends a tool to solve a specific problem, then the answer is ok.  And if the question isn't asking for a tool to solve it's problem, then the question is ok too.

---

Sometimes the answer to a problem is a tool, even if the question doesn't ask for it (and
if it does ask for it then you should edit the tool request out or vote to close the question).

But if the question is on-topic and if the answer is a tool does that mean you shouldn't answer the question?  Why not?  If you have knowledge that can help solve the specific problem, then you should provide the answer.  However, you shouldn't just provide a link to the tool.  At an absolute minimum you should explain why the tool solves the problem, and ideally you should show the usage of the tool and include some code to show how the tool solves the problem.

You concern here seems to revolve around the fact that recommendation is the problem.  At the core, the problem is not the recommendation itself.  Recommendation type answers can be good or bad, just like regular answers.

A bad recommendation can be

- Link-only with no context
- Spam
- Blatant self promotion

But a good recommendation can solve a specific problem.  It usually:

- Include a lot more context
- Explains **why** it solves the problem
- Explains **how** it solves the problem
- Shows how to use the tool/library

So answers that recommend a tool can be extremely valuable if done correctly.  Similar, many questions on Stack Overflow are solved with a tool or library.  Why make someone reinvent the wheel if someone already did the work and you only need to implement it in your own project.

The problem is with the moderation surrounding tool recommendations.  A high percentage of tool recommendations are link only answers, or are otherwise bad.  These need to be dealt with appropriately (nuked on sight, converted to a comment, or edited to fix the question), but why should a good quality answer suffer the same fate simply because it says

> There is a tool that will solve your problem.  You can get it `<here>` and this is how you use it...

So when you encounter one, you need to decide if the content is valuable or not.  If it isn't then moderate it appropriately, but if the answer is good and the question isn't asking for it, then there is really nothing wrong with the answer.

There is a side issue of tools not aging well, that isn't really addressed because I see them as only marginally different than many non-recommendation answers.  Tools, libraries, and languages all change over time, so if they are not kept up to date, they become obsolete.  Since this is a systemic problem and not one isolated to tools, I don't think that alone should be a reason to eliminate any and all tool recommendations from the site.

Comment: If the only 'acceptable' answer is a tool, I'm not sure I agree that the question is on topic - you can surely phrase any question asking for an off-site resource in such a way that it doesn't directly ask for an off-site resource any more, making it on topic (thus the close reason is largely pointless).

Comment: @Dukeling you are misunderstanding the close reason then.  I've tried to clarify it a bit.

Comment: I still don't really get why "I'm looking for a library to foo the bar" is off topic, while "How do I foo the bar?" can be okay (same foos and bars), given that the conversion between the two is **trivial** ... or why the popularity contest thing magically won't happen because the question doesn't contains the text "looking for a library" or similar. Or is the reason just there for things like "I'm looking for a graph library" which really has no appropriate alternative, in which case I'm willing to bet that a significant amount of uses of this reason has been misuse.

Comment: @Dukeling I wasn't around (or at least active) when that decision was made so I can't really provide much insight into the decision beyond my MSE experience.  However, even if the question is `how can I foo the bar` and one of the possible answers is a tool, why in the world would you deny someone a good answer simply because the best answer revolves around a tool.  If the answer is of good quality, it shouldn't matter whether it is a block of code or a tool to solve the problem.

Comment: If the best answer revolves around a tool, the question *likely* needs more focus. Solving it "manually" would be unwieldy (or the tool wouldn't be so necessary), and using the tool entails obtaining it, getting oriented with it and then writing the code specific to the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I completely disagree.  There are problems that people have that can be easily solved by a tool/library.  The problem is that the OP doesn't know the tool/library exists.  So why do we need to make them jump through hopes just to get the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pretty much covered my view on this, but I'd like to raise one point about questions that do ask for an off-site resource. See the close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam.

So the reason these questions are frowned upon is that they attract opinions and popularity contests. But I interpret that to mean that *if there are no opinions to argue about, asking for an off-site resource should be fine*.

I have an example of this, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961733/oracle-java-code-conventions). It is asking about a specific resource directly related to programming, so there shouldn't be any popularity contests (see the comments there as well). I think it's a question that is ok to ask, even if it is asking for an off-site resource.

Comment: I, on the other hand, put a bit more weight into "they *tend* to". I read the reason as something along the lines of "While this question may not itself attract opinionated answers and spam, due to a tendency of questions asking for an off-site resource attracting opinionated answers and spam, we have decided that **all** such questions are off topic." (but I guess only SE staff can confirm that one way or the other)

Answer (score -4):

The title here is

> Recommending off-site resources when questions don't ask for it

but the offending question text is

> ... or if anyone can recommend a library to do this, I'd appreciate
>   it.

which arguably is in the question. Personally I dislike it because it's effectively two questions in one.

However, a library recommendation need necessarily be in the form of an answer. It could be (and perhaps should be) a comment, much like 'see this other stackoverflow answer' is.

Perhaps a useful edit, where off-site resources are useful but do not answer the headline question, would be to add "(in comments)", thus:

> ... or if anyone can recommend a library to do this (in comments), I'd appreciate
>   it.