# Canned responses for First Posts from new members

Tags: discussion

I recently hit 500 rep here on Stack Overflow and I've started entertaining the review section of the site. Since I'm new to that section of the site this may already be available and I am just unable to locate it.

When going through the [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) section of the review page I find that on several occasions the questions are not un-salvagable, but just poorly written to the point that they really shouldn't be flagged, but they aren't complete either. Most of the time it is obvious that someone signed up for the site just to ask their question and did not take the time to review the help pages such as [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), etc...

I have seen in the past where established members within SO have placed comments on questions from new users that help direct them to specific how-to posts or to the help sections.

Here is an example of one I have recently seen:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

My Question:
**Is there a listing of canned responses that can be copy-pasted for this type of scenario?**

If there isn't any real sort of *accepted* responses, then maybe this would be a great place to come up with a few and have a wiki created. I also think that if there was some way to shortcut in a "new user how-to" comment in the add comment box, that would be helpful as well. These comments could be generated somewhat personalized like the following:

> Hello @[OPusername] and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Complete Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

I know that having cookie-cutter responses isn't really ideal in a community that values and is driven by user input, however I see it done so often that it seems it would be beneficial to have some level of standardization.

Comment: [Auto Review Comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: Keep in mind the user wasn't allowed to ask their question without confirming that they had already read "how to ask".  A comment like that, just putting the link that they already claimed to have read, isn't likely to be helpful.  Either they'll have already read the page, or they aren't going to in response to your comment.

Comment: @Servy Well it doesn't have to be that link specifically. I was just using it as an example. Also that asking the user to confirm they read something before asking a question is like clicking the `Agree` button on a terms of service when installing new software. How many people actually read it vs. how many just click and go?

Comment: @BrandonB I'm well aware that most people aren't going to read the link, but the point remains that all of the people that won't read the link the first time, aren't going to read the link the second time you show it to them either.

Comment: I wonder whether this shall be a discussion, support-request or feature-request too. Care to resolve that?

Comment: Maybe, it shall be a discussion regarding the support of the review section and a possible feature inclusion on the "First Posts" section.

Comment: @BrandonB No.  Either you're proposing a new feature, you're requesting help on how to use a feature of the site, or it's neither (aka [meta-tag:discussion]).

Comment: @Servy I disagree with your first comment. I think confirming when making the question and getting the recommendation to read such topics in a comment have completely different impacts. The fact that someone responded is of great encouragement to the user, especially a new one. That encouragement can possibly lead them to actually reading those documents more closely.

Comment: @JordanHanna I've seen *lots* of comments like that, I've yet to see a single case where the author indicated that they read them as a result.

Comment: @Servy: Do you mean a comment in which the OP explicitly says "OK, I [re]read [X], and now I get what I did wrong"? Because no, I've probably never seen that either. On the other hand, responses that address the issue raised by a boilerplated link (or its surrounding text) are quite common; I can link several in the last few days. The actual incidence of useful (re-)reading is therefore doubtless somewhere between those.

Comment: In the "Low Quality Posts" review there is a text box that allows you to choose a canned comment, depending on whether it is a "thank you" answer, a link-only answer etc... I guess it could be widespread to other review queues

Comment: You'll also want to look into the [comment shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), such as `[ask]` becoming [ask].

Comment: We need these canned responses, but not with comments, but with flags (or some fancy new wording)

Answer (score 30):

I have a moderately customized install of [Auto-Review Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). Only about half of them are for questions, and not all of them are intended for posts I'm about to flag, either. But the more important thing is that I can and do customize those before posting; one or two, in fact, flat-out don't work without my typing something else in the box, while several others are frequently tweaked on application, often by removing chunks that don't apply or adding in conditional clarifications. Comments that overlap with the autocomments the site inserts at various points (close reasons, VLQ) or that just rehash the readily-available guidance — without really engaging what parts are relevant and why — are a lot closer to noise, but I've had some good results with a number of these.

Here's the most common templates:

`###[A] Answers just to say Thanks!
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.`

`###[A] Nothing but a URL to answer (and isn't spam)
While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.`

`###[A] Nothing but a URL to tool (and isn't spam or NAA)
Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.`

`###[A] Attempts to clarify
This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment).`

`###[A] Adding a new question as an answer
If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.`

`###[A] Another user adding a related question as answer
If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button; you may want to include a link to this one for context. Or you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) it.`

`###[A] Another user adding a 'Me too!'
Please don't post "me too" as an answer. Instead, you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) it.`

`###[Q] Missing info
Please [edit] your question to [type here]. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!`

`###[Q] Needs reduction
That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?`

`###[Q] Self-answers in a comment/question
You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself.`

`###[Q] No code in question
Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!`

`###[Q] Website is "broken", no code in question, just link to site
Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!`

`###Wrong language
[$SITENAME$ generally works in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it.`

`###Don't just fiddle
In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!`

`###[A] Code-only
Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.`

Comment: @NathanTuggy Over time I added/adapted several canned responses. I posted them in a [separate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366642/4298200). You might find some useful. Also I "hacked" some headlines into the UI, they might be useful to you too

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't *not* flag a post just because it could possibly be salvaged.  If a question is currently unanswerable due to significant problems that will require the author to address before the question is answerable then you should absolutely be voting/flagging the question for closure.

The primary purpose of closing questions is to provide an opportunity for the question to be improved such that it can be reopened, without allowing users to post low quality answers to the question while it is in state likely to attract low quality answers and not high quality answers.

Of course, if you can personally fix whatever problem(s) the question has personally, then you also have the option of editing the post rather than voting/flagging for closure, but since such a large percentage of problems a question can have will require the author's input, this is not often an option.

The information that you're trying to convey is *already conveyed through the close reasons*.  If you want to comment with more specific advice that's tailored to the question at hand, then you're welcome to do so.  If you're only going to be providing a cookie cutter response about typical problems with a question that cause it to be inappropriate for the site, then they already exist *as the close reasons*.

Comment: I will often rephrase the "questions seeking debugging help must..." close reason as "You're more likely to get useful help if you edit your question to include example inputs, the expected outputs and the actual outputs or full stack traces." (or whatever is missing), which has a surprisingly decent action rate.  From experience I can usually tell which askers care and which aren't worth bothering with, though.

Comment: "You shouldn't not flag a post just because it could possibly be salvaged" the new Triage queue is confusing in this context, because its UI suggests that you should close only unsalvageable posts.

Comment: It's also confusing when you get a flag declined because your comment led to the user fixing a question that initially richly deserved closing. On the one hand, great, we short-circuited that whole messy unreliable process of closing and reopening within just a few hours. On the other hand... flag declined.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is heavily base on [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287278/4298200) provided by [Nathan Tuggy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099598/nathan-tuggy), but I changed it quite a bit. Like him I am also using [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). Over time I added some responses, changed the wording and provided more links to useful resources. Also it became really hard to find the appropriate response as there were so many, so I sorted them into categories and added headlines to each.

All responses should be short enough to fit into the comment box. Because of the welcome message and some placeholders (like `$SITENAME$`) being replaced, they might occasionally be longer. If so let me know so I can shorten the response

I will update this post over time as I add/modify these canned responses: If you have some canned responses which are missing, feel free to add them. Also please do correct any spelling/grammar mistakes you find!

```
### <div/>
<h1><font color="black">MIXING COMMENT/ANSWER/QUESTION</font></h1>

###[A] OP answers follow-up questions from comments
Thanks for answering follow-up question. Unfortunately you have posted your reply as an answer to your own question. Please instead reply with a comment. Make sure to mention the person who asked the question using the [@USER notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/316262) so they will get notified of your reply.

###[A] OP adds information to question as answer
Thanks for providing additional information. Unfortunately you have posted that information as a reply to your own question, instead of editing it. Please go back to your question, [edit it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/316262) and provide any relevant information there. This will increase your chances of getting fitting answers to your question

###[Q] OP answers follow-up questions in comments
Thanks for answering follow-up questions to your question, but please instead [edit] your question to add any relevant information. Any question on $SITENAME$ should make sense on its own so that other users finding this question in the future won't have to dig through all the comments to understand your post. Also search engines will do a better job of finding your post if everything is at the right place.

###[A] Answers just to say Thanks!
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain the [privilege](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to [upvote](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/vote-up) answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.

###[A] New question as an answer
Please don't post new questions as answers. You can ask a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. By adding answers as questions you just add noise and make it more difficult for others to find actual answers to this question.

###[A]'Me too!'
Please don't post "me too" as an answer. Instead, you may [star this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/316262) as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) this question, which will make it more likely to be answered.

###[Q] Self-answers in a comment/question
It is great, that your solution has been solved. But please post the solution as a new answer. If it is the best (or only) answer to your question make sure to also [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/316262) it, so others know this problem has a working solution.



### <div/>
<h1><font color="black">CONTENT MISSING/NEEDS REDUCTION</font></h1>

###[Q] No code in question
Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem will increase your chances of getting good answers.

###[Q] Needs reduction
That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code until you have a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem? This will increase your chances of getting good answers.

###[Q] General missing info
This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Providing a [mcve] will increase your chances of getting good answers.

###[A] Code-only
Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.



### <div/>
<h1><font color="black">EXTERNAL CONTENT</font></h1>

### Code hosted on external site
In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and [**don't** just include a link to a code hosting site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/316262). Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

###[A] Only URL to tool
Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above. If you can't provide that, consider [writing a comment](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment) instead.

###[A] Link to external answer
While this resource may answer the question, [it is necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and ideally to provide the link for reference. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

###[A] Link to SO answer
While this other answer may help solve the problem, [it is necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and ideally to provide the link for reference. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that question was closed/deleted/migrated.



### <div/>
<h1><font color="black">FORMATTING</font></h1>

###[Q] General formatting
As it is, this question suffers from poor formatting, making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Is the code properly [marked and indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Did you use enough paragraphs and [other formatting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)? Please [edit] your question until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [ask]. Well formatted questions have a higher chance of getting good answers.

###[Q] Not marked as code
The code you posted is not properly [marked as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262), making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please [edit] your question until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [ask]. Well formatted questions have a higher chance of getting good answers.

###[Q] Code not indented
The code you posted is not properly [indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262), making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please [edit] your question until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [ask]. Well formatted questions have a higher chance of getting good answers.

###[A] General formatting
Thank you for answering. As it is, this answer is poorly formatted, making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting. Is the code properly [marked and indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Did you use enough paragraphs and [other formatting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)? Please [edit] your post until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [answer]. Well formatted answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.

###[A] Not marked as code
Thanks you for posting an answer to this question. The code you posted is not properly [marked as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262), making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please [edit] your post until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [answer]. Well formatted answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.

###[A] Code not indented
Thanks you for posting an answer to this question. The code you posted is not properly [indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262), making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please [edit] your post until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [answer]. Well formatted answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.

###[A] Use of "EDIT:" and "UPDATE:"
Thanks for providing additional information to your post by using the [edit] functionality. But please don't pollute your post with `EDIT:` or `UPDATE:` sections. [For future readers, posts need to be standalone, without any history. These sites are not forums, but intend to be libraries of canonical, high-quality, questions and answers. Future readers are not helped by seeing all kind of history.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262)

### Code/Error as screenshot
Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.



### <div/>
<h1><font color="black">OTHER</font></h1>

###[A] Wrong language
[$SITENAME$ generally works in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it.

###[Q] Vote and accept
Your question already has answers. You can [upvote and accept](https://$SITEURL$/help/someone-answers) any quality answer. You can upvote all good answers, but accept only one. [Accepting an answer](https://$SITEURL$/help/accepted-answer) will give you some reputation and also ensure that others seeking help will know immediately that this problem has already been solved.

###[Q] WEB-related: Website is "broken", link only
Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/).





---- don't copy me, I am just here to make selecting all text easier ----
```