# Handle new answers to old questions

Tags: support, answers, new-users, old-questions

I'm very new to reviewing answers, and I found a new one by a new user at this question [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) asked 7 years ago. I downvoted it, but I'd like to be sure, how should I handle this kind of situations?

Comment: Which answer? Click on the 'share' link on the bottom left of the post to get a URL linking directly to the answer.

Comment: @remyabel the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24853/timeline) shows protection, but no question.  Presuambly it was deleted quickly after being asked.

Comment: I noticed just now that that answer has been deleted

Comment: Then your response (downvote) was likely the right one.

Comment: That [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28835784/961113) was more of a spam

Comment: @MichaelT: Trust us, it was clear-cut spam, and not simply bad. Meaning only flagging for removal, preferably as SPAM, would be the right response.

Comment: If the reason why you downvoted it is because it was 7 years old, then clearly it's very wrong.

Comment: @Sebas The reasoning was wrong, the outcome good.

Comment: Note: when you find a post with *spam* (i.e. a post that is clearly posted with the sole intent of advertising something, not just something useless) you should flag it as spam, but do *not* downvote it! If that post is a question it might receive a few downvotes, and hence disappear from the frontpage and then it will then take more time for people to flag as spam and destroy it (because they cannot easily find it in the frontpage). Flags for spam will remove 100 reputation from the user anyway, so a few downvotes don't really matter.

Comment: @Sebas: I downvoted the answer, which was posted yesterday, and not the question!
As a matter of facts I'd like to know what am I supposed to do if I find a legit answer to an old question?

Comment: There can be many reasons why providing an answer to an old question is good, there is even the [necromancer badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) to encourage good answers to old questions. Sometimes old questions need updated answers and sometimes old questions have only so-so answers that leave room for well written new answers. So good answers to old questions should be upvoted if they fill in some sort of gap.

Comment: @Phate01 yes I understood. My comment was not phrased correctly but that's what I meant.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't have 10k, so I can't check the answer in question. This is just going to be general advice.

A new answer **can** be perfectly legitimate and even deserve upvotes. However, statistically there's a greatly elevated chance that a new user's first post will be spam, a misplaced comment or question, or generally garbage. So review is there to **distinguish** those cases and handle them appropriately.

Therefore, when reviewing, start out by taking some time to consider each of several possible flaws a post can have; FP and LA, unfortunately, cover a broad spectrum, so you have to keep a flexible focus and not simply hit No Action Needed just because it passes a couple of the smell tests. You'll want to run through these in approximately this order to avoid wasting time or missing something important. (Although you probably won't need to refer to this every time. I hope.)

#### The easy stuff

In LA specifically, if you see something that:

- Looks like spam:

  - It probably is. Flag as such. Don't comment.
- Is rude, profane, whatever:

  - Flag as such. Don't bother commenting in most cases.
- Is a misplaced comment or vote — anything that just asks the OP if they still have the problem, thanks someone for helping, confirms that a posted solution worked, is nothing more than a diagnostic to help get to the actual problem for an actual answer to solve, or similar:

  - Flag as NAA; if possible, comment to tell the user not to do that again.
- Is a misplaced question, asking for more answers or ones that fit some slightly different situation or even a completely different situation:

  - Flag as NAA and comment if possible.
- Is (nearly) unreadable, perhaps because it's not in English:

  - Flag as VLQ. Comment in the latter case (since SO, and indeed most of the SE network, is English-only by policy), and perhaps in the former.
- An answer to a different question (no, seriously):

  - Flag as VLQ and perhaps comment. (In practice, because VLQ and NAA mostly feed into the same queue now, they're largely interchangeable, but this may not always be the case; the strictly correct thing to do with a post that's legitimately an answer but in the wrong place is to VLQ-flag it, not NAA.)
- Is a link-only answer — boiled down to its essence, consists of nothing more than a URL of the actual answer, without paraphrase, amendment, or tips included:

  - A signpost to the real answer is Not An Answer, and should be flagged accordingly and commented if possible.
  - Links to tool downloads generally don't qualify as such, but *may* be spam, see above. Otherwise, you might comment that more information around the bare tool link would be helpful.
- Is something you have no idea what to even what:

  - Skip this sucker!
- Is something that will take you way too long to work through:

  - Skip!
- Is something that makes you feel too lazy to even try:

  - Skip!
- Has something wrong with the post, but there's a suggested edit pending:

  - Skip!

#### The sneaky stuff

In LA specifically, if you see something that:

- Looks mostly OK, but has a link to a site that's not well-known or allows user content (like GitHub, Blogspot, etc):

  - Check the link carefully; if blatant spam:

    - Flag as such. Don't comment.
    - Otherwise, check the author's profile and see if they're self-promoting a lot or without disclaiming; if it's fairly plain:

      - Flag as spam. Don't comment.
      - Otherwise flag ♦ and explain that it's subtle spam. Don't comment unless it's the sort of self-promotion that might be a legitimate mistake.
- Is plagiarism (often from the accepted answer to the same question; often spam too):

  - Flag for ♦ intervention, and explain what it's plagiarized from. Comment if it seems like it could be an honest mistake.
- Is wrong, generally a lousy hack, or otherwise well below par:

  - Downvote; comment if practical.

#### Spit and polish

In FP or LA, if you see something that:

- Has something you can only partly fix or address:

  - Edit or comment, then
  - Skip! (You may be noticing a pattern here. Skipping is *always* a correct response. It may not be as useful as it could be, since someone still has to review it, but it's far better than giving a bogus review, of any sort.)
- Is poorly spelled or formatted or whatever, but in a way that you can fix yourself:

  - Edit to fix it.
- Includes a signature, greetings, best wishes, worry that it's too late to post something, a note that the poster had the same problem (assuming the post also contains the solution they used; otherwise it's NAA, see above), a vague declaration that searches were made or days were spent tearing out hair, or similar well-meaning noise.

  - Edit to remove. Don't comment, but do make sure to note in the summary.
- Could use some changes by the OP to make it better:

  - Comment.
- Is, perhaps surprisingly, a good answer already:

  - Upvote of course. Comment if there's something in particular to call attention to.
- Doesn't manage to meet *even a single one of the above categories*:

  - No Action Needed, at last.

There's a good deal of guidance around proper flagging for various categories, and you should look into that for a more complete understanding. But if you misflag occasionally, you'll generally get feedback, albeit rather tersely, and can then figure out what you got wrong.

You might notice after a while that the comments on a lot of these get pretty repetitive. If so, consider digging up a prefab comment list/tool, perhaps one such as [my list here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287278/4099598), but handle with care: dumping thoughtless autocomments where they only partly apply can be rude and not particularly helpful.

Comment: So you know, the answer was spam. It and the account were destroyed

Comment: I gathered as much from the comments, but I figured hey, teachable moment?

Comment: For sure. Its a good answer!

Comment: This ought to be linked from somewhere in the FP/LA interface -- it's way better guidance than the current help text.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I wonder if I should expand this a bit to cover FP more thoroughly and repost with a new self-answer question.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I have [now done so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/4099598)!