# Too much importance given to the lack of context explanation for a link in an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, late-answers

This is not the first time I'm audited while reviewing an answer which:

- Contains a link to a solution
- Also contains the solution itself
- But doesn't contain a summary of the linked resource.

Here is an example:
[Excel ADODB VBA error msg 'Not a Valid Password'](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7457398)

> [image]
>
> The linked resource:
>
> [image]

While I agree that the answer could have been written better, it provides all the information which is in the linked resource itself. Note that the MS page poster clearly mentions that the solution works, but the reason why is unknown to him. On the other hand, the SO question has no accepted answer, and the answer being reviewed really brings something new and useful.

Should I really down-vote it, and provide the explanation that the link should be associated with a short description, etc? (Actually this guideline had already been provided earlier).

Comment: as the comment already there states, it **might** be a good answer, but the content **should** be here

Comment: @Plutonix: the content *is* here, the useful part of the solution is in the post.

Comment: @mins: Well, the post didn't make it clear that it already summarized the content of the linked page ... changing that "OR" to "which says that" would be sufficient here.

Comment: This is an ambiguous audit at best; a wrong audit, if you ask me. They can't all be great. Forget about it and move on.

Comment: @SamB  So people must formally state what they are doing everytime they do it "I here by affirm that the words in this answer fully represent the content in the aforementioned linked page completely in total. The previous statement was not part of the answer. Nor that last statement." The only people I can see having made this mistake are people who didn't actually read the answer, and just glanced and didn't see the link was followed by what was essentially an answer on its own.  Such individuals are willfully illiterate, having chosen not to exercise the basic exercise of reading.

Comment: I'd just like to formally state the above was a comment.  Please do not flag it as "Not a comment", because just to clarify for anyone who might not have read it, it is not an answer nor is it a question. It is a comment.

Comment: @AaronLS: It's not our fault if our eyes glaze over about halfway through a URL of that length! Honest! (Plus, the answer implied that what turned out to be the summary was actually an alternative.)

Comment: @SamB I'm sure the intention is good, I just don't want those who agree with to universally apply that as justification for a close/delete. Mainly 1) If someone is going to do a review, flag, or close vote, they should be taking the time to read carefully. Those are serious actions and no one should be shooting from the hip.  2) Sloppy formatting while not great, shouldn't be justification for any of these actions.  3) Certainly good formatting should be encouraged through comments/edits, such as a footnoted link with abbreviated link text would make it much more readable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is not a link-only answer - it contains the exact same solution as the *accepted answer*. It should not have been deleted through review, and it is a bad audit.

It probably does deserve to be deleted on the grounds that it adds nothing new to the accepted answer that was posted more than two years previously, but that is a call for moderators to make - not reviewers in the First Posts or Late Answers queue.

Comment: Ehm, in the LA queue is the natural place to check for such duplication, and to a lesser extent also in the FP queue. Where else should it be done? Now *how exactly* it should be deleted, that may be up to debate.

Comment: It seems to me you've already agreed that it belongs in LA (*on the grounds that it adds nothing new to the accepted answer that was **posted more than two years previously***). It's a *perfect call* for reviewers in the LA queue to be making.

Comment: ["At 20 reviews a day limit, one has plenty time to do more thorough check of reviewed posts before clicking Looks OK..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251155/165773)

Comment: @gnat: Interesting question actually \(I'm inviting everyone to [look at it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251155/165773)\). Audits are what they are, sometime they are bad, and the moral is written in the last comments: **Loko**: « I'm not complaining about being "banned" Im just saying some audits are just impossible. » **Martijn Pieters**: « Yup, and we know that already. That's not going to change. »

Answer (score 10):

IMO, an answer should always contain a summary in the answer itself. It doesn't happen often, but on occasion even Microsoft's web pages are unreachable, or something gets moved that shouldn't have, or becomes obsolete and simply disappears.

It wouldn't have taken but a minute or two to provide the summary, and the link as additional reference, and then the content is available no matter what happens to the external page. Posting a link-only answer is simply trying to FGITW your way into being first and getting rep quick. It doesn't do anything to provide persistent information that will always be readily available for future users.

Comment: Iver the last few days, I've run into 6-8 MSDN links here on very old SO answers which are dead.

Comment: @Plutonix: And I've run into them frequently elsewhere as well, via a Google search or a blog post somewhere or an older user forum post.

Comment: If you look at the post, it contains the useful part of the answer found in the linked resource.

Comment: @mins: Yes, it's there, hidden amid the clutter of the link. Why not state it clearly by itself (with some additional detail) and then add the link *separately* for more information to make it easier to pick out? Again, takes just a moment longer, and the answer's clarity is vastly improved.

Comment: While I definitely agree on this guideline in general, I'm not yet convinced in this very case.

Comment: Well, that answer belongs deleted, for only duplicating part of another answer, badly. Not really for being link-only. Curiously, there's a "me-too"-question-as-answer still on that page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24461678

Comment: @mins: Ok. I don't like the useful information buried away, and would always prefer to see it clearly where it can be found easily, in 100% of the cases. You posted asking for discussion, and I've provided my feedback.  We'll have to accept that we don't agree on this one. IMO, the part that's almost lost after the link (it actually at first glance just looks like the link is broken because of wrapping) should be stated *first*, and then a reference to the MS page added as a *see also* type reference.

Comment: @KenWhite. That's naturally how I see it. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: It's not uncommon for links to MSDN, TechNet, or KB to permanently go bad due to various reasons, ranging from pages being retired to website restructuring. Just recently I had to fix a link in one of my answers, because Microsoft decided to move that particular piece of documentation elsewhere.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers They are notorious for that.

Answer (score 7):

That post is a perfect review-audit for the **Late-Answer**-queue.

The LAQ deals with an extremely diverse amount of bad posts, interspersed with some real gems (and also some marginal answers).

While in the other queues there are relatively few different ways a post can be bad, in the LAQ there are all the possibilities found in the other queues, far more common duplication, and lots more SPAM or otherwise delete-worthy posts.

See [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505) for a writeup of all the things to test for. Beware: It's a really long list!

In this case, the comment link-only-answer is trivially proven wrong: The second part of the answer contains everything of relevance, even if it's a bit hidden. Here the full answer, emphasis by me:

> Please refer Microsoft link as below
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13612ba0-f8cf-4c5d-b1db-96076e8ade70/error-while-connecting-access-2010-with-vba?forum=accessdev
>   OR **you can set Access->File->Options->Client Settings->Advanced and check "use legacy encryption"**.

But there's another reason to schedule it for deletion in the LAQ:
It does a really shoddy job of duplicating far older answers (years!).

Thus, you should have done this, in order:

1. Downvoted it.
2. Commented about the duplication.
3. VLQ-flagged for deletion.
4. If you can DELETE-vote, do so.

Comment: Thanks for you time commenting and answering, I accept this as a useful recommendation, and understand better the reasons behind LAQ existence . Note that step 2 requires to open the question page, and read the other answers provided. This actually lead to another question (I'm not suggesting you should answer it)... why not provide the other answers in the review page systematically?

Comment: @mins: Presumably because it would take up too much space, but honestly I'm not sure; sticking them below the question would work fairly well, seems to me.

Answer (score 3):

If the author had written **the relevant part** in its answer, it would have been a good answer citing its sources. But it has not.

The relevant part is : **remove the password**, go into Access->File->Options->Client Settings->Advanced and check "use legacy encryption", **then recreate the password**.

Without those elements it **is** a link-only answer because it cannot be unterstood without the link. And as it did not need much to be added, it shows that author had made no effort.

Comment: Actually, he wrote out the relevant part. So the comment is bogus. But the answer still belongs deleted, for duplicating far older answers, and at that badly.

Comment: @Deduplicator : when I read the answer alone (without reading other answers or the link) I did not understand immediately what should be done ... Ok, I read it with a minimal attention, but honestly 7 words to add should not be too much :-)

Comment: The NAA-queue-comment is a red hering, and *should not have been posted at all*. What you are missing is that this is the LAQ, which means lots more scrutiny for duplication and other things is needed. Added my own answer finally.

Answer (score 3):

Like so many other audits, this post should indeed have been deleted, but the comments displayed when you fail are *actively misleading*. Do not assume that just because *one* reviewer thought it was NAA that it was deleted for that reason, or even if it was, that that was actually the right way of doing so.

Assume instead that comments are almost as wrong as the posts themselves, and evaluate the whole thing on its own merits or lack thereof.

Comment: That's unfortunately true about review comments. Many people think one really has to select a canned comment, even though the default is "no comment needed".

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah; since gaining access to LQP I've been a little surprised at how relatively seldom the canned comments are useful there, compared to either a) how often they show up on posts I see or b) the canned comments from the script I use. Probably because you can't customize them, so maybe a third or half of their potential uses go from "sure, just tweak it thoroughly" to "nahhhh".

Answer (score 2):

You should have selected to `Edit` the answer because in its current state it's pretty poor.

If you haven't go the time or expertise for an edit then `Skip`. If an `Edit` option isn't available then you can still bring up the original post by (middle) clicking on the question title (which may be underneath the post being audited) and then skipping the review.

Whichever option you take, think of quality. Just because the answer being reviewed contains an answer that doesn't mean it's in an acceptable state.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the audit caught me when I up-voted the answer, I had no opportunity to go further. I'm not sure, the Edit button might have been be grayed. Anyway I'll remember your suggestion which is good, and yep the answer might have been a wrong one too.

Comment: Are you sure there's any value to editing an answer which duplicates a much older answer poorly so it just duplicates?

Comment: @Deduplicator When you are in the edit queue you do not have immediate visibility of the other answers, therefore you have no idea if it closely resembles another answer. So you have to deal with the review in isolation to the other answers.

Comment: It's the LA queue, not the edit queue. And in that queue, one has to deal with answers badly restating something in another far older answer. Editing it to not suck quite as much when duplicating far older answers does not help any.

Answer (score -1):

Most importantly web links may be down in future or url may change.

Therefore, when providing links the poster should always include the key concepts or solution in his answer, at least in short. Any "please refer to " posts cleary don't help, even if the OP may have found the link himself by research.

Comment: Actually, he wrote out the relevant part. So the comment is bogus. But the answer still belongs deleted, for duplicating far older answers, and at that badly.