# 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290096/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, April 13th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: I should point out that these are questions for *candidates* to answer, so please don't use comments below them to leave your own answers. If you have questions or clarifications about the proposed questions, comment away, but the point is to see how the candidates will respond to them.

Comment: Will candidates look at the present answers, to better write their ones? Our Q&A style wasn't meant for a questionnaire.

Comment: @Joiner In the past, they've created a separate question with a list of all of the questions. Then the candidates post an answer to answer the questions.  [See 2014 noms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)

Comment: @bluefeet Same problem.

Comment: @Joiner While it might not be ideal, it works.

Comment: Why not create another meta post for the candidates only to answer?

Comment: @KronoS That will happen later.

Comment: @bluefeet ah I see now.

Answer (score 160):

A question is asked and receives some very good answers. The asker then flags this question and asks for it to be deleted because having it up will cause them trouble at work or school. Do you delete the question?

Comment: Do what Brad would do.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - That may not always work out so well.

Comment: With your rep and moderator status, wouldn't following be a good idea? You are leading by example.

Comment: @JaredBurrows No. Do what's right, not what's been done before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe from last year: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire

Comment: @meagar This happens pretty much daily so it'd be nice to know how the candidates would handle it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, definitely still a good question, I was just making an observation.

Comment: @meagar - I'm bringing back the Greatest Hits. Removed the "or be fired" bit, since everyone seized on that last time.

Comment: If answering "it depends", please elaborate, especially with (real S.O. question) examples.

Comment: @BradLarson: Shouldn't you present a few options for what can be done in this situation?

Answer (score 128):

You notice an experienced, high-rep user who has started a pattern of rude, not-constructive borderline abusive comments directed at users. How do you proceed in this situation?

Comment: Is this not pretty much the same as this guaranteed-to-be-included community team question: *"How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments? "*

Comment: Paging Col. Shrapnel

Comment: @Radiodef I guess it sort of got lost in there when I read that answer...blame the end of the day  This is something that we've dealt with multiple times in a highly visible ways, due to the users involved which is why I bring it up.

Comment: I think it is a great question, I just noticed the redundancy. Although, actually your phrasing may be better. The flag aspect of the community team question is narrow and has an obvious answer.

Comment: "or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8". My understanding of this is that if the guaranteed two are tweaked and highly scored, the tweak may replace the question it was forked from.

Comment: Excellent question and definitely one I think we should measure moderators by.

Comment: The part that @MichaelT notes is technically meant for the 3 non-guaranteed ones (which are very not-guaranteed for SO), but I'll be fine to reword the one to this wording if people prefer that.

Comment: @GraceNote Sorry for obviously not fully reading your answer. :/  We can delete this.

Comment: @bluefeet: Directed at certain *specific* users? A characterizable *class* of users? All users? Please clarify.

Answer (score 96):

A new user has gotten into a disagreement with a more experienced user over a question closure, and complains that the site is "unfriendly to newcomers."  How do you respond, if at all?

Comment: I think that this could provide some valuable insight on candidates points' of view.

Comment: Considering this plays out on meta nearly daily (and probably lots more often in comments on the main site), that's certainly a test of the candidates patience. Especially considering how often flags are probably called by either side.

Comment: I like this question, since it (indirectly) gauges the extent to which high-rep users are condescending towards newbies. Especially if you "read between the lines" of the answers...

Answer (score 95):

A valuable member of the community starts vandalizing their posts and deleting them, what do you do? Do you step in and suspend? If you don't suspend them, then how do you handle it?

Comment: This doesn't sound familiar at all. Are you sure this is a real life example?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker she just has an overly active imagination. It is so obviously made up

Comment: @Pekka웃 Blame the blue feet, it makes me do crazy things.

Comment: @bluefeet I thought being an SO mod makes you do crazy things ;)

Comment: @Pekka웃 See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288229/3210837 for a recent example. Also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288748/3210837.

Comment: @toothbrush thanks, it was meant more as an in-joke (George was at the center of one of the posts you link to)

Comment: @bluefeet: by "posts" do you mean answers, questions or both?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah, OK.

Comment: @einpoklum Posts means anything they've posted - questions or answers.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker yes, it is a real life example, although not on SO: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5133/17592

Answer (score 92):

A user has been flagged for making a series of "trivial" edits. How do you decide whether these edits are a problem? How do you act on that flag?

Comment: Looking for candidates who will calmly assess the situation, make sure to consider all points of view and then BURNINATE ALL THE GARBAGE EDITS

Comment: @Pekka웃 My stance on garbage edits is [well known](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148167/a-way-to-downvote-a-suggested-edit-and-affect-both-the-edit-suggester-and-re/148172#148172) :p

Comment: I have seen this a lot on review queues simple grammar mistakes though it makes the post better than it originally is it's hard to decide whether to allow the changes or to reject them a *minor edit* button would be great in this scenario and the editor not awarded any rep

Comment: @BradLarson; Be more specific please. Is this a < 1,000-rep user trying to farm rep with edits? Are these "trivial" edits at least marginally useful (e.g. spelling corrections, English phrasing improvements) or not?

Answer (score 73):

A user had done a veeery long series of `Looks OK` flags in Low Quality Posts without editing anything. What would you do?

Comment: Ohh - I like that one. You might want to consider adding First Posts / Late answer with "no action needed".

Comment: Given that the low quality queue has turned into a massive flood of s**t, how can you even get a long series of "looks ok" without getting trapped by the review audits?

Comment: @Lundin oh, you can, believe me.

Comment: @Lundin as a 10k user, you can [look through the history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) and likely will see this. On P.SE I've seen [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IxqNK.png) in the past in First Posts (which might be even worse as one review completes the task).

Comment: Do you mean without editing *or deleting* anything? Or, excluding delete actions, they never edit?

Comment: @Air excluding anything, except pressing the ``Looks OK`` button and advancing to the next review item as fast as possible.

Answer (score 64):

A user continuously calls you out for your moderation style on Meta, Chat, and other venues.  How do you react?

Comment: This needs more context: why is the user calling the candidate out? E.g. "A user calls out your decision to close a question, but you think you acted fairly. How do you react?"

Comment: @Sklivvz It could be anything, really.  It's happened to every moderator. The specific most recent instance of being called out isn't as important as the fact that as a moderator, you have a shiny target on your back; how do you handle it when some of the most vocal users decide to continuously shoot rubberbands at you?

Comment: I know it could be anything, it's the reason why you need to specify the context: the answer, and the tone of it, varies completely if a user calls me out and I realize they are right, or they are just insulting/trolling or if they are simply misguided.

Comment: @Sklivvz Over the course of a year, a user is bound to be right sometimes and wrong sometimes; but all that adds up. How do you deal with it as a moderator?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Perhaps make it "Do you react? If you do react, how would you react and in what venue?"

Answer (score 55):

<sub>*(Disclaimer: this is motivational rather than technical.)*</sub>

You are an experienced user, and have been a member for several years. You know how the site works and the problems moderators and trusted users have to deal with.

But tell us, why today instead of last election? Why today instead of next election? What has driven you to nominate and stand up to the task *now*? Are you confident your intent can and will remain the same in the mid future?

Comment: Several of the nominees *did* run in the last election and it seems reasonable to predict that several of the runners-up *will* run again in the next. Perhaps it would be simpler to remove the "instead of" parts of this, which might put those candidates on the defensive?

Comment: @Air, well, I have already used *rather than* in the disclaimer. *Instead of* was the best alternative I could find, and I personally don't think it is that hostile. (And even if it was, *putting candidates on the defensive* does not mesh well with the thick skins I believe moderators should wear.)

Comment: This reads like a "Why this school?" college essay.

Comment: I think this is too abstract. Most nominees would just have to come up with some smart-ass reason for 'why now'. Also, if their intent does change mid future, I'm pretty sure they cant foresee it now. Crossing their hearts and promising they'd perform for their entire term is no guarantee it'll really happen, irrespective of how they answer this question.

Comment: Personally I'm against this question because it introduces waffly stories that shouldn't matter. People don't care that I'm doing it for the children and world hunger and the rain forests and the endangered three toed sloths (well.... I *think* they don't really care about that as a reason for mod nomination). If you are really curious you could just ask this in chat.

Answer (score 50):

When reviewing recently deleted posts and current posts with deletion votes, you begin to notice a pattern. A group of users is consistently present for deletion votes, and some of the deletions begin to cause meta posts questioning the validity of the certain deletions. The deletion set gets so big that some high profile posts are being deleted.

How would you address this situation?

Comment: Good question. Might want to clarify whether or not the questions being deleted are on topic.

Comment: High profile in what sense? Highly-voted, on-topic questions, or just ones with a bunch of views and a few copy-pasta answers?

Comment: @ssube - Something in the ballpark of a post with 50+ votes, and answer with perhaps 100+ votes, and tens of thousands of views. I would say that is the lower end. I think the upper end would be something in the ballpark of 500+ votes and hundreds of thousands of views. Some background on recent discussions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/1026459

Comment: Votes isn't a good metric for quality, is an indicator but not the sole metric. Didn't we already learned that?

Comment: high-profile because a fun bike-shedding question, or why?

Comment: @Deduplicator - We don't delete good content.

Comment: @TravisJ: That's a non-sequitur.

Comment: @Deduplicator - you should read the linked material

Answer (score 44):

Before elected mod, you used to hang out in one of the SE chat rooms and  continue to do so after being elected (ok, not so active as before, your new duties and adjusting to them take some of your time now). You consider "regulars" there to be your friends.

One of them has the habit of posting witty/snarky comments under SO questions and re-posting them in the chat room - for your friends' notice, and sometimes amusement.

The comments are not inherently bad, on the contrary they are often pointing on the questions' misconceptions or lack of useful info. But they can be taken as snark and are sometimes flagged.

First, what do you do?

- Nothing. If the comments are flagged, they will be dealt by you - or another mod.
- Leave them. The comments are just funny, no harm done. Not worth jeopardizing your friendship.
- Delete whatever comment they re-post. They are snark anyway.
- Ban the user.
- Irrelevant. You have no friends.
- Something else?

Second, do you tell, announce to your friend and others what you did (if they have their comments repeatedly deleted, they will notice of course, but they will not know who did, only guess.)

The point of the second part is not only whether and how your friendship will affect your actions but how you will deal with the consequences of your actions and the effects of them to your friendship.

Comment: These are brilliant questions and reflects whether the candidates can take their position fairly and justly. Plus, honesty also plays a fair part in answering, which is splendid. :p

Comment: @Unihedro thnx.

Comment: "Ban the user." That seems like the "wrong answer".

Comment: -1 I don't see why friends should be treated differently and I don't think candidate's answer to this question (words) will match their actions once elected. Its human nature I assume.

Answer (score 40):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: AM I the inspiration for question number 1, and if not how much meaner do I have to be to become it? :)

Comment: @Gabe I think your main objective would have to be to travel back to 2011 and register then, when that question first started getting asked in these. ♪

Answer (score 39):

> A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the
>   past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will
>   do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

<sub>[Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289449/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/289450#289450)</sub>

Answer (score 38):

For handling NAA flags:

What constitutes an answer to a question?

Related: Do answers need to answer the question, or just address the question to avoid being possibly deleted under the above criteria?

Follow up:  Where are users and reviewers expected to find this information?

Comment: Also, does it matter if the question is really old when the standards were different.

Answer (score 32):

There appears to be a growing problem with code only answers in the VLQ review queue. What is your opinion on answers that provide code without explanation or comment, should we stay the course and continue to click "Looks OK" or should there be a higher bar for answers?

Comment: I think this question could be improved by making it more open-ended e.g. more along the lines of *"when is a code answer OK, when is it VLQ?"* Get the candidate to tell us more about their views.

Comment: I feel like this doesn't have much to do with moderating as it does with site policy. It's more of a meta question, no?

Comment: @slicedtoad There has been some Meta discussion on the topic, but asking potential moderators for their opinion on it will hopefully shed some light on their moderation styles. To a lesser degree it may point to whether they tend to be more "status quo" or "progressive".

Answer (score 32):

How would you handle a user or group of users that is/are upset at a moderator action you have taken?

For example, if someone posted on meta "This mod deleted my [question|answer|comment] and he is abusing his power," how would you react? What if it was a tweet or off-site blog post? What about a user editing his profile to insult you? etc.

*reposted [from last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220386/180276) with minor edits*

Comment: The moderator could send them to the "In praise of moderators" meta chat room for instance

Answer (score 30):

What's your view on old and highly voted [link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) that get flagged for not being answers?

Answer (score 26):

Now that you are a moderator, how will you spend your time on SO in comparison to when you weren't? Let's say that there are hundreds/thousands moderation tasks to do and you see a question you know the answer, but your time is short. What's most important: answering a good question for the SO community or doing a few moderation tasks in that time?

Comment: "10 moderation tasks to do" - Oh, those were the days. You may need to add a couple of zeros to that now.

Answer (score 21):

You received a spam flag for a historical post answering an old, off-topic (say for library seeking reasons), but **useful** question (well accepted by the community, e.g. 100k views and 100+ upvotes) with many legitimate answers. What will you do? When would you delete such Q&A content and when would you keep it?

Comment: To clarify: the flag is on an answer, and is it relevant to specify whether that answer is old or new? Also, I think this question may lead the answer because it assumes the flagged Q&A is useful. (What if it's not useful? And is its usefulness not somewhat subjective?) If the usefulness is important, perhaps you could briefly describe objective criteria that the Q&A has met. (E.g. has this Q&A aggregated information that is not easily available in Google results?)

Comment: The phrasing simply prompts the responder to [repeat existing moderator opinions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/2891664) when we actually want to learn the personal opinion of the responder.

Comment: @Radiodef, it would be a spam flag on an old answer like *Try this open source library. It has these features...*, where the poster is not a spammer (e.g. has no relation to the product). The question itself asks for some complex task, which can be solved by certain libraries, hence all the posts are of this sort. But the question and answers are useful, and you know they are.

Comment: *"But the question and answers are useful, **and you know they are**.* This is why I'm saying: define a case in your question that gets the responder to reveal to us how *they* define usefulness. Otherwise the answer doesn't inform us about what the candidate will actually do in specific situations.

Comment: Spam is spam – it's usually pretty obvious. If something is spam, it should and will be deleted immediately, if not by the moderator, then by the community. If it's not spam, the flag will be dismissed. This question, therefore, is really about what you would do *with the question*, and we have established policies for that (although that's a good question that might warrant its own posting). If, on the other hand, it's not actually a spam post and just a link-only answer, well, you have another standalone post right there.

Answer (score 20):

A relatively new answer was flagged as SPAM and you go about handling it, but it isn't a clear-cut case, because it is in some (small) way relevant to the question. Where is the line for you to confirm or clear the flag?

Comment: This is a good question. Spam flags carry heavy penalties, and a mod should know how to handle them.

Answer (score 20):

A high profile user in a given tag notices a rash of questions about a specific subject and notes that all of the otherwise relevant answers don't really cover all the bases on the topic. He writes a self-answered question with a high quality answer designed to address most, if not all, of the ins and outs of the issue, with the goal of funneling future questions on that topic to this one thread.

Another high profile user takes offense at the intent of the first user and proceeds to open a duplicate close vote that points to a much older and highly voted thread that does not have anywhere near the detail of the new answer. Close vote passes. At this point there's a close/reopen thrashing that's going on.

Do you reopen the thread and lock it or moderator close it?

Answer (score 17):

What do you think you will enjoy most as a moderator? What do you suspect you will find difficult?

Comment: Enjoy??? Is there any enjoyment?  :)

Comment: Well, you do get to fix what's wrong with the internet a little bit more... :-)

Comment: I do enjoy hunting socks when I have spare time.

Comment: @bluefeet I never could figure out if you are a he or a she. Martjin Pieters says you are a girl. Are you?

Comment: @jakekimds Why does that matter?  But yes, Martijn is correct.

Comment: @bluefeet just curious. Most mods have obvious names/pictures. Your picture is a bird with bluefeet.

Comment: @jakekimds Not all mods have obvious names/pictures - http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @bluefeet I guess.

Comment: @jakekimds The gender of the moderator shouldn't matter. You should judge the moderator by how they act on the site, not by anything else.

Comment: @jakekimds You mean it never occurred to you that bluefeet might just be.. a bird with blue feet?

Comment: @Seth No, that never occurred to me.

Comment: Deleting spammers is intensely satisfying. (I know this question is for the candidates, I just thought everyone should know.)

Comment: @Seth: Birds have gender too, you know.

Comment: @BoltClock I was waiting for someone to catch that ;P

Comment: @bluefeet: When looking at a single moderator, gender shouldn't matter. When looking at a team of moderators, I don't see anything wrong in talking about gender. My experience with mixed teams has always been very good. Therefore I'm happy that you are a member of the mod team.

Answer (score 17):

What mistakes have you made in the past on SO? What actions did you take to rectify those mistakes? How will those actions impact your views and reactions as moderator?

Comment: This is good – mods make mistakes like anyone else and need to know how to handle them.

Answer (score 15):

After an interaction with a user who cursed your Nazi soul to burn in the eternal fires of hades you notice you received a downvote to just one of your questions, which has a timestamp that is aligned with the whole incident.

What do you do about it?

Comment: send [two fast DVs to their unrelated posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773)?

Comment: Oh no, a single downvote! WHATEVER WILL I DO?

Comment: I don't see that this question is particular to moderators, actually. Sure, they can do more, but this can happen to anyone with some reputation.

Comment: @gnat: Just one DV. Tit for tat and less easy to blame you for it...

Answer (score 14):

You observe that a user has behaved badly enough that a temporary suspension is warranted (which you do and advise the user of why they have been suspended).

After being suspended, the user contacts you back saying they are sorry and won’t repeat the behaviour and requests that the suspension be lifted. Reading their message, the user seems genuine.

Would you lift the suspension?

Answer (score 13):

A user posts correctly spelled, nicely formatted, well written, clear and easy to understand question.

Question asks for advice on a nice place to make a geek party. Another user flags it as Very Low Quality.

How would you act on the flag?

Comment: Suggest a nice place for a geek party? ;-)

Comment: @blalasaadri if you were a nominee, you'd get my vote right now

Comment: This is an excellent question, albeit the missing context.

Comment: @gnat: And this stuff ever happens on SO? I doubt it.

Comment: @einpoklum question is inspired by recent discussion over here at MSO, you can search for it. I didn't refer it only because all other questions seem to omit mentioning real cases (maybe to avoid influencing answerers)

Comment: @gnat, ok, so s/ever happens/happens more than once a year/ then.

Comment: @einpoklum at a site that gets 8K (that's _eight thousands_) questions a day...

Answer (score 13):

You stated in your nomination that you could *"easily spare [insert smallish amount of time] a day"* to dedicate to your moderation duties.

- How much do you think you will get accomplished in that time?
- Is that time spent all at once or spread throughout the day?
- What if the moderation workload demands more - can you reliably and sustainably dedicate that time?

<sup>This question is aimed at new candidates to see if they have any idea of the scope of the moderator role.</sup>

Answer (score 12):

If in a rare case scenario, a very good friend of yours continues to break rules, what will you do?

Will you suspend the user if required or save your friendship?

Comment: I'll do one better: what if you have to decide whether to suspend *your significant other*?

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Usually, it's the "couple" getting suspended by someone else - because the significant other likely doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Wouldn't know about suspending, but I did vote to close one of her questions once. Let's just say I won't be doing that again.

Comment: Isn't it standard to declare this kind of situation a "Conflict of interest" and let someone else decide?

Comment: @Pekka웃 your father is dying and his last wish is to post "what have you tried? Noob." on a new question, for added drama the question is by Joel Spolsky - what do you do?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Q: "My father is going to die if I don't do XYZ right now, how can I do that?" A: "What have you tried?" ... :-)

Comment: I feel a part of my question has been incorporated in Q10 in [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290096/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)

Answer (score 12):

A user has posted many answers. The user is now concerned about posting code in their answers. They look through their extensive list of answers and begin taking several actions on *some* answers.

- For some low voted answers with code, they flag for deletion.
- For some high voted answers with code, they remove the code and replace it with an explanation.

What actions would you consider taking and why? Would you attempt to deal with the situation as a whole or on a post by post basis?

Answer (score 12):

What do you consider the most important job of a moderator?

Comment: And if s/he thinks all tasks are sort-of about equally important?

Comment: @einpoklum imho than he/she should start to give priority  to task ,

Comment: "Which of your children do you love the most?"

Comment: left one always , though i dont have even girl friend :D

Answer (score 12):

You mentioned that you were active in a problematic tag that collects a lot of low quality posts or inaccurate answers. What will you do if you are awarded a ♦ - will you go nuclear on that tag? Or will you take a hands-off approach and let the posts filter through the review queues? Will you clean up those inaccurate answers?

Comment: I WILL VOTE FOR YOU ONLY IF YOU PROMISE TO GO NUCLEAR

Comment: @Pekka웃 For you I will go all [Kim Jong-un](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong-un) over it.

Comment: [Supreme people agrees and holds spontaneous victory parade in Pyongyang](https://twitter.com/dprk_news)

Answer (score 12):

You feel strongly and are confident that an action taken by another moderator was not the best way to handle the situation, and the action is reversible.

What do you do?

Comment: This is much too broad... give a more specific scenario. What kind of action? vis-a-vis whom?

Answer (score 12):

A user flags (as low quality or NAA) an answer that consists of only code -- no explanation, no references, just code. On the one hand, the answer is (1) correct and (2) self-explanatory to an experienced user of the language/tool in question.  On the other hand, it's possibly meaningless to the OP. Do you delete the answer?

Answer (score 12):

Someone flags a long and thoughtful answer using other:

> This does not answer the question, though it contains lots of valuable advice for the OP.

That observation is correct. What now?

Comment: This is something that happens on a fairly regular basis, and can be tricky to handle right, so I like this as a question.

Answer (score 10):

Many moderators seem to disappear from the review queues after becoming a moderator.

Given the size of the close vote queue, the perpetual stream of... well... into Low Quality Posts, and the newer queues of Triage and Help and Improvement - **will you still participate in the 'regular user' review queues? Why or why not?**

Comment: Is this really an answerable question? What if they say "yes" but when elected discover that there's enough mod-specific (super important) stuff to do to keep them busy?

Comment: @Pekka웃 its a question of intention. I would put answers to it in the same realm as any campaign promise for any elected position. It is just as (un)answerable as any other hypothetical being asked here and that the plans an individual has for being a mod may change when they actually get the diamond. But, it still speaks to the intentions of what type of mod they intend to be.

Answer (score 8):

If you review in the Low Quality Posts review queue, what criteria do you use to complete the review? Would this differ from how you handle Very Low Quality flags?

Related: A post was deleted by the community via the Low Quality Posts review queue. What would be the necessary conditions for you to undelete it?

Answer (score 8):

How much of an issue to Stack Overflow's branding and goals is the perceived quality of questions presenting? What actions will you take to guide Stack Overflow and its community to address these issues?

Answer (score 8):

You are alerted towards a pattern of serial downvoting directed at a highly reputable user. However, you notice this user has garnered a large number of upvotes on each answer
that has been targeted, and that each answer has a comment from the targeted user a mere minute after initially posting along the lines of "*Why the downvote, this is absolutely 
correct!*"

It then hits you. The user is serially downvoting their own account with a sock-puppet in order to acquire mass sympathy upvotes from other community members in their popular tag. They have done this
on hundreds of questions.

How do you proceed?

- Remove their sock and award the user hundreds of precious rep?
- Suspend the user for downvoting themselves?
- Alternative action?

Comment: Is that inspired by something which happened, or are you just fitting the pieces available for a really interesting result?

Comment: @Deduplicator The latter, admittedly. I think it's not particularly clear what the right course of action would be however, which may make it interesting.

Comment: Ah, complex tactical questions :-) Do scenarios as convoluted as this one (but not this particular one) occur on SO at all?

Comment: @einpoklum If only I had that answer ;) Think of it as a question in critical thinking.

Answer (score 6):

What would you do with a flagged **code-only** answer? The code will not be self-explaining in the language that you're not keen on, with no comments. The answer would have no votes because it's been posted a few minutes ago. Would you:

1. delete the answer
2. keep the answer as it is
3. ask the author to add some description in comment
4. do something else, I would...

Comment: As per me "ask the author to add some description in detail" not for others. :)

Comment: @TLama, are you sure this isn't a no-brainer question? I mean, you can always take any other action after doing 3. ...

Comment: @einpoklum, assume that you cannot use more than one option. You would need to use option 4 to explain an action chain.

Answer (score 4):

How do you react on controversial edit to question ?

Here is the situation :

- the OP ask a really poor question quickly downvoted and closed. The OP didn't post any comment nor edit the question.
- during the *on hold* period: another user made a substantial edit to the question making it a high quality and valuable question. (many up-votes, everybody agree on that point)
- at least one quality answer is posted
- an edit/rollback close/reopen war take place : according comments you can see that the close-voters estimate that the original intent of the OP is not respected. The re-openers estimate that the edited question is of top quality and that the original intent of the OP is respected.

How do you react if:

- you estimate that the original intent of the OP is respected ?
- you estimate that the original intent of the OP is not respected (but you agree that the edited question is a top-quality question) ?
- you cannot estimate if the original intent of the OP is respected or not (but you agree that the edited question is a top-quality question) ?

Answer (score 3):

What is your opinion on the effectiveness of the current moderation queues (particularly Close Votes), in light of the large influx of low-quality/"crap" questions? If you could change the moderation queues in any way, how and why would you change them?

Comment: We aren't evaluating SE employees, only candidates for the post of moderator.

Comment: @Deduplicator "This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current." The close votes/question quality issue is a perpetual big'un, and I feel that how a potential moderator answers it can give valuable insights into his or her style of moderation. Plus, I want to know who I should vote for! :)

Answer (score 3):

A user flags an answer as Not an Answer. You review it and see that the answer provides a lot of context about the same type of problem/error/issue. But it also makes clear that the person who posted the answer is really asking how to solve a similar, but not identical, problem.

The "answer" is possibly helpful to the OP and other readers, but it also doesn't answer the question. Delete or no?

Answer (score 1):

How would you determine whether the degree of similarity between answers (primarily code-based), by distinct users, constitutes plagiarism. Furthermore how would you proceed to deal with a situation where plagiarism is evident by your criteria?

Comment: Too long, can it be condensed?

Comment: I would hardly call a paragraph too long, but that's me! ...I was aware there is a 15 character shortness limit, but didn't think questions for this election could be "too long". Of course it can be condensed, but felt it appropriate to qualify it as completely as possible. So is the down-vote for the quality, length or both? I wonder if it's an objective view? I can "shorten" it for those with time constraints or other constraints, if necessary.

Comment: The first part of this question is a "I know it when I see it" type situation. Re how to proceed, not sure that's a fair question to ask someone who isn't a moderator yet? It's likely to be part of the training

Comment: A lot of questions I've seen here seem to inquire as to how, given the hypothetical situation where you are a moderator, you would proceed in the situation described. Similarly, I presume, one will likely be trained to handle some of them.

Answer (score 1):

What would be your added value if a reviewer points out an alleged problem in the audit process, like this:

[Too much importance given to the lack of context explanation for a link in an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288649/too-much-importance-given-to-the-lack-of-context-explanation-for-a-link-in-an-an).

Would you say that a change *is* required, and in this case, what would *you* do?

Answer (score 1):

You notice a pattern that you personally think is problematic. What type of unilateral action do you take to address the observed pattern?

For example, the repetition of a tag, reference or phrase in certain questions.

Answer (score -7):

Moderators are able to do more reviews than is possible for other users. Do you want to see how many reviews you can do in a day without loosing focus and help out an overflowing queue (like close votes queue)? Do you plan to repeat this for several days (not necessarily consecutive or to the same extend)?

Answer (score -8):

Say there is a user which answers questions but ignores comments on his answers, or simply doesn't know they exist, meaning the asker of the question can't ask for more information. how would you proceed the answering user?

Comment: How is that a question for a moderator-candidate? And what's the problem with ignoring comments not relevant for the post (or which don't need a response for other reasons)?

Answer (score -10):

What is your opinion on unicorns?

Comment: Dragons are better.

Comment: This was intended to check for a sense of humour, because I think it says a lot about a person. (Am I wrong?)

Comment: This is quite subjective, though. I expect most moderators not to be compulsive against unicorns (or dragons, for that matter).

Comment: Perhaps better way to word this would be "Do you hate fun?"

Comment: @apaul34208 The minimum length for an answer body is 30 characters and that's 16, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the correlation between unicorns and hating fun escapes me ...

Comment: It's simple, @ypercube: if you like unicorns, you hate fun.

Answer (score -10):

Looking at your profile, I see that you have gold badge/silver badge for [xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xxx), [yyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yyy) and [zzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zzz), showing that you have expertise in those topics. Apart from [zzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zzz), whose questions and answers are generally good, I see a lot of low quality questions and answers in [xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xxx), [yyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yyy). As a moderator, apart from your general responsibility, what will you do to increase the quality in those tags?

Answer (score -14):

So, from all the other questions we have covered mostly everything about motivation and how would you act once you are selected as a mod. But I would like to know kind of the opposite of your motivation, I want to know what situation derived directly from the site would make you resign from this position (can be harassment from users, bad behaviour from other mods, etc).

Comment: I doubt this would lead to useful answers. If someone is prone to ragequitting but nontheless wants to be elected, they will surely not say so in their answer. There's also a lot of unpredictable reasons that could make one quit the position, e.g. accidents, job changes, family, etc. What useful information would you expect to be contained in an answer to your question?

Comment: @l4mpi that's why I said "what situation **derived directly from the site**", not sure if that's clear

Comment: I read that, but still - I'm saying if you want to gauge if a moderator is likely to leave the site after a short time, it's not especially useful because there are many things completely unrelated to the site that can force a mod to quit. And as far as SO-internal things are concerned, I doubt anybody who nominated themselves would freely tell you "I usually lose interest in things like this after a few months". Again, what is your goal with this question?

Comment: @l4mpi The goal of my question is to know what would make a mod to lose his/her motivation. If you read the part about a situation derived directly from the site, I'm not sure why you keep saying that there could be an accident or job changes or things unrelated to it

Comment: The list of things that might make a mod lose their motivation is potentially endless.

Comment: In addition to what Pekka said, you don't have any way of knowing if a candidate answers truthfully. Assuming they want to be elected, why should they do so if it would reflect badly on them? Furthermore, most people would probably answer this rather optimistically (see planning fallacy etc, self-evaluation is seriously hard). And anyways, losing motivation may only be the nth most likely thing that makes them give up the position (or heavily restrict their time for SO). Thus it doesn't seem like a particularily useful question.

Comment: "you don't have any way of knowing if a candidate answers truthfully", isn't this valid for every answer?. And I get it, you don't find the question useful, I don't know what more do you want

Comment: "isn't this valid for every answer?" - of course that's true to a degree, but if a question is "what would you do in [a specific mod situation]" then they can't exactly just handwave it away, as would be the case with this question. Anybody could answer "I'm calm and collected and if anybody harrasses me I'll take a quick break to distance myself from it" or something similar, which is simply not interesting (and not verifiable). You can't just do the same with e.g. "how to react to a high-rep user that defaces their own posts".

Comment: @l4mpi there are plenty of questions here that go to character instead of a standard procedure on how to act for some misbehaviours

Comment: @l4mpi: No, anyone can suggest any question they like. They don't have to provide a reason. (The reason for this one is obviously obvious to Lamak and obviously the opposite to you. We don't have to hear the debate about your motives.) I don't see any other suggested question to have a reason. it's our job then to upvote or downvote the suggestions - and Gracy's job to judge if they are irrelevant, regardless of the votes.

Comment: A more sinister wording of this question is "How can I get you to resign if I don't like you as a mod?"