# Candidate count has not been updated since one candidate was withdrawn

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election

The header for the election page still says that we have 6 candidates:

> [image]

But currently [we have only 5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412472/1426539).

I imagine it could be [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/), but it's been 8 hours since the change, and it hasn't refreshed still.

Either that number should be fixed, or we should add a 6th candidate. Either works for me.

Comment: Are you volunteering, then?

Comment: Can't. Monkeys aren't eligible for public office. It's unfair, I know. But it's the Law.

Comment: The entry of the withdrawn candidate is still in the list. It doesn’t say “_active_ candidates: 6”. It seems consistent with the number of answers on a Q&A page: 10k rep users can see deleted answers and the answer count includes these.

Comment: Sshh, don't tell that to [these 24 monkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)!

Comment: @SebastianSimon I guess you are right. Still seems wrong to me, though.

Comment: @SebastianSimon There are two withdrawn candidates ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69532000/revisions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69541099/revisions)) not included in that count.  The difference is that they withdrew before the election.

Comment: It has been officially determined that this is a bug. It should only count the *active* candidates (i.e., the ones you can cast a vote for), so the correct number is 5. A dev will take a look at it when they have time, probably after the weekend.

Comment: Related: [Candidates whose nominations have been withdrawn are still visible in the dropdown on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371123/348196)

Comment: @CodyGray At least one of those monkeys is a dog. Strange.

Comment: @CodyGray after the weekend? Of which month/year? lol. Seriously, such minor bugs are rarely fixed, let alone so fast.

Comment: *This current* weekend, @ShadowWizard. That comment of mine is based on a discussion that I had with a CM while reviewing this bug report. We're getting *excellent* CM support during this ongoing election.

Comment: @CodyGray no doubt CM's are awesome. No doubt developers are awesome, each and every one of them. But from long years of experience, bugs that don't have actual critical impact just don't get fixed, see MSE for example, thousands of such bugs. So yeah, I am skeptic. And hope to be wrong, as usual.

Comment: This has been added to the backlog and will be addressed as a part of bug duty rotation. We'll let y'all know once we have new updates.

Comment: @JNat I would argue that this *isn't* a bug. Withdrawn candidates should still be considered in the count

Comment: If we want the number to reflect how many candidates can be voted for, @ughStackExchange, then it is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed for the count on the 2021 SO mod election, and will be fixed for elections moving forward as well.