# Where can we find information about all the nominations that have been withdrawn from the 2021 Stack Overflow Moderator Election?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

The [home page of se-electionbot](https://electionbot.samliew.com/) shows three *withdrawn* candidates:

[image]

We already know one of the [withdrawn cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412472/candidate-changes-in-2021-moderator-election-review-your-ballot).

Where can we find the withdrawal information about the other two candidates?

Comment: Honestly, you can't. There's no public (or private) explanation for why a nomination was withdrawn. No reason is required when pushing that button

Comment: There was a joke nomination, and one that OP somehow (and I haven't got the faintest idea how this could ever happen - don't ask me why/how) managed to nominate on Stack Overflow instead of Music.SE. All withdrawals this election had a reason, though. But as Cat mentioned, there's not a requirement to give a reason for withdrawing, so there's generally no way to tell. It also generally doesn't matter. As it says on the nomination page, anyone can withdraw at any time for any reason. The only time there's a trail is when said withdrawal happens in the voting phase

Comment: For transparency's sake: one was withdrawn because of being considered a "joke nomination" (which they were, albeit in good faith), the second, apparently, withdrew voluntarily, and the third you already know. There's really not much to each case other than that - and the minimalistic information reflects that. P.s. The bot's feature of displaying withdrawn nominations is very much experimental, so we might add *some* information on the candidates (like score and phase when they withdrew), but not too much to avoid fueling extra drama around the nominations.

Comment: @Oleg The second withdrawal was indeed voluntary on the basis that they had "nominated on the wrong site"

Comment: @Nick yeah, it was indeed - quite embarrassing, I guess, to find oneself to nominate to the wrong site :) Although with that many concurrent elections getting one's wires crossed for a second is plausible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nominations are withdrawn for a reason, whether the withdrawal is voluntary (i.e., someone withdraws their own nomination) or imposed by staff. As such, we intentionally do not make detailed information about these withdrawn nominations public. There is just no reason that anyone needs to know this information.

It is not truly "private"; if you poke around enough, armed with the right information, you can find out. But there's no reason to make it any more visible than that.

In the case where the withdrawal occurs *during the voting phase* of the election, as occurred during the 2021 election, the withdrawn nomination will continue to appear on the voting page, grayed out and annotated as such, and some sort of public notice will be posted to explain what happened.