# Why did I fail this audit when it contained a solution to the problem?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Why exactly did I fail this audit and why was it deleted or handled somehow?

Yes he's asking a question on top of giving a reasonable answer to fix the problem.

Can't really wrap my mind around that.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7480241

Comment: This probably isn't the main reason, but that answer is hard to read because of its formatting/grammar improvements.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I can agree with that but none the less it's a valid answer or am I wrong?

Comment: I agree that it is an answer, though at first glance it looks like something that should be a comment.  If it was worded "Your version of the program is different than your buddy's.  Check the version this way and get on the same version." it would clearly look like an answer.  If it was worded "What version are you on?  It looks like your version is different from your friends.  Check your versions and use the same one." is probably better as a comment because of the initial question.  The wording sucks which makes this hard.  An audit should be obvious and this one isn't.

Comment: You are saying that no action is needed... That there are no corrections to capitalization are necessary.  That the answer *properly* and *completely* answers the question being asked (if you are not sure, skip) and is not a duplicate of another answer that was posted a week or so before.

Comment: You failed it because it was added to the queue as an audit. Audits *never* take into account whether they're actually correct or not; they just get generated based on some vague criteria, and you *have* to vote the same way as the audit system expects for you to pass. In this way (as in every other way you look at it), it's not really appropriate to call them "audits". More like "coercions".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, keep in mind that not all audits are perfect.  Posting the audit in question (as you did) here in Meta is a good way of getting feedback and potentially fixing any wrongs from a bad audit (one failed audit will not affect you much if at all).  IMO, this question is not as clear-cut as an audit should be.

That being said, the first post and late-answer queues are supposed to help new users learn to use SO properly.  So "no action needed" is giving the user a green light to continue doing what they are doing.  In this case, an edit or a comment to let the user know to better format their answer is appropriate.  The content of the answer looks fine (it is a legitimate answer), but the presentation is lacking and you should take an action that fixes this.

Comment: Nonsense, there was no need to edit this answer. The purpose of the review queue is to weed out unsalvagable crap. In this case it was not, as it attempts to answer the question. If the answer is poor, it should perhaps be down voted, but nothing else. Improving answers with edits when doing review work is certainly not mandatory practice.

Comment: The answer that was deleted (and is in the audit), posted on Feb 27th is also a duplicate of the material in the answer [posted on Feb 16th](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28550031/289086). As described in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) duplicate answers may be deleted. With the first post and late answer queue, you should always check to make sure that the new answer isn't repeating what has already been said (something often done on forums that shouldn't be done on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @MichaelT If we should, then the review system should be re-made so that one can easily do so, without opening the post in a separate window.

Comment: @Lundin I point you to [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/).  Note that several actions suggest going and checking other resources. I almost *always* open reviews in another window so that I can get a fuller picture of the context of the entire question and its answers. Yes, the review interface sucks for many things. That doesn't mean that one shouldn't spend some time in giving proper guidance to new users who show up in this queue. Clicking 'no action needed' robs them of this opportunity.

Comment: @MichaelT I agree I could've commented on that.

Comment: @Lundin No, that is the purpose of Triage. FP and LA queues also serve a similar purpose to H&I: To fix the mistakes of new users and bring their posts to SO quality.

Answer (score 3):

This only happened because the review audit system is broken. The only reason you got this in your audit is because a diamond mod had deleted the answer. Under normal circumstances, there was nothing in answer appearing in your audit that would justify a deletion.

The diamond mod only deleted it in an attempt to clear up a protected community wiki question. For such wiki/frequent questions, we might be more picky with the quality of the answers, just so they don't spam down the place too much, and distract from the high-quality answer(s) which could be regarded as "canonical". Also, diamond mod might know the greater picture that we can't see just by doing a review. For example they might detect plagiarism, spam etc.

The audit system incorrectly thinks that anything that was deleted by a diamond mod is per default a bad post and therefore throws it into the audit.

Comment: Interesting I didn't know that mod deleted answers directly go as audit

Comment: **negative** voted with a VLQ flag or NAA flag (or spam) on it is required.  Just deleted isn't sufficient. There may have been a system VLQ flag on the answer or someone else may have flagged it as NAA. It needs all three conditions to be a known bad audit: negative score, flag, and mod delete.  Note that as a 20k user, you can help prevent these from showing up as audits by actively moderating  and deleting answers before a mod needs to become involved.

Comment: No diamond mod deleted the answer. [It was deleted by the community.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7180185) There is another answer to that same question that did, perhaps you were looking at that answer instead?

Comment: @hvd Hmm perhaps I was looking at the wrong one indeed since you don't see the content once they are deleted. Regardless, the system for picking audits for the review audit system remains broken.