# Is there a place where all reviewing policies are described?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

Today I was "banned" from reviewing, because I made too many mistakes in review audits ("You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example..."). After reading some questions on Meta, I understood that probably I don't understand a lot of things. I tried to find a Q&A where the question "how to make good reviews" is answered, but I failed. I have two particular questions:

1. Is there a detailed guide for each type of review? For example, it should cover questions like: Which "suggested edits" are good, and which are not? What exactly means "should be improved" in Triage? Who will improve - author (how will he/she know?) or community? And so on. I have a lot of such questions; for some of them I found answers on Meta, but for some not. I have my own opinion on "how does a good Q&A site looks like", but the community has another one. How will I know, what the community expects of me?
2. Is there a way to know how far I have gone with my mistakes? I have the impression, that in the last few days I passed more audits than before. But I don't know it for sure. So, for example, there could be a progress bar, that shows "Your permission to review will be blocked in three days if you continue to make that many mistakes". Any type of feedback would be helpful.

PS: Many other people in such situation wrote "I'm not complaining". Of course I'm complaining (joke), because I am a bit demoralized (not joke).

Comment: Why did you want until you'd performed 1,264 reviews to decide to figure out how reviews should actually be done?  If you didn't know how to properly review posts *you should have taken the time to figure it out a long time ago*.

Comment: First, you should read the [help], as well as [faq and faq-proposed questions on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq+or+faq-proposed), especially [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505). There are more details on meta, covering lots of more or less obscure edge-cases.

Comment: @Servy I'm well on the side of review bans... but I also like to believe that I am realistic in recognizing  that not everyone who reviews has even a token amount of familiarity with meta or participation here. I applaud Dmitry for coming here and realizing the wealth of information that can be found here, and wonder what to do to help provide this information to people earlier (the amount of 'looks ok' and 'some improvement needed' in triage... well... yea).

Comment: Dmitry, while I wrote it for another site, I believe that for first post and late answers my answer in [Looking for guidance on using “No Action Needed” in the first posts review queue](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6681/40980) may be helpful in doing more. First posts is probably one of the most important queues to review in - and give help. [New users who receive help are more likely to stay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216683/213963). Editing and commenting to help them are almost as important as answering - you find these via first post.

Comment: @Servy why do you think I haven't? And what do I have to think after a lot of "Congratulations! This was a test, and you have passed!"? Maybe I have to think "Oh... Too much of congratulations, probably, I do something wrong?" Of course, now I think so ;) To all: thanks for the links, now I have a lot of time to read.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing has some more guidance, although it's a bit sparse on some of them and (naturally) doesn't mention Triage at all.

Comment: I support this question. I have done lots of reviews but I skip lots of cases because there are no easy to find guidelines on how to handle various review cases. Many questions on how to do reviews or how to handle a specific question are closed as duplicates where the duplicate seems to be a discussion with no clear guidelines.