# How to say 'No Action Needed' when there are edits (less than 6 chars) to be made in reviews?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7676956)
First Post review to be done. But I can not improve its formatting (edit the post) due to the required edit is less than 6 characters. Should I say `No Action Needed` although there is a small improvement to be done? I know skipping this review is not a solution for this. I have faced the same so many times before.

Comment: Skipping is always fine.

Comment: Then another user will encounter the same issue.

Comment: Don't worry about that. Either he will find more to do, or he'll have enough more rep to get such a small correction done. Anyway, do you know http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts

Answer (score 4):

[There's *always* something else that needs to be edited.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29618364/revisions)

Also, this wasn't a question. Note how nothing was ever asked? You should've flagged it for closure.

Comment: Yes this is just an example. What if there are two or three characters to be corrected in a URL posted in a question. With all the others perfect?

Comment: There's *always* something else that needs to be edited. Always.