# "You made too many incorrect reviews" - I just made one!

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I sometimes make mistakes when reviewing. It doesn't happen too often, but sometimes I just don't pay enough attention and I fail. *I'm not perfect.*

But after just one failed audit, I get banned for two days. After another failed one for one week and if I fail for the third time, I get banned for **1 month!**

It is very hard to not fail on **any** audit, **ever**. So in principle, I get banned for one month + one week + 2 days after only 3 failed audits. I try really hard, because I know the next time I'll be banned for even longer, but it sometimes still happens.

Why is the review policy so strict? I'm not a robo-reviewer, so this really upsets me! Sometimes I just overlook something that seems so obvious later on. That's why each post is reviewed by more than one user, right?

Comment: Apparently spam failures are extra bad. Did you miss any of those?

Comment: Did you fail audits or did you get banned otherwise (e.g. by a moderator)? What queue(s) are we talking about?

Comment: Have you considered taking a break from reviewing until you are a bit more familiar with the site's guidelines and general expectations?

Comment: I recently had a 1 month break and I informed myself and continued reviewing more carefully. But if one failed audit means a ban, then certainly at *some* point, I **will** get banned! No one is perfect.

Comment: You don't get banned for one failed audit, unless you've already failed several before. This isn't a case of "I wasn't careful once, and got banned". I'd advice you to take a long break, and be _a lot_ more careful when you return.

Comment: "I got suspended for bad reviews. As soon as that suspension ended, I immediately did more bad reviews and got suspended again. As soon as *that* suspension ended, I right away made more bad reviews and was suspended again. As soon as *that* suspension ended, I made more bad reviews and was suspended *yet again*. And as soon as that suspension ended, I made *even more* bad reviews, and now that this has happened **eight times**, I'm surprised that **bad reviews got me suspended**, and I want to complain." I have a suggestion: *Stop reviewing.* It's clearly not something you're suited for.

Comment: @KenWhite so you are suggesting that I should not make **any** errors, **ever**?

Comment: Of course not. I'm suggesting that you make at least a minimal effort to *learn from those mistakes*, which after **eight repeats of the same exact cycle** you're clearly not doing. It's simply idiotic to do something wrong, be told that it's wrong, repeat the same behavior seven more times (being told after each time that it's wrong even more strongly) and then complain that you don't understand why you're getting suspended yet again. If you're not going to learn from the mistakes, the best course of action is to simply stop reviewing. You're clearly making no effort to improve your reviews.

Comment: Is there somewhere a guide I can learn from?

Comment: At the risk of sounding rude, if you need a guide to tell you that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7825622) was a completely bogus edit, then clearly reviewing is not for you.

Comment: see [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) (general principles laid out over there, can be applied to LQ reviews too)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, let's see... [You failed this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7825622) most recently. A few days prior, you [failed this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7787025) *right after* coming off a 30-day review suspension for [failing *this* one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7426098)...

...I could go on listing the audits you've failed, but I think you get the point: you've failed a **lot** more than one. In fact, you've been banned from review a total of 8 times at this point.

I think you should probably stop reviewing *period*; it's not for everyone, and in this case it's not for you.

But, if you *do* want to try again after your current suspension is up, **please pay more attention.** These audits are not difficult; they're blatant spam and nonsense. If you're failing them even *once*, you're clearly not even reading the post you're reviewing, much less thinking about the action you're selecting. Reviewing so carelessly hurts everyone; each post you click through without reading puts more responsibility on others to get it right. If you can't review well, then *please* don't review at all.

Comment: I find you suggesting that I should not be reviewing rude! I'm sometimes inattentive, not robo-reviewing!
On the topic: Will it stay like this, me getting banned every time I fail one audit?

Comment: If you keep failing audits as soon as your suspension lifts, yes. I'm not trying to be rude, but if you can't pay attention then... Go do something else until you can. There's no reason to do this if you're not going to do it well.

Comment: @bytecode77 you may see this as "just a review".  But to the person one the other side of the review, you are potentially causing them harm if you are not going to do the review well.  Forget about audits...  if you say that their first post "Looks Good" when it isn't, how is that user supposed to learn how the site works.  You are basically helping a user get downvoted to death and potentially banned from asking question because you did not provide them feedback on why their question was not good and how to improve it.  Reviews are a serious business and not something to be taken lightly..

Comment: I'm mainly interested in why I get banned right after just one failed audit. I always thought you had to fail more than once. I really want to review, but it's like you have to pass a test with 100%, otherwise you would get an F. That's basically my problem! I do not fail 99% of the times and this, say, 1% gets me banned **every time**. Afterall, that's the reason there are multiple reviews for each post.

Comment: @bytecode77 You don't get banned for a single failed audit. Unless you've already been banned in the past. In which case, you aren't getting banned for "just one failed audit", but for _yet another_ failed audit.

Comment: This is more like failing a test because you misspelled your own name when filling it out. Audits are generally not hard; if you fail them it is a good sign that your other reviews are problematic too.

Comment: I get that point. I'm also trying to be better at reviewing, but there is always some point, where I miss something. I also flag a lot of posts where I see something wrong with it.
@Shog9 If your answer wasn't rude, then your last comment definitely was!

Comment: @bytecode77: Will you stop repeating *after one time*? It's not after one time; it's after you were previously suspended **seven times** for repeating the same behavior in a short period of time. **Eight times being suspended for bad reviews is not being suspended after one bad review.** It's being suspended **eight times** for **repeating the same poor quality reviews and ignoring what you're being told with each suspension.** Shog9 was not being rude by suggesting you stop reviewing; it was wise advice. Poor reviews are as bad as no reviews. You're wasting your time (and that of others).

Comment: Nobody in this thread has mentioned anything about audits that the user *didn't* fail. Does this mean that passed audits don't affect the banning algorithm, or that there were simply no audits of that category in this specific case?

Comment: @bytecodee77 see bans as a threshold between good and bad. If you've been good for long, the threshold is far and you need a BUNCH of failures. Whenever you come out of suspension, you are obviously close to the threshold. Of course if in your first day back to reviewing you miss the first audit.... well you'll go back below the line. Remember, if you're unsure, skip. And saying "I miss something" when someone pointed an audit where you accepted an edit where " sbit ebits R layout gravity centers " was inserted mid-sentence.... do you read 100% through before choosing an option?

Comment: @bytecode77 when you successfully pass an audit, you get a message. When you come out of suspension, do you ever receive "successful audit" or is it that the first audit you meet, you fail?

Comment: I get some audits right before I get one wrong. Anyway, I'll just try to be more careful from now on.