# Separate ban for each review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-suspension

All three review queues are logically separate from each other in each aspect:

1. Triage
2. First questions
3. Late answers.

The reason behind same is that each kind of review needs different skill sets. Even we have separate counting and badges for same. However, when a user gets banned from reviewing, s/he is forbidden to work on all the queues.

Right now, I am banned from reviews because I reviewed one latest answers wrongly. So I should be banned from reviewing late answers.

Please can anyone explain why it's different in the case of review as compared to badges.

Comment: Because bans in most cases are obvious. A lack of attention applies to all queues, not just one.

Comment: If you're not paying necessary attention in one...

Comment: I think that most review queues are similar in a way that they all require you to pay attention. So if you review stuff wrongly one queue, it is quite likely that you will review stuff wrongly elsewhere also. Spam, Link only answers, bad questions are the same everywhere.

Comment: Why are you even comparing bans to badges?

Comment: @BoltClock Because that's why reviewing exists, isn't it? To get badges? ... [obviously kidding]

Comment: *I am banned from reviews because I reviewed one latest answers wrongly* do I need to read one (1) in the same manner as in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291405/you-made-too-many-incorrect-reviews-i-just-made-one)

Comment: This is not a well-documented question.  You don't get banned for failing just a single audit, you failed multiple.  You ought to at least show that you *only* failed the audits for a single review queue.  And if that's a common problem that more SO users experience, then it starts to make sense to make bans selective per queue.  If you don't remember what audits you failed, well, that's the problem.  Stop, look, listen.

Comment: I think I missed a trick, when I got banned from reviewing I considered what I'd done, why it might be the wrong action, and tried to learn from it. Apparently you're meant to make a post on meta.

Comment: Is there any list which shows what all reviews i failed ?

Comment: @BoltClock I am comparing badges to bans , because both are parameters to know if i am doing it right or wrong. What else is parameter to track how i am doing ???

Comment: @BoltClock i am not implying that reviews are existed for getting badges only, i am simply giving example  that all the reviews are considered different in a way. One more thing, I don't know why you think that getting badges can be someone's intention, apart from being measure himself, i am not aware of any usage of badges for user.

Comment: @TZHX I too trying to learn from my mistake. Same time, I was just wondering if we can have separate ban, separate ban doesnot mean one cannot learn. May be one can learn better as he may know specifically what mistake he is doing in which flow.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this wasn't the first time you were banned from reviewing. The mistake is *not paying attention*.

Comment: @TZHX yes i got previously also got banned but learned from them. Those were mostly related to question, this time actually it was answer and was looking good, but i opened question in other tab and i mostly messed up by reading other answer this time. Making mistake and learning from them made me what I am today. Infact my main reason is to learn from my and other people mistakes, as in my job I was not getting much handons to make my own mistakes

Comment: One more thing I am not able to understand, why people considering whether I am learning (I am concerned about that) or not, while answering question. Lets assume someone who was never banned (not sure how he will come to know about ban) and never made mistakes , asks same question, then also he will get same downvotes? I don't see any problem in question

Comment: @Panther Down-votes on feature requests typically mean "we don't want this".

Comment: @TZHX Ohh , I thought some big problem in my question. Now it make sense, people don't want that is fine. I saw no answer and lot of downvotes I assumed worst.

Comment: Agreed - it is a complete nonsense!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, this is not a good idea.**

Bans from the review queue are meant to say:

## You are not doing this well. Go away, and come back when you have the time to think.

They are meant to *stop you making mistakes*, not just limit your mistakes to other queues.

> All three review queues are logically separate from each other in each aspect:

That's not really true. The primary thing you're meant to be bringing to each review is the same: **attention to what you're being asked to review**. If you are consistently not paying attention to *First Posts* or *Triage* why should the system assume you're going to be paying attention to *Late Answers* or *Suggested Edits*?

> The reason behind same is that each kind of review needs different skill sets.

Not really. The only "different" queue currently is *Help & Improvement* -- but I don't think that has audits, so it's not really relevant. The only "skill" required in most cases is *reading*. Remember, if you don't know what to do, **press skip**. Skip *should* be your default option.

> Right now, I am banned from reviews because I reviewed one latest answers wrongly. So I should be banned from reviewing late answers.

Well... you don't get banned for a single failed audit. And I'm fairly sure this isn't your first ban. Furthermore, in a comment you say:

> but i opened question in other tab and i mostly messed up by reading other answer this time

If you opened the question in another tab, it should have been ***blindingly obvious*** that this was a review -- the answer you were being asked to evaluate would either be highly-upvoted or deleted. That *even then* you didn't make the right decision demonstrates you are not paying attention.

The reason that the review queues share a ban is because if you do badly on audits, it's a good indicator that you probably do badly in other reviews.

> Please can anyone explain why it's different in the case of review as compared to badges.

Because the two are only tangentially related. You get badges for completing 1, 250 and 1000 reviews in each queue because they want to incentivize people to do reviews across all of the queues. You get bans for failing review audits (or at the discretion of ♦ Moderators if they notice you've done something particularly ridiculous).