# What's the difference between the quality of a question and the quality of an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

*I feel bad for the meta effect that may result from this question, since the user **just joined today**.*

The consensus would be that [their first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338637/4151918) needs some help.  But somehow, it made it through the First Posts review queue, and I'm guessing it was not reviewed as a Low Quality Post?

[Matt's answer is funny.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338691/4151918)  (Maybe it will get tens or hundreds of upvotes.)

But the new user is just *poorly* asking for help.  They *did* get a good answer, and I'm glad they found help, even though their question was low-quality.

I haven't been here a year yet, but I do start to feel a little cynical about the questions that show up from people who need are trying to code without an understanding of basics, who seem to want a "block of code" they can copy and paste without really understanding what it really does.

My [very first question and experience at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26492749/4151918) was slightly negative.  A user assumed I didn't understand cell reuse.  It turned out to be an iOS bug.  I learned, but the experience I see now and then is that we may (inadvertently) be cynical about questions or get tired of answering them.

The site has problems, and I realize I'm a part of the problem, because I haven't developed the habit of "moderating" questions or users.  I'm honestly not comfortable doing that, but I really should be flagging more questions, and leaving more comments for users.

So, the question I've been wondering is, **"How do we mentor people?"**  New people who just joined today?  People like me who have been here less than a year, but still have much to learn about how SO is meant to "work."

**How do we get the more experienced users to coach new or less experienced users, for the sake of improving the site?**

*Since meta is discussing documentation and tutorials, **perhaps SO needs tutorials that guide users how to use the site**, similar to what GitHub prominently does?  Yes, there's a Help Center, but if people don't refer to it or use it, the site has to "coach" people one-by-one, through the same process, over-and-over.  And that can make people cynical or burnt out, and we lose contributors and great contributions.*

Comment: `perhaps SO needs tutorials that guide users how to use the site` - I see you have the [Informed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=4151918). Congratulations. There is your tour on how to use the site. It seems you decided to utilize the resources available. The user in your question...not so much.

Comment: Also, Matt's answer was deleted nearly 40 minutes before this meta question was posted. It had a score of 2.

Comment: "_But somehow, it made it through the First Posts review queue_" there's your problem.

Comment: The main problem you will have here is "how do we clone experienced users so we have enough for all the new and less experienced users who just want help NAO"

Comment: Related: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

Comment: @Andy.  Maybe the tour should be more prominent/visible?

Comment: @PetahChristian more prominent then a BIG POPUP on your first question saying "did you read this?"... how?

Comment: @Deduplicator I have participated in reviews.  I do better with other queues that are more objective and less subjective, mostly because I haven't gained enough proficiency at discerning what the site considers good or not.  I suppose we all learn differently.  I'd read a tutorial, but don't really learn as much from (why I failed) an audit.

Comment: Just to note that here: *You can't help everybody* We already have a help center, a tour site we have many hints and notes which will pop up and give you information when you ask a question. We have tag wikis for every tag. There is already a lot of information, but users have to read them.

Comment: @Patrice Unfortunately, the percentage of people that actually read that one-time message is low; people are in the habit of dismissing things like EULAs and TOS, and popups are unfortunately another "annoying thing" that people are sadly conditioned to "dismiss" without reading.  So, yes, perhaps the tour could be prominent in a different way?

Comment: @PetahChristian then how do you make it better? any other way you can do it will be the same "EULAs and TOS"... so, people will dismiss it.... how can you make something that will be intrusive enough that people WILL see and read the article, and at the same time, won't look like an "annoying thing"?

Comment: @Patricia I think GitHub is a good example.  I still have the GitHub Bootcamp banner visible at the top of their home page, because it's not obnoxious and serves as a point of quick reference.  I hadn't noticed it could be dismissed, but even though I now realize it can, I still don't feel the need to dismiss it.

Comment: @PetahChristian Does EVERYONE read the bootcamp on github? not at all (I know I didn't). So in the end, this doesn't change much. No matter how you put them, you won't have everyone to read it. Unless we make it mandatory and ask randomized questions on the articles.... which is just dumb IMHO.

Comment: @Patrice Look at the SO review/audit process.  People are tested.  People can fail.  People can temporarily be banned if they fail enough audits.  If users are "failing" at asking questions, why can't they be channelled to an SO bootcamp where they get exposed to the articles.  And perhaps they have to read them to recover a privilege.  Right now, there is no motivation or incentive or reason to read the documentation, and the quality directly suffers because it takes longer for people to improve.

Comment: *there is no motivation* Getting privileges back, getting answers, getting answers faster, getting upV, ... isn't motivation enough? <- You all get this if you read the help center + tour and are able to write a good question.

Comment: @PetahChristian the review/audit is a fully automated system. If we can't automate the same for the SO bootcamp..... then we need to have other users do it. Which is not feasible. Right now when questioner's quality is bad, they end up being banned, which normally leads to a meta question, followed by someone explaining what's happening... I don't see a way to have the behavior you want without having humans check new users. And since quality-conscious members are outnumbered by a BIG margin, this will be ROUGH

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes.  But there is a big disconnect between people who ask lots of questions but never accept or upvote or gain rep.  Some are here for an answer they can copy and paste but may not understand.  How do you motivate them to improve, apart from leaving comments telling them what to do?  (I suppose that's what I'm uncomfortable doing.  I can help with an answer, but I'm not experienced with helping to use the site.  Hence, how do you make them or me better?  For me, I guess I favor a safe way to learn, where I'm not penalized for mistakes.)

Comment: @PetahChristian As I see it, I think you are trying to help the users which don't want help (learning) / which we don't necessarily want on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow and many users already give new users / normal users hints, links to the help center and other helpful links, where they can learn and read. But if a user don't want to read you can't help him.

Comment: @Rizier123 The argument is that they'll never be productive members, so they aren't necessarily wanted.  But people learn at a different pace, and who can say who will become a truly valuable contributor in the future?  I think people can flourish when they are encouraged, even if it may take a while for that to be seen.

Comment: The (moral) dilemma here is whether or not we help people who don't appear to want to learn.  If we focus on promising users, and ignore or punish problematic users, it just feels wrong.