# What is the correct action for this LA review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, late-answers

Earlier today I was reviewing an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9399533) in the Late Answers queue. The answer didn't sit well with me and as I am not familiar with the topic I skipped it. I saved its URL though so I could see what the correct review for it was later. Not long after, another user came along and reviewed it selecting **No Action Needed**.

I do *not* think **No Action Needed** is the *correct* option based on reading I've done on Meta, particularly this [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/1552737). The answer does not seem like an *answer* to me. At first glance I thought it needed editing to make it clearer and more legible. However on further reading I feel there are **too many** `if's`. My understanding is an answer should be **definite** and comments should be used for clarification which is what this answer contains.

My question is what do people think the appropriate actions for this review are? Is No Action Needed correct and I'm overthinking things? Or I suppose more specifically should I be commenting to explain I don't think it really answers the question and should be posted as a comment or is flagging the answer as **Not An Answer** the correct action?

I want to point out I'm asking this for the case where a review similar to this does appear in a topic I'm familiar with and can act on.

Comment: Just remember that a *lot* of reviewers are going to "no action" the vast majority of posts, simply because that's much easier than actually reviewing posts (because *actually* reviewing posts is just hard), so the fact that it was "no actioned" doesn't mean much of anything.  Having said all of that, I don't see anything wrong with the answer at all that I'd fix; it looks like a perfectly fine answer to me (I can't judge the technical merits though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the question doesn't give enough data to go on (for example which code runs at application startup) that answerer made a best guess answer. It offers a couple of options to try and how to pinpoint the issue by eliminating possible causes. Future visitors that find this question will maybe face a different root cause but might find the answer useful.

Based on that (and that I'm somewhat familiar with that technology) I would say it is an (attempt to)  answer.

The reviewer who choose *No Action needed* is correct and so are you by skipping reviews if you are uncertain.

Please note that borderline answers might indicate a question that lacks some quality attributes. In those cases you better visit the question as well to either edit, down vote or flag/close vote the question.

Comment: @Servy sure, fixed

Comment: In this case then would the correct action to be to flag the question as too broad and as you say choose *No Action Needed*? Or should I just forget about the questions and choose *No Action Needed*?

Comment: @IKavanagh you can't flag the question from the queue so I would leave the answer alone and might flag the question for too broad or unclear.

Comment: @IKavanagh If, as a result of being shown an answer in a review queue, it becomes clear to you that a the core problem is with the question you should *absolutely* go to the question and take the appropriate action(s), whether that be voting to close it or whatever.  Presumably the whole reason you're in the review queue in the first place is to improve the content on the site.

Comment: Thanks, you've cleared up the answer for me. @Servy I think that's probably what I thought was wrong with the whole situation but didn't know specifically. Thanks for the help.