# Banning user for review - what is the reason for banning for one wrong review?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was recently banned from reviewing the queue for two days (refer **[this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317901/why-am-i-blocked-for-reviewing-only-one-answer-incorrectly)**), and the day before yesterday my ban was lifted.

Yesterday I reviewed reviews correctly, but today while reviewing **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11514437)** I was told that I reviewed it wrong and I am banned for 7 days (for only one review that may be wrong). The answer had only one downvote.

**The point here is that Stack Overflow is not a site where you post your code and get that code corrected**. Here in the answer the user provided a link which is from a trusted source with all the explanation of the user's query by which the user will learn something.

Now the person who first reviewed posted

> *While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.*

Here he tells "*Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes*", but these are official documentation which will not change.

Here some users will tell this answer is correct because this will solve the user's query, but some will argue that code should be posted because the question has code and it is low quality. **But why for only *one* wrong review?**

Comment: `but these are official documentation which will not change` oh, how naive you are :). In any case, we don't decide which sites are 'official' and which are not. If it's an answer with no information other than a link, the answer will likely be deleted. Also, it wasn't for one review. You were banned in the past. I would assume the system is much more strict after a recent banning.

Comment: @Rob but,  why  i am banned for only one wrong review.?  and everybody is/was so called `naive` at some point of time in life, you also were.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean naive as an insult.. simply that just because it's an official webpage doesn't mean the link will never break, or the content will never change. And as I mentioned before, you weren't banned for one wrong review. You were banned for one wrong review 2 days after receiving a ban.

Comment: @rob ya, for those wrong reviews i got banned for 2 days and day before yesterday my ban was lifted and from day before yesterday this was my first wrong review (i correctly remember). Now i got 7 days. "for only one wrong review"

Comment: @gnat The question you mentioned is for first posts queue and mine is in late answers queue.

Comment: it doesn't matter: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

Comment: @Sandeep the real question is "since your ban, how many audits did you get RIGHT?" Anyway.... you also seem to think that was an unfair audit... but the guidance for link only answer is CLEAR. So yeah, you messed up a review. Live with it, learn from it. Complaining about it like it's unfair will just lead to you getting unbanned and doing a similar mistake RIGHT away, then getting 30 days banned.

Answer (score 12):

You are not banned for one failure, you are banned for a combination of your current failure and the fact that you've recently been banned and have not used that as a wake up call to change the way you are reviewing.

This time the increased ban length does seem to have got your attention so per its design it has worked (assuming your reviewing does improve). If not your next ban will be for 30 days.

Comment: I did mistake in past  and i got banned for that. but  I review in 3 queues i,e 60 review allowed ( i nearly review around 40) and in that a user can't have one wrong review, that also on a `ambiguous reason`. This is very very harsh and disappointing.

Comment: Its supposed to be harsh, bad reviewing is a very big problem here.

Comment: @Sandeep You keep saying it's one wrong review, despite being told repeatedly that it wasn't *just one*.

Comment: @Rob This is my review history http://i.stack.imgur.com/kGy4s.png . i failed only one review that is marked after my two day ban was lifted.

Comment: @Sandeep I am not really sure how to say it any clearer: You were banned for 7 days because of this review *and* the reviews which caused the first ban. They don't magically get removed from your history once the ban was lifted, especially since it only took you two days after a ban to make a bad review. It seems you are not the least concerned with *why* you were banned, and trying to fix it in the future - you're just simply wanting your ban removed.