# Can we ignore plagiarism during audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I have failed a review audit today because, I thought the answer is copied from other answer.

This what happened

- I saw a one liner solution to a old question.
- Opened the question in another tab
- There is an exactly same answer from another user.
- Came back to 'review' page, here the answer is from different user.
- So, I clearly understood that, it's an audit in review.
- I want to flag it as 'plagarism', Couldn't find any option. So, thought of leaving a comment with downvote.
- As soon as, I downvoted, it says 'audit' failed.
- User name changed to a actual one, which is shown in another tab.

so, Audit fooled me that as if this post is from different user than the original one.

**It worries so much because, I failed this audit when I clearly know that this is an audit question.**

How to deal with this situation ?

Comment: I suppose using "Audity McFakename" for all of these might help a little bit.

Comment: See the end of [this [faq-proposed]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506) for instructions on how to catch these audits. Basically, pay attention to where on the page you ended up when you clicked the link. If the answer scrolled to has a different username... it's still the same actual answer!

Comment: @NathanTuggy, That's how exactly I was fooled. Actual page has same identical answer from another user. Review page user doesn't exist in the actual page. So, I have decided to take down the post in 'review' page. Now, I am banned.

Comment: @Raju: That's my point. That was a mistake, for the reason I gave in the link (which somehow broke, sorry -- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506 is what I meant), because that was, in fact, the answer you were reviewing. There was no other user and no other answer that had ever been posted with that text on that question.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, During audit, deleted posts will be displayed. These deleted posts can't be seen by user with <10K. I thought this audit was a plagiarism test, and duplicate answer has been deleted (as the this user is not available in actual page).

Comment: @Raju: Right, but you were wrong to believe so. The link you can click to get to the answer under review will *always* either take you to *that very answer*, or, if it was deleted, take you to the top of the question. There is therefore no possibility of error in determining whether or not the answer was an audit based on a plagiarized post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, you shouldn't get straight-up plagiarism as an audit.

Now, I have to make an immediate exception here for things that are plagiarism + spam, since those *do* show up in audits and for good reason. But the critical aspect of those is that they have *spam* in them as well. That's what makes them unsalvageable in life, and useful for auditing in death.

But in the absence of spam, you can cheerfully assume there's no attempt to trick you. If you don't see two mostly-identical answers on the page, wave it through.

Comment: If we skip 'plagiarism' in review's, how do we  deal with the answers copied from others. for ex: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36587030/5832518), this answer is same as existing one, but not identical. Answer was formatted a bit.

Comment: Didn't say anything about skipping plagiarism, @raju - merely that you shouldn't encounter it in audits. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: understood, But new user will never know this, until there are some guidelines for review. They will know only once they get banned from review, just like me. It will be nice, if there is link at every review page. ex :[triage review guide](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

Comment: I believe [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/5832518) should be revised. It says -- ***So if you're checking for plagiarism as you should, but aren't paying attention to which part of the page you landed on, you might look at the accepted answer and see that it looks just like the audit copy but has a different author! If it was scrolled to when the page loaded, it's still the same post***

Comment: @Raju: I'm not sure what you think needs revision, exactly, but I've edited to try to clarify the point made originally there. (Plagiarism *should* be checked for in the queue in general.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy, Yes, Shog9 has mentioned the same. We should check that. But, Audit posts won't be taken from 'plagiarism' cases.  [see this statement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320899/5832518) ***I have to make an immediate exception here for things that are plagiarism + spam*** -- shog9

Comment: @Raju: Yeah...? The guide is written from the perspective of not knowing immediately whether a post is or isn't an audit, and checking conservatively accordingly in a way that will not fail audits needlessly, nor treat regular posts wrong.

Comment: Lemme try and clarify this, @Raju. You were second-guessing yourself on a review, and determined that it was an audit. Then you realized the post existed on the page in a different form and, uh, second-guessed yourself again. IOW, if you'd gone with your gut instincts the first time around, you'd have been fine. But since you assumed that the system was trying to trick you, and then made further assumptions on the nature of this trick... You got tripped up. So don't do that - don't try and think your way around the system, focus on what you can actually see.

Comment: @Shog9, Thanks. You are right. I think, if I open that user (from review page), it will show actual user with actual rep. I could have done that !!

Comment: I just failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24303343) where the answer *was* straight-up plagiarism, but with *no spam*. The user still exists so presumably it's not the same case as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388919/1364007) where all a user's negatively-scored posts were spam-deleted. I don't dispute that I should have failed the audit - on a second look, the review answer is slightly different to [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450167/1364007). Should the answer in my review be an audit?

Comment: Yeah, that answer should definitely have been removed, but it probably wasn't spam, @WaiHaLee. I've removed it from the pool used for audits.