# Review late answer - middle quality post with nothing new (but could be improved)

Tags: discussion

today I was reviewing late answers and I found myself in trouble what to do correctly. Lets look at this question: [What is the difference between Normalize.css and Reset CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css). It was asked 4 years ago and I think we can say it is successful question with plenty of good, exhausting answers.

In Review I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541548/2916232) to that question, made by new user. It is not bad (in meaning of it's content), although it should be edited to improve some grammar aspects (in time of my decision there was pending edit).

When I looked to previously posted answers, they were more readable, contained more facts and they so that answer didn't bring nothing new (in my opinion, maybe I'm wrong).
Although I was fighting with my self because I want to courage new users to bring new facts and info to old question, I decided to **flag** it as **Low quality post**. (I didn't want to bother moderator)

So, was my decision correct? Should we decide to close late answers that didn't bring anything new? (Assuming that we can edit answer to meet SO standards). And if I made mistake, what should I do next time?

**EDIT:** My flag was accepted, but I assume it was automatically accepted when pending edit was reviewed and approved. Still, that answer brings nothing new and look way more poorer than older ones. And I noticed that the answer was downvoted (so it isn't very good answer indeed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty good [review guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) for the Late Answer review queue.

> In *either queue*, if you see an **answer** that:
>
> ...
>
> - Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough:
>
>   - Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if a substantially earlier answer already said
>       everything this does; if so:
>
>     - Downvote; comment if practical.

Flagging is not mentioned there, but doesn't hurt. This answer does not add any value to the already existing answers, so the site is better off when it's deleted. Thanks for doing so.