# Pasting Fiddle snippet into original question as an edit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

When I was reviewing "Suggested Edits", I came across an edit where someone had pasted the code from the Fiddle OP had added into the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437708/validate-form-input-on-keyup-with-jquery). I skipped it because I was unsure what to do.

What would be the correct way of handling this? Approve, Reject?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the question itself should contain the code and not only a link to another site like jsfiddle or pastebin. But I guess I would have rejected (and edited) this particular case due to the sloppy job of the editor. The indentation is horrific.

Comment: Self containt post are the best so the idea is great. I would have accept andreindent it my self.

Comment: I agree with @PierreLebon. "Improve Edit" fixing the formatting. The original editor had the right intentions in putting the code in the question, but the formatting needed some help to make it more readable

Comment: I'm amazed at how few people use the Tidy button in Stack Snippets. It fixes the format for you! In one click! Click it!

Comment: Very clear. Next time I will approve the edit (after fixing the indentation of course) instead of skipping it. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan there is a tidy button?...

Comment: Why did you accept Bakuriu answer? The formulation of his arguments are completely wrong. When a user creates a SO account they agree to the site's terms. The terms include questions, answers and code are CC-BY-SA. OP's option is *not* ask on Stack Overflow. Otherwise code accompanies the question per site rules.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What the editor did is wrong, because it copied content they did not own into a question which is under CC-BY-SA. This could make other people think they are legally using the code, even though they do not actually have a valid license. The OP specifically did not put the code in their post, and did not provide an explicit license in their jsFiddle ([jsFiddle does not impose any kind of license, which means there is *no license*, unless explicitly stated, and all the copyright rights remain to the sole author of the snippet](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/meta/credits.html#license)).

So: reject these edits. However, you should also:

- Comment on the question noticing the OP that the post is incomplete and they should add a StackSnippet.
- Vote to close the question as lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Possibly downvote the question.

Comment: Should we revert the changes in that case?

Comment: @Cœur Well, I wouldn't, simply because in 99.9% of the cases the OP doesn't actually care for such matters, moreover the history of the post will keep containing the offending code so if the OP really wants the code removed he'll have to file a DMCA request to remove the entire page. I'd just `@notify` the editor that what they did is wrong.

Comment: @Bakuriu: You're mostly right, but takedown doesn't require removal of the entire page, it's possible for the developers to scrub a single revision from the history.

Comment: Wait, what? If a question is unclear because it wasn't included in the question we should not edit it because... what? There's so much absurdity in meta...

Comment: @Braiam Blame lawyers.

Comment: For people wondering, Pastebin content is CC-BY-SA, so unlike jsFiddle, it's fine to reuse Pastebin given that you attribute the author.

Comment: @Cœur - Is attribution really necessary when the bin & question authors are the same person? All content in a post is already assumed to be by the post's author unless otherwise stated. Wouldn't it be redundant to point out that the OP's code belongs to them?

Comment: @BSMP It was included in the post by someone else, so I think attribution of Pastebin content would be ambiguous without otherwise stated: but author(s) can be written in the edit description, that's enough for CC-BY-SA.

Comment: *"This could theoretically allow other people to legally use code that the OP specifically did not want to allow"* - That's not how Stack Overflow works. When OP agrees to site terms then questions, answers and code is covered under CC-BY-SA. The content was always part of the question. OP's option is to *not* ask on Stack Overflow if he/she does not agree to terms.

Comment: @jww No you are wrong. In this particular instance the code *Was not* hosted on StackOverflow. An editor put it in against the choice of the OP. StackOverflow license only covers the text on SO, not the things that you link to. I'm not saying that using a jsfiddle is right, in fact I'm against them. However copying the content from the fiddle to the question without author permission is not okay. It's the author that should do that, otherwise the question should be closed/deleted for lack of code.

Answer (score 0):

If the author has a minimal reproducible version of what is his issue, then the outside resource link isn't necessary. If the MCVE included in the question doesn't illustrate the problem yet the one in the outside resource does, including the code from the outside resource is warranted, otherwise close it as lacking MCVE.

The later option is obviously more costly for the community so it should be avoided. It can be simply edited into the question, in all the years of SO, I haven't heard of a single case of someone complaining that its code was included in the question so others can answer it... never.

Comment: Oddly enough, it just happened here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344869/asker-refuses-to-keep-mcve I've seen other users refuse to add the necessary code themselves but that might be the first time I've seen them actually edit it back out if someone else added.