# Asker refuses to keep MCVE

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, minimal-reproducible-example

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42557732/2069064) is the question in question (10k only). Originally, it contained just a code fragment, referencing many names that weren't defined in the question. I prompted the user for an MCVE and they provided a pastebin link. The code in the pastebin link actually is an MCVE, so I edited it into the question.

However, OP has reverted this change. Twice. If they *actively* do not want to provide an MCVE, what do I do? Just DV/VTC and move on with my life?

Comment: Pretty much. I have an "auto-comment" for when people link to their code: "Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site." If they don't take the hint, VTC as lacking MCVE. *shrug* Some people...

Comment: I'd say dv/vtc, move on. _After_ explaining _why_ they should put the code in the question itself. (Which a couple of us have now done, so if they ignore the advice, totally dv/vtc and let it go.)

Comment: Hopefully a few more comments reiterating your valid point will make them see sense. If not well that's VTC and they won't be helped.

Comment: Welp, I've done the best I can. If the OP edits the MCVE into their question, it can get reopened. If not, well, they were warned.

Comment: *After explaining why they should put the code in the question itself.* @Kendra - This makes sense for new users but not users who have been around and been active as long as this user has. New users might argue with you because they don't know/understand the rules & how they're enforced but established users argue (and revenge down vote) because they know about the rules and just don't care.

Comment: I've encountered similar resistance when the OP shouldn't actually be posting the code to SO, wants the answer, and will destroy the off-site material when they've got the answer, leaving what's on SO incomprehensible. This is reprehensible; down-vote, vote-to-close, maybe comment on it. If you've got a vested interest — you've provided an answer and the OP wants to remove the material — flag a moderator. (The example I'm thinking of was going to become an exercise for the course they were teaching, and they didn't want the answer on SO.) Don't engage in edit wars; that's counter-productive.

Comment: The "asker" can bugger off, frankly. We have better things to do than handhold such counter-productive idiots. Remember, he/she is asking for _our_ time, not the other way around. We have no obligation to spend more of it on them, and life's too short for this to be tempting to do anyway. Delete and move on. They can find their free help someplace else.

Comment: mm. It makes perfect sense to me to keep question's code to minimum (so that it's short and fast to read to get the gist of it) and provide a link to the more complete example on site where you can edit it real time.

Comment: @lakesare: NO. It is a well-established (and sensible IMHO) site policy that _questions must stand on their own_. You can make the quesiton short & fast to read by having a summary first, then the complete code at the bottom. And a "link to a site where you can edit in real time" is totally ok, if it is in addition to that.

Comment: In some programming languages it's ok to give the MCVE via links as they contain multiple files, eg. javascript often has links to pages where you can edit the html, script and css. I don't see why that should be different between languages. Though I don't know how long pastebin is stored.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful If the code has multiple files, you can simulate that by putting them in separate code blocks (and for the specific case of HTML/JS/CSS, Stack Snippets can do that for you anyway). There's no situation where it's acceptable to provide necessary code only via links.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If it is true that the non-pastebin code does not demonstrate and/or reproduce the problem at hand, and the asker is not interested in supplying the code that actually *does* within the question, then the asker is the one that's not interested in a solution to their actual problem in the first place. That's their problem, not yours.

Note that I said "If it is true that the non-pastebin code does not". If the non-pastebin code *does* produce the error message, then it counts as an MCVE, and the pastebin link probably isn't essential and should probably just go away.

Comment: Although their non-pastebin does provide the error (or so they say in their question) I don't think it's useful to those who want to repro and that's what the code from pastebin link provided.

Comment: @Bugs: Yeah, if it's non-reproducible despite the asker's claims then it counts as non-reproducible and the question should be closed.

Comment: It's not an MCVE if it's not Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. Half a function complaining some error that _happens_ to occur on those lines is neither Complete nor Verifiable. (I have no idea if that's the case, but it's incorrect to say "if it produces the error message, it's an MCVE")

Answer (score 26):

From the OP in recent comments

> the question actually had a minimal example provided. It is a lie that it did not, and it was super-easy to access.

And

> I'm just utterly sad that I am not free to ask the question I had, the way I intended. I'll leave this question as it is refractor my code not to use lambdas here, and hope, that when someone else has the same problem, the person will not be blamed if they don't accept bad edits.

This person is recalcitrant. Just [break the wrist and walk away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9Mn6nez900)

Answer (score 15):

> The code in the pastebin link actually is an MCVE, so I edited it into the question.

I'm not sure about Pastebin, but for jsFiddle you shouldn't do that, [as stated in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/1033581), because it is content you do not own and there may be legal issues.

So, if in doubt, unless you are sure about the copyright of the linked content, you shouldn't edit someone else's post, copying code into its question/answer. Instead, close the post as off-topic and ask the OP to perform the edit themselves.

[Edit]
T.J. Crowder found out that Pastebin content was [CC BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses) 3.0, up until October 14, 2020, so actually it should be fine to copy-paste it to Stack Overflow which is also [under the same license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285711/source-code-on-stack-overflow-cc-by-sa-or-mit), given that you attribute the author and that the Pastebin content predates October 14, 2020.

Comment: @genpfault - Seems to be gone now. :-| S'okay, I didn't really think copying things from pastebin to SO was a good idea. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Vote to close. Down vote because the asker is undermining reasonable attempts to improve the question. Then find something else to do.