# Should I add protected content to a question?

Tags: discussion

This question: [JavaScript nested arrays exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44683468/691711) is asking for help with a coding course.  However, the poster has neglected to give much detail about what they are trying to do.  They have provided a link to the exercise on the coding course, but when I go to access the link to add relevant information from that link, I am asked to sign up for an email list before I can see the exercise.

I'm inclined to just give a trash email and add the pertinent content, but I'm not sure if that would be wise since the content is behind a subscription wall.

Comment: Sounds like that would be a copyright violation and you'd be the infringer. If the question does not make sense without the link, vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @RobertLongson IANAL, but couldn't that be considered fair use?  The question is useless without the course question context.

Comment: I don't think that fair use applies when you license that stuff as 'cc by-sa 3.0' (the license used by Stack Exchange), but I'm no lawyer.

Comment: @Tom Where did you find that it was CC by-SA?  I was looking for a license to see if linking back to the tutorial was enough.  If it is in fact CC-BY-SA, then I could add the content as long as I attribute right?

Comment: Just scroll down to the bottom of the page :D. It says "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required". *"If it is in fact CC-BY-SA, then I could add the content as long as I attribute right?"* - Sorry, I can't tell you that. Copyright can be tricky, so I wouldn't do that in order to avoid issues.

Comment: @Tom I'm talking about the actual course site, not SO.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thought you were talking about SO.

Comment: I think the wall makes it clear that they don't want that content to be completely public, which posting it on Stack Overflow would do. The only thing to do here is flag & vote since you already asked the OP to improve their question and they've already said they aren't going to.

Comment: Relevant: [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/4639281). Don't include content from anywhere unless you are the license holder, or you are absolutely certain that the content's license is compatible with CC-by SA (the license that Stack Overflow uses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has failed to include pertinent, critical details into their question, and as such, their question should be put on hold as the "Why isn't this code working?" rationale, specifically due to their failure to include this pertinent information.

You are under no obligation to copy that information in.  You may elect to inform them in a comment that they should add that information in - especially since the majority close reason would be "unclear" - but you're not obligated to add the link.

I'm no lawyer and I don't want to pretend to be, but I would err on the side of caution when it comes to adding links or content that you're not entirely clear on their legality.  Also, y'know, it does mean that the OP is technically cheating on university course work, and I'd rather that kind of thing be made open to the general public and let them deal with any potential fallout from plagiarism that may ensue.

Comment: It's not clear from their web site whether grades/credentials are awarded based on work completed in the free courses. Their FAQ only talks about the Bootcamp stuff, which is paid.

Comment: @BSMP:  It may not be university coursework then.  I was in a bit of a rush when I skimmed that link.  In either event, I would imagine that there is *some* policy in effect which pertains to disingenuous answers anyway...