# When to edit code/links into snippet?

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-snippets, code

Being that I'm relatively new in my education on front-end development, I've come across a lot of older, basic questions that I use to help myself along. Oftentimes, if there is plain code there, I edit the question so that it will view as a snippet, like so:

```html
<p> Hello world! </p>
```

However, I also often find answers and questions that contain links to websites such as JSFiddle.

What is our stance on taking code from these sites and putting them into a snippet?

My initial view is that it is more helpful to have the code on-site, in case one of these sites goes down and for readability, but I am unsure if this is unnecessary or increases server load.

Comment: Also, see [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/4642212).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't able to find those resources by searching for some reason. Pretty much exactly what I was looking for.