# Question closed after submitting an edit

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, specific-edit

I edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861992/what-is-wrong-with-my-solution-to-find-the-largest-element-in-the-given-vector) a little while ago, the approval of which is still pending. However, the question got closed around 15 mins ago on the grounds of [details needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). My edit essentially fixes this very issue. The OP seems to be new and had posted the complete question and code as a screenshot instead of typing it out, which I have corrected. I feel my edit resolves that problem. Why was the question closed before the approval of my edit?

Comment: I fear that was a wasted effort. OP posted an image and they shouldn't have: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Transcribing that image to text is 1. unreliable 2. Has some risk of breaching license similar to [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698)

Comment: In general we should not transcribe images for the OP. Closure is the best option and then have the OP provide the code as text instead of an image.

Comment: I must admit, the amount of effort some people put into answering the linked question, it's no wonder some people are so lazy when they post their questions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69862571/2029983) (10k only) might as well be a full on article...

Comment: @Larnu, I did not put much effort in the answer, because that much effort was not needed for such a poorly asked question :)

Comment: I'm not saying you did, @kesarlingHe-Him , just that at least one person did. Answers to such questions, in my opinion, don't help anyone; not the OP, not the one answering, nor future readers.

Comment: Isn't there a (canonical) meta post about transcribing images of code? I was expecting to find something about this in *[How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219)* (it has ***a lot*** of *don'ts*), but didn't.

Comment: I think you want this one, @PeterMortensen : [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) *"**Don't:** Transcribe code from an image to text. It's just too easy to introduce new errors."*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Question closure doesn't wait for pending edits. Closure and suggested edits are completely orthogonal processes. We don't want closure to wait for *anything*; ideally, questions should be closed as quickly as possible.

If the suggested edit does, in fact, correct the issues with the question that led to its getting closed, then the question can be reopened once the edit is approved.

In fact, the UI for reviewing your suggested edit now looks like this:

[image]

Note the "Approve and reopen" and "Approve and leave closed" buttons.

---

Aside from that general answer, looking at this specific edit… yeah, you probably shouldn't be making edits like this. As your edit summary said, you "essentially created the post". That's not your job; that's the asker's job. You must have manually transcribed that code from the image. We recommend against that for at least three reasons:

1. It's a ridiculous amount of manual work for no reason. There are other, more important things you could be doing with the time you're willing to devote to Stack Overflow.
2. You might make a transcription mistake that would lead to the question getting answers that would eventually turn out to be unhelpful or irrelevant, and/or the question getting closed as a typo when the typo was not there in the original code.
3. Putting code in the body of the post actually *licenses* it under CC by-SA to Stack Overflow. You, as a third party, don't technically have the ability to re-license code provided by the original poster. Therefore, this edit is legally dubious.

Comment: Does that mean that if a question has a pending edit, that edit is not seen by the person who's closed the question? That's weird :(

Comment: That's correct. Pending edits are not seen by anyone who votes to close the question. It's not weird; the processes have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him users who have the close vote privilege can also see pending edits. But it's not directly shown to them when closing - they have to look at the Edit button and see there is one. With that said, I'd argue they don't need to in this case. It's a classical case of low effort question. Nobody is obliged to put more work into reviewing this question than OP did.

Comment: As there seemed to be an answer to the question, I just thought of making it a little, for the lack of a better word, "viewable". But that's fine. I will try not to make such mistakes in the future :)

Comment: Um... In reference to point 3, am I not supposed to put the code in the body of SO, even when the code is a gist (or some such text), essentially not an image?

Comment: Yes, the licensing situation makes it legally dubious for you to copy code or other text from external sources linked in the question into the body of the question itself. We (as mods) certainly wouldn't *punish* or otherwise sanction you for doing this, but it's not really something we can *encourage* or recommend, either. See related Q&A: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698 @kesarling

Comment: The point that the textual representation of code re-licenses it is unreasonable. The OP licensed the code when he first posted it. The form is not substantive. The substance is substantive. There may be good reasons to reject that edit but "editor relicensed code he doesn't have the ability to licence" is not one.