# How to handle edit limitations when adding code to a question?

Tags: discussion, edits

My problem started with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746386/unable-to-inject-into-a-component) and [my revision of it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47746386/revisions).

When I added the code from a link that the OP provided I couldn't submit the edit because it only contained code. Thing is - that was the whole point of the edit. So I had to also put the error message in a blockquote for it to count as a valid edit.

So should I just avoid questions that are not editable because of limitations or try and circumvent the problem by just adding minor edits to the revision?

Just a small extra note: I've also encountered problems while trying to remove wrongly used code blocks, blockquotes, etc.

Comment: I close vote those as 'Unclear' and move on, else you end up putting much more effort into the question than the OP.

Comment: Questions that actively try to bypass the quality filters rarely are of good quality. You don't have enough rep yet to close them, but I'd flag them as _Very low quality_, if I were you, unless you believe the questions do have some quality. You can try to help the OP by specifying what's wrong with the question (in this case, this is far from the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue, thus it's not [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Well, in this case I tried to make a good post out of a decent question. The question itself can be useful - the way it was asked was bad. I understand the idea behind just flagging it, otherwise I can see now that making that kind of an edit encourages an "I can post however I want, someone else can fix it" mentality.

Comment: Well, imo the question is not that decent, since it lacks context (no description of what the code was doing exactly, adding such a description would avoid the quality filters, no sharing any research about the problem, just an error and code), and could probably be reproduced with less code.  The problem might be interesting, but the asker should've put in a little more effort and context, and doing so would've avoided the quality filter

Comment: **Do not copy code into a post from an external source for the OP.** In general, doing so has significant copyright/licensing issues. If the OP has chosen not to put the code in a question, then act on the post as it is (any/all of down-vote; vote/flag to close (usually no MCVE, Unclear or Too Broad); etc.). Please see [Pasting Fiddle snippet into original question as an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344484/3773011) and [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/3773011).

Comment: In some *very limited* situations, it *may* be acceptable to do so. However, first determining what the license is for the code and then complying with whatever that license is, can be difficult and/or complex. Doing so legitimately/legally is *almost never* just a simple copy-&-paste. Note that this sets aside the issue that you very rarely can actually *prove* that the OP is the one that actually holds the copyright to the code. Let the OP copy the code into the question/answer. You can leave a comment asking the OP to do so and act on the post as it actually exists.

Comment: Related [MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304331/may-i-edit-a-question-with-a-jsfiddle-link-to-incorporate-the-code), coincidence?

Comment: @MártonMolnár unrelated I think (technical vs legal), but I've given a reply to it.