# Restricting 'pastebin.ca'

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, licensing

I noticed that **https://pastebin.ca isn't CC-BY-SA** (as opposed to https://pastebin.com), so we can't re-insert **pastebin.ca** content back into a post.

So please restrict usage of **pastebin.ca** the same way as **jsfiddle** is restricted. Thank you.

Posts using pastebin.ca:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Apastebin.ca

Examples of no-code posts with link to pastebin.ca:

- [mysql not using composite index but only by FORCE INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739645/mysql-not-using-composite-index-but-only-by-force-index)
- [integrate pdf generator to mailer in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188414/integerate-pdf-generator-to-mailer-in-php)
- [Firebase on Unity error: get_realtimeSinceStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731542/firebase-on-unity-error-get-realtimesincestartup)
- [Yarn resource manager fails the application even though Spark application executes successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538689/yarn-resource-manager-fails-the-application-even-though-spark-application-execut)
- [Running existing application with Java9 causes Guice Injector error with PreDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905547/running-existing-application-with-java9-causes-guice-injector-error-with-predest)
- [Spring Boot Getting Started Guide "Accessing Data with JPA" throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783576/spring-boot-getting-started-guide-accessing-data-with-jpa-throws-an-exception)
- [Easy way to convert complex json to simple POJO files for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721477/easy-way-to-convert-complex-json-to-simple-pojo-files-for-android)
- [How to make object bounce off edge of canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101054/how-to-make-object-bounce-off-edge-of-canvas)
- ...

Comment: All posts on pastebin.ca are public domain according to [this page](https://pastebin.ca/what.php). I know public domain isn't legally sound everywhere, but is this really a problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the jsfiddle restriction isn't based on a legal issue. It's for practical reasons.

Comment: The copyright at another site only affects whether we should be copy/pasting the OP's code for them into the question (we shouldn't be for JSFiddle, it's OK with Pastebin). They shouldn't be posting links to code without including it in the question regardless of the copyright at the 3rd party site.

Comment: @Stijn for people which applicable law is from some countries where there is an inalienable moral right, like France, then it's impossible to make the content Public Domain. Which means that if me (French), I post on pastebin.ca and I declare the content "Public Domain", it will not work and I will keep my full moral rights on it until I die or change nationality. The only way to reliably track the permissions is to attribute the content an **explicit** license, being it either CC0, CC-BY or CC-BY-SA. See [the **Problem** §](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0)

Comment: What JSFiddle restriction are you talking about?

Comment: @TylerH I think its related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable

Comment: Also related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit/344512#344512

Comment: So not an actual system restriction or even a policy, just a discussion that was had between users. This shouldn't be tagged [tag:feature-request] if that's the case, as there's no actual feature like what OP is requesting we copy.

Comment: @Cœur can you clarify what you mean by "the same way JSFiddle is restricted"?

Comment: @Cœur I'm sure things can get complicated, but it seems to me if you post code to a website hosted in a country where public domain exists, complaints that it got re-posted to somewhere else that also recognizes public domain are going to be legally baseless.

Comment: @TylerH Since they have a list of *Examples of no-code posts with link to pastebin.ca*, I'm assuming they mean the restriction that prevents users from putting links to JSFiddle in their questions without including any code in the question itself. It seems they think that's for copyright reasons but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @BSMP I'm guessing that's what they're referring to as well but like you said they're associating it with copyright so I want to be sure I know what feature Coeur is referring to.

Comment: It may be worth banning if it's constantly mis-used, but that doesn't have anything to do with its license. If we forbid links to non-compatibly-licensed content, that would include MSDN and many other sources of documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few concerns here that we probably need to talk about individually.

#### 1 - We can't ever hope to ensure 100% license compatibility.

CC BY-SA 3.0 isn't a great license for code to begin with, and its compatibility with other standard licenses for that use case is dubious at best. But, there are scenarios where code mixes are decidedly *less* worrisome than others, and 'public domain' is one of those. While the concept of public domain doesn't hold up in some areas, when you get *into* those areas, CC BY-SA gets sketchy too. While this doesn't solve the problem of Public Domain not being a license specifically saying *you can use this with no restrictions at all*, it *doesn't* add more restrictions on top of CC BY-SA, so it's not making *that* problem any worse.

Additionally, people can host their own stuff on various platforms (including Github, their own domain, older forges, etc - they are free to write their own licenses that blankets everything there.

#### 2 - Most snippets are functional, anyway.

No, not as in functional programming, but as in they *don't really implement any kind of art* and it's dubious if a court would even consider them to *be* licensable. There's a devil in there, though, because you can cram a heck of a lot of art into a sorting algorithm that's easily mistaken for just some boilerplate code. Point is, folks need to be conscious of what they copy ***regardless***, and any sense of security from some kind of cross-site license compatibility initiative would be sketchy-to-false to begin with. I'd love a world where we don't have to worry about this, but I'd be doing you a major disservice by misleading you into thinking you're safe because we actively block anything that doesn't legally mix.

#### 3 - Our guidance for attribution really does help.

Use it from our site? Somewhere else? It's The Right Thing To Do ™ to leave a code comment pointing to where you found it anyway. Not only does it satisfy attribution requirements, it helps hand code over to new maintainers, helps you figure out *if* you have any code from 'foomatic.com' if needed, and just makes a great reference point. If you're doing *that*, you can ratchet down your worrying to under a dull roar and let legal deal with whatever comes up.

---

Now with that said, the site does currently 503 when I hit links to it. One reason why we *might* block links to something is total unreliability (or they later inject ads obnoxiously, etc), so if you notice posts *depending* on content from this domain for relevancy - it's worth editing to pull any relevant information in if the post is worth keeping.

But that's a practical, not theoretically legal reason for doing it :) So if reliability becomes a major issue, bring it up again and let's decide on that alone - but doing it for licensing reasons isn't the best way to make it go down in site history.

Comment: Thank you Tim Post for answering. Regarding your first paragraph statement "_We can't ever hope to ensure 100% license compatibility_", let's note that: (1) If pastebin.ca had been CC-by-SA 3.0 or [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0), then editors could ensure the compatibility; (2) Without aiming for 100%, it's Stack Exchange duty to look after popular hosts compatibility (like it was done for jsfiddle among others), so imo it could boils down to ask if 10 votes here or [265 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Apastebin.ca) is worth taking actions.