# I failed an audit, but why is my response considered incorrect?

Tags: discussion

I recently was going through the first post review queue on Stack Overflow, and I failed an audit. I would like to know *why* I failed the audit, as I fail to see a problem with the answer that was posted.

[Here is a link to the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16534623)

Now, having seen the other answers on the post after the audit, I can see why it would have been denied. I also did not see the answers down votes or comment.

Given just the information in the audit, I felt like the answer did answer the question in a way that made sense and also explained what it actually was.

I trust that Stack Overflow is correct in this decision, I am not debating that, I would just like to improve my reviewing for future reference and want to know how to avoid a similar situation in the future.

Comment: So you indicated that there was nothing to do in the case of a post, you've since found out that the post is a bad post, and you know why, so...what's the question?   You know now why the post was bad, and you know that you should have noticed it earlier, but didn't.  What more is there to say?  Next time make sure not to indicate posts like this don't require any action (or that they're good answers).

Comment: First posts should be reviewed in context. What awesome value does the post adds to the site, or in case of an answer, to the question. For the given example there is none. So check the context before you make a review decision, not afterwards.

Comment: You can always see the question below the answer and especially for old questions there tend to be a lot of low quality answers so you should definitely take that into consideration. If you're unsure you can also click on the question or click on the *link*. In that case you would have immediately noticed that it's an audit because the answer is already deleted. And if you're still unsure there's nothing wrong with hitting the *Skip* button.

Comment: @Servy So even in the review queue I need to look at the rest of the post? It seems to me that the review queue should INCLUDE the rest of the post in that case. My decision was out of context because I was basing my entire reasoning on the context I was given.

Comment: @rene Again I didn't realize I was supposed to actually go to the post and look at other answers etc, I feel like that should all be displayed in the review. My decision was based on the content that was given to me.

Comment: @Keiwan I was not able to see the comment until I made a decision. My decision was based on all the context that I was given, if I'm supposed to review every other answer in the question as well, then why was that context not given to me in the queue?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton You need to be able to recognize when a post isn't adding any value.  If you need to go to the question itself to see that, then do so.  If you're able to properly review the post without needing to go to the question itself (as is certainly often, although not necessarily always, the case) then more power to you.

Comment: @Servy But how do I know when I need more details about the post? The answer in question _does_ actually answer the question asked I think, and in a way that may be welcomed in some other places.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The comment is simply telling you how someone else felt the post should be reviewed.  You didn't need to see their comment to come to the same conclusion as they did.  You could have looked at the answers yourself and determined that this answer wasn't adding anything new to the table, which is a major problem of answers like these, and certainly something that you should be looking out for.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It's up to you to determine when you need more context.  If you find yourself unable to determine when a post is appropriate, or how it can be improved, without looking at the entire question, then look at the entire question, if you're able to recognize how a post can be improved or otherwise moderated, be confident that it doesn't need any improvements, without needing any additional context, or to at least know what red flags indicate a need for further investigation, then you'll know when you can avoid opening up the question.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for the advice. Although I still believe the other answers should maybe be included on the review page, to make reviewing easier for the reviewer, what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The more information you include, the less visible it is.  If you include everything, then nothing stands out.  The link to the question itself is there for the cases that you need it, and when you don't, it's not in your way.

Comment: @Servy Okay. I appreciate your time on this topic, thank you :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Oh you're right, the First Posts queue doesn't actually immediately show the question as well (the LQPQ does which is what I had in mind when I wrote it).

Comment: @Keiwan Yes if I had that context I definitely would have answered differently :P I understand where I went wrong now though. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first posts and late answers review queues are a bit more in-depth than the low quality posts review queue.

In the low quality posts review queue, you're determining whether or not something qualifies for immediate deletion. These posts either can be improved or are already good enough, or they can't be improved and need to be deleted as quick as possible. Any effort you put forth on top of that is gravy.

In the first posts and late answers review queues, you're expected to put more effort into determining whether or not the answer is a *good* answer.

In the first posts queue, you are literally reviewing the first post that user has posted, their introduction to the site. This is your chance to correct any deviations from what we expect here at Stack Overflow and get the user on the right track. If you like quality content, treasure these reviews. There's no better route to quality content than quick and early user education.

In the late answers queue, you want to make sure that this new answer adds something over what is already present in the other answers, or at least presents that information in a different manner. There is no use keeping a low quality answer to a question that already has four or five high quality answers. Again, it is important to educate the users on what we expect at this point, and help them make the answer into all it can be.

In this case it was both a first post and a late answer, and there were already a few higher quality answers saying relatively the same thing in different ways. The new low quality answer did not add anything new. The correct action here would have been to investigate, then downvote and possibly comment.

Comment: I also failed an audit today on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16538683), which imo, clearly answers the question, though it might be a bit short in explanation (failed because I wanted to upvote, from my point of view the answer had all the necessary info)

Comment: You want a "good" late answer? [Try this one on for size](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/84125/388). THAT is what a Late Answer is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 3):

From [the First Posts/Late Answers review FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts/288506#288506):

> In either queue, if you see an answer that:
>
> […]
>
> - Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough [especially if there are a number of other answers and the question is not new]:
>
>   - Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if a substantially earlier answer already said everything this does; if so:
>
>     - Downvote; comment if practical.

In this case, the answer *was* fairly trite and lacking in detail. The age of the question and the number of other answers (both of which are shown in the sidebar) give a decent hint that there may already be much better answers that say the same thing.

There are some more tips in the FAQ, especially for handling audits. I shamelessly recommend anyone read it if they want to do well in FP and LA.

Comment: Are you sure the answer count and question age are displayed accurately in first post audits? If I recall correctly, they are not.

Comment: @TinyGiant: The *answer* age is not shown correctly, but the question age is. IIRC, the *answer count* is often, but not necessarily always, off by exactly one (including the answer that is actually deleted). It is never off by any more than that.