# How are audit posts selected? Should audits be more "cut and dried"?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18143073) and got banned for my trouble.  The question was asking why `var_end` is used in C++ variadic functions.  I will admit that I am no expert on variadic functions, but while the answer was poorly worded, it seemed reasonable to me.  The answer basically said that `var_end` terminates an argument list and prevents a potential stack overflow (no pun intended).  The answer was closed as VLQ.  This does not seem like a "cut and dried" audit failure to me.

While this particular answer may have been wrong (although it could have just been poorly worded), it was not obvious spam, a non-answer nor a link-only answer. Are queue reviewers expected to be experts in every nuance of every programming language? Should we get banned for making a judgement call?

I don't think I am robo-reviewer.  My recent review history will show that I comment, properly upvote and downvote, and edit many posts.  I did stupidly approve a link-only answer recently.  I'll admit, that was a mistake.  However, that mistake happened after passing many audits in a row.  Then I failed [this questionable review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18143073) and got banned.  I try hard to contribute to the SO community.  While my judgement may not always agree with the audit system's, I carefully read each post before I review it.

Is the audit system designed to weed out people who may have a different opinion, or it is designed to catch people who are blindly clicking through the reviews without thinking about them?  If the former, shouldn't audit questions be more cut and dry?

If I am mistaken here, please let me know why, so I can improve.  Thank you.

Comment: _Are queue reviewers expected to be experts in every nuance of every programming language?_ No, if you're unsure it'd be better to skip it, in the audit question you got, it seemed to be _wrong/nonsense_ and an answer that doesn't add much to a question asked 8 years ago hence why most people would recommend deletion

Comment: Bottom line: **if unsure, skip**. Skipping is perfectly fine. Focus on the ones you are sure you can make a positive difference.

Comment: Whilst it is better, as mentioned before, to skip when in doubt it is usefull to add that posts for review are picked by an algorithm. This is not 100% fail-proof. If you feel that the particular post is unsuited to be a review item raise a post on meta to discuss if this post should be removed or not. In this case the comments pretty much gave away that this was a poor answer.

Comment: @yivi: It's not about skipping; it's about improving the audit posts. For the audit posts that I failed I was sure of my answer and I remain sure of my answer. To the OP's point, these audit posts should be unambiguous and not be open to interpretation.

Comment: You are not mistaken that the audits should be more cut and dry, but that's very hard to achieve when they're automatically selected. That has sparked many pre-existing discussions about what to do, ranging from "get rid of audits" to suggestions on how to improve the automatic selection and even on how to make it possible to manage it to hand pick them. No real game plan really, we'll just collectively keep regarding audits with disdain.

Comment: @George - I agree that it doesn't add anything, but it indicates an issue in the audit-process. The most positive interpretation of the late answer is that it is an incomplete description where a better explanation already existed as another answer. But the auditor doesn't see the other answers.

Comment: @Luuklag The reviewer does not get to see the comments in a late review audit. I could only see the original question and the audit answer.  Had I seen the comments and the other answers, I probably would have decided differently.

Comment: This vaguely reminds me of a question I posted here a while back https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351289/i-failed-an-audit-but-why-is-my-response-considered-incorrect - though the audit I failed had a little less information in it then yours.

Comment: @TomAranda. Pro-tip: if you want to make sure you never fail another audit again, ***always*** click the little [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587128/what-exactly-is-va-end-for-is-it-always-necessary-to-call-it/47161329#47161329) to the right of the question/answer. This will open the original in a separate tab, and show you the full context. If that doesn't make it blindingly obvious what action you should take, then just skip it. This should protect you from stepping on one of these booby-trap audits which are too subjective for most users to judge consistently.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Valid point.  I normally do that when a post looks like it could be an audit, maybe I should do that every time.

Comment: That was a bad audit. I've manually lifted your ban, but as I comment below I'm not sure if there's anything we can do as moderators to remove this. I'll check.

Comment: @BradLarson.  Thank you. I will be more careful from now on.

Comment: @ekhumoro While good practice, a good audit should be one that after (passing OR failing!) the reviewer can look at the post and say "yes, I see that this action was the correct one." I think that if I'd been in Tom's shoes **and passed the audit** (e.g. by opening the original in a new tab) I'd still have been annoyed at the audit: there's no way to know that this answer is "very low quality" without being a subject matter expert (ie being able to comment, "You're wrong and here's why"). And audits shouldn't require that.

Comment: @Draco18s. The entire intention of my comment was to point out a way to protect yourself from bad audits. At present, there is no way to filter these out beforehand, so if you want to avoid review bans, extra caution is always advisable. The current example is an answer that is merely factually wrong, and should never have been flagged as VLQ. If an answer is truly VLQ, then, by definition, it should require no expert knowledge at all to flag it as such.

Comment: @Draco18s While I'm not defending this audit in particular, there's good reason for an audit to require domain knowledge: If you aren't qualified to review a post, then you **should skip it**. It's *good* to have audits testing to verify that people are skipping questions which they aren't qualified to review. However, that's not what the current audit system is intended to cover, thus this particular audit shouldn't exist.

Comment: @Makyen When I do reviews (I've done less than 200, admittedly) I will skip anything that is on a topic that I don't understand. No issues there. But there are times when a Q/A makes sense even if I don't have knowledge of that specific language or technology, as was the case here. *That's* the problem: the answer was deleted as "very low quality" which is reserved for *spam and non-answers.* Not deleted because it was a *bad* answer, but for *not being an answer at all.* And the only way to distinguish that...is very specific domain knowledge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Audits are selected automatically.  Since we still haven't managed to develop an AI as smart as the collective user base of SO, sometimes the selection algorithm will end up picking a bad audit.

The [timeline of that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47161329/timeline) is kind of interesting.  It seems that, within a few hours of being posted, it gathered three downvotes, zero upvotes, two delete votes and two comments describing it as "nonsense" and explaining why it's wrong.  It also went through [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17867578) and [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17867774) reviews,* before finally being [deleted from LQP review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17867780) four hours later.

Since then, it has been used for [three](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17995023) [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18063105) [audits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18143073), only one of which was passed.  Presumably, it was picked as an audit because it was heavily downvoted with no upvotes, flagged as a low quality post and then deleted from review.  As far as the audit selection algorithm could tell, it looked like a crap answer than almost nobody thought was worth keeping.

There *was* one "Looks OK" vote on the original LQP review from [an experienced reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002139/baum-mit-augen), which the algorithm perhaps should have taken into account.  But given the general randomness of review, if we required every audit post to have been *unanimously* deleted, I guess the pool of eligible posts might get excessively small.

(FWIW, [this FAQ post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#157172) currently claims that "bad post" audits in the first post and late answer queues would have to have been deleted by a moderator.  Obvious that's not the case here, so clearly that FAQ should be updated.)

Anyway, the problem in this case is that the answer is obviously bad (or, at least, not obviously good) *if* you're familiar with the internals of variadic functions in C, or if you read the comments under it or the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587128/what-exactly-is-va-end-for-is-it-always-necessary-to-call-it/587139#587139) that explains what `va_end()` actually does.  But [comments are not shown in review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331908/possible-bad-audit-in-late-answers-queue), and neither are other answers to the question.**  And even though reviewers are encouraged to skip posts on topics they're not familiar with, IMO we can't really expect them to only review posts on topics they're so deeply familiar with that they could catch a plausible but incorrect answer like this one.

In any case, you probably did the right thing by posting about this bad audit here on meta.  Perhaps a ♦ mod or an SE employee can do something to make that particular answer ineligible for future review audits.  (Maybe undeleting and re-deleting it might do it?)  Or maybe, just maybe, some SE developer might even be able to tweak the audit selection algorithm to be a bit stricter in what it accepts as "bad post" audits.

---

<sup>*) We don't know what the first post and late answer reviewers did, although we can tell that they did *something*, since the outcome is listed as "Reviewed".  They didn't comment, but they may have cast downvotes, and it's possible that one of them flagged the answer as low quality.  Neither of the reviewers had enough rep to cast delete votes, so they couldn't have cast the first delete vote; the second one clearly came from the LQP queue, but the first one might have been cast by one of the commenters, both of whom had enough rep for it, or by some other random passerby.</sup>

<sup>**) <plug>My [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script / browser extension does include an interface tweak that makes all (other) answers in the same thread visible in review.</plug>  Although, to be honest, I'm not 100% sure that it would've helped here, since it only loads the other answers if the review page actually claims they exist.  I'm not sure if audits lie about that or not.</sup>

Comment: Short of undeleting, I don't know that there's anything I can do as a moderator to remove this as an audit. It's being used as an audit because it had a "very low quality" flag on it that was marked as being helpful by the system when reviewers deleted it. I would have declined that flag to prevent this, but can't now that the flag has been accepted. If I undelete the post, it will remove it as an audit, but it would become an audit again if I re-deleted it. Do I allow a bad answer like that to sit around, just so it can't be an audit?

Comment: @BradLarson: That's... unfortunate. Do you know if undeleting, upvoting and re-deleting it would work?

Comment: Not sure. I'll ask. This is yet another case where [it would be nice to be able to manually remove disputed audit cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790).

Comment: Perhaps audits that have a high failure rate should be removed automatically.

Comment: @TomAranda: Perhaps. But I doubt it would've helped much in this case. Before you hit this audit, it had one pass and one fail. Statistically, that's not really enough to make this obviously a bad audit, as opposed to one that's simply doing its job of weeding out careless reviewers.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - After consulting with someone in the know, it appears that any edit committed on a post like this will remove it as an audit from First Posts and Late Answers review (the queues this was qualifying for). Just did that, so hopefully this case will go away while leaving the bad answer deleted.

Comment: An interesting detail is that the review audit on that answer that was passed had the message "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully". When I see that message, I always suspect it's an audit (since posts with that message are according to my experience almost always audits), so I open the post in a new tab to check (and therefore pass the audit). It's possible that the user who passed that audit did the same thing.

Comment: @DonaldDuck That may very well be true.  I hate to admit it, but I recently avoided failing [another audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18178776) by following the technique of checking the link before taking action.  The question seemed to be requesting an off site resource (off topic), but it got 11 up votes, so taking negative action would have failed the audit.

Comment: @TomAranda: The official view seems to be that [that technique is a feature, not a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug): if you notice something odd about a review, investigate and determine that it's an audit, then you've been paying attention and deserve to pass. Of course, I hope you downvoted that question while you were at it. (It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47187107/timeline) you did, or at least someone did.)