# Review banned after failing one audit?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

So I've just failed this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17510844) and was immediately (presumably automatically) review suspended. Now the question is whether that post has really been an issue. The answer even has a comment by the asker saying it helped. Yes, there were two links in a pretty short reply though the answer would have even been useful without them.

Was me passing this one incorrect? I'm not sure. I'm the new guy here looking to improve.

Comment: That's not an answer. If someone else comes and sees that question then all they'll see is a link to another site. That link won't solve their problem and therefore it's not an answer to the question. It should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: The link redirects them to a place that could help more though?

Comment: With that reasoning every question on here could be answered with a link to Google. No, that's not what this place is for. Stack Overflow is for questions and *answers*. Telling someone to go look somewhere else is not an answer; it's at best a helpful hint and so it belongs in a comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are never banned for failing a single audit. That almost certainly would not be fair. You are only banned after failing *multiple* audits and taking into account your previous history, as well (but I don't know the exact details and probably shouldn't be disclosing them even if I did).

It's just that the ban message only displays the most recently failed audit. Probably because that's the link the system has on hand, without having to go back and retrieve all of your recently failed audits. Furthermore, there is a character limit for that message, and when I do custom moderator-imposed bans, I frequently run into it, as I like to provide a detailed history along with specific guidance for where reviewers went wrong. An exhaustive summary of your actions just won't fit in the ban message. All you get is the proverbial straw that broke the camel's back.

In your case, you recently (within the last two days) failed both of these audits in the "Late Answers" queue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17510844
  (a link to where an answer *might* be found)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17502267
  (an attempt to comment on another answer)

You *should* have also failed all of the following reviews:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17502794 (since edited by Pang)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17502069
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17502004
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17502884
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17489985

All of these answers *desperately* needed to be edited, yet you indicated "No Action Needed". These didn't lead directly to your ban—since they weren't audits, the system didn't know that you chose incorrectly—however, users who are banned based on failing audits almost always have made other incorrect reviews. That's kind of the point.

An edit to fix the formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17490242) would have also been appropriate, but not *required* as in the previously cited cases.

You also made the wrong decision [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17503059), since (A) the answer did not answer the question that was asked, and (B) it was [plagiarized from an external source without attribution](https://www.slideshare.net/EdurekaIN/spring-framework-tutorial-spring-tutorial-for-beginners-with-examples-java-framework-edureka).

[This review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17491942) was also incorrect. The answer was little more than a link to another question on Stack Overflow. If the question is answered by another Q&A, then it is a duplicate and should be flagged as such. Although Bradzer did try and summarize the information so it wasn't *only* a link, they failed to provide proper attribution to the person/people whose answer(s) they were summarizing, so this runs afoul of our [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), and thus needed to be flagged for removal. You probably *also* should have checked to see if the question was a duplicate of the linked question, and if so, flagged accordingly. This isn't strictly *required*, since the review was just on the answer, but diligent reviewers will also deal with the question when appropriate (like when it is attracting spam/recommendation answers, or in this case, when someone obviously thought it was a duplicate).

And that's just your history from the last two days in the "Late Answers" review queue. Each queue maintains a separate per-user history, and I didn't want to take any more time digging through this, as I see no evidence that your ban was unwarranted. (Although, to be fair, you have made many *correct* reviews, too.)

While you're banned from reviewing, take some time to [review our detailed guidance on reviewing Late Answers and First Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts). Please ask follow-up and clarification questions, if necessary. Bans aren't meant to be punitive; they're meant to be educational (and to put a temporary stop to unhelpful reviews).

---

> [The link redirects them to a place that could help more though?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357343/review-banned-after-failing-one-audit/357346#comment518886_357343)

is [*textbook* "not an answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). It's a sign pointing to where the answer/apples can be found, not *itself* an answer/apple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply, I'll take some time to read through everything again. I might also stop doing late answers in general because it's the one I'm mostly the least confident in reviewing. Also I noticed it may have become a habit to use "No action necessary" as a default option sifting through my reviews myself (maybe because I'd hit flag limits on non-Answers before) which is something that would definitely need work. Thanks again for taking the time out of your day to read through what seems like all of my reviews.

Comment: The default action should be "Skip". There's no shame in skipping when you're unsure. "No Action Needed" is only for when you're *confident* that it's a good answer. You're welcome for the advice, though. We *need* community members to help us review, and I try to do everything I can to help them. @LW001

Comment: I've seen you reply on literally every meta post on that I could find, I've noticed that. Fact is I'm aware and was aware of skipping being the actual default option though sometimes my brain didn't use it which is a problem I see when looking at my reviews afterwards thinking "What on earth is OK about that"... Fact is I'll return in two days with hopefully pressing Skip more.

Comment: Yeah, great I just managed to get locked out for [one audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17537194) from LA again, guess I'll stop with that queue completely... So any single negative audit there will get me twice the days timeout now?