# Reviewing in help center

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-center

I recently achieved reviewing privileges and wanted to read more in-depth information about all the options and expectations. I had to come to the meta and search various posts for answers. Shouldn't this info be available at the help center?

Comment: I assume you started [here in the Help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) and [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), right?

Comment: I actually found what I was looking for here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts

Comment: I just realized there are two metas xD

Comment: Most of the help pages are shared across all sites so I'm not sure if all in-depth information that is needed to fully grasp the review queues can be in the help centre but maybe there needs to be a common link that can links to the FAQ's on each site's meta.

Comment: Help is concentrated public initial info, it's short, up to topic and it doesn't required you to read hundreds of pages to get started. Meta are discussions, you go to meta if you have additional questions, to clarify complicated/rare cases. You don't want a complete Meta to be a part of Help. So what do you request? Update of specific page content in Help? Can you add this information to the question: which page, what is wrong, what you suggest?

Comment: I'm very glad you looked for some guidance first! We have a lot of reviewers who dive in immediately.... and then run into trouble. You are showing responsibility, which gives me hope that you'll become a good reviewer. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extensive guidelines for reviewing are available as a FAQ on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/168333) .

This doesn't have to be in the Help Center. You get review privileges because you are considered an experienced user. By the time you get review privileges, most of the advice in the Help Center should be logical to you.

I for one think the review information is better as a FAQ. It wouldn't hurt, however, to link to that FAQ from the Help Center.