# Audit on plagiarism in Late Answer review queue

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I recently had [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19364622). Naturally, the comments are *not* shown prior to an action by me, so the only way I would have recognized this as plagiarism is by opening the full question. I'm fairly certain this isn't expected on *every* post, or it wouldn't even be an option.

I think it's worth pointing out that <sub>(IMO)</sub> this isn't worthy of being deleted solely for it being a primarily-code answer. It *does* provide an answer to the question at hand, and only has a small typo. I didn't try to edit it, as it's 22 days old, and I don't think such a small typo is sufficient to bump a post of that age.

Because of this, I imagine the reason this was removed is due to the blatant plagiarism, which is obvious once the full question is opened. But given the info provided at first glance, is it reasonable that this be an audit? **Audits are supposed to be obvious**. This one certainly isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Also note that audits are automatic.

Comment: I'm aware that they're automatic. That's why I'm making the case for it to be removed :)

Comment: Audits will never be removed. Having comments displayed (appear to be) good however, but it's... unfortunately, abandoned, despite getting 12 upvotes.

Comment: No, not audits in general. Just this specific one. I'm aware of how things work haha

Comment: Some audits are so insanely stupid. I got banned at some point, because I delved deeper and opened the original question outside the audit scope. Since the audit post and the original post were identical minus the name, I flagged. I got temporarily banned because the audit post and original post were the same (the author's name was blanked/different in the audit). My response? I banned reviewing from my repertoire, I'm not here to get "gotchad" by such crap. I have enough crap to deal with IRL.

Comment: see also: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/839601)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you were correct. That audit has troubled a few others as well.  There are 3 mistakes here:

1. The user decided to cast a Very Low Quality flag on finding plagiarism (or rather, a close copy with a few small changes), instead of using a custom moderator flag.
2. The Low Quality reviewers did it [wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). They saw the comment while reviewing, and deleted it because they knew it had to be deleted (as it was a copy of the other answer).
3. The audits on Late Answer queue don't show you comments. Had you seen the comment, you would perhaps have not failed it.

If any of these mistakes was not committed, that audit wouldn't have been present. The audit system is broken, and that is not new information. Any kind of audit system which you design, would have some flaws and would not cover a few edge cases. This is one of those edge cases. I have cleared the audit for now.

Comment: As an aside, how do you clear an audit?

Comment: Mind clearing my review ban? "Unfortunately" I review quite a bit, and the system doesn't take into account passed audits (to my knowledge). Any audit that is sensible I'll certainly pass.

Comment: @jhpratt for that I'll have to look into your audit history (and I'm a bit held up for that). Usually no one would be banned because of one audit failure.

Comment: @DavidPostill for those deleted by reviewers, undelete and delete. That'll clear the audit.

Comment: @BhargavRao Many thanks :)

Comment: @BhargavRao That's correct. I just got off a ban. It started because I wasn't very careful in the beginning, so now a single missed audit for me will cause a ban (essentially). It _really_ should take into account passed audits and total reviews, cause I certainly feel most of my reviews are fair. I'm certainly no robo-reviewer.

Comment: @jhpratt I drastically reduced the ban duration. That should be better now.

Comment: @BhargavRao Much better! Thanks for the understanding.