# Bad Late Answers review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Admittedly, the answer wasn't the best, and I actually did click through to the post to see if it looked like it was even related, but it *did* answer the question:

> Solved to me uninstall and reinstall egit

Obviously bad grammar and pretty short, but evidently this person had the issue, and reinstalling EGit fixed it.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/23756565

<sub>Actually, I was pretty sure this was a test when I clicked "Looks OK", since I clicked through to the post, and this post wasn't there, but I disagreed so I clicked it anyway.</sub>

Comment: _"No action needed"_, for that? Really?

Comment: Ok, so maybe I should have commented or edited.  I admit I felt a bit lazy ;).  That said, it didn't deserve a NAA

Comment: Great. The audits are doing their job: catching inattentive or lazy reviewers.

Comment: semantics. it's an audit, and you knew it was because you clicked through... disputing it doesn't really accomplish much does it?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Obviously bad grammar

You could've fixed that at least. But... There's an even bigger issue here - from the question:

> I tried various attempts to fix it :
>
> - Uninstalling EGIT from Eclipse via MarketPlace the process seems good but after restart, EGIT's still there.
> - Deleting it manually by removing it from plugins and featuresfolders as suggested on other posts.
> - Starting a fresh Eclipse install and importing git projects, the problem shows off right after the project are added.
>   ...

Uninstall/reinstall was the first thing the asker tried. The first *three out of the five* things that they tried. It didn't work. An answer saying "worked on my machine" is not only *not an answer* to that question, it's... a borderline insulting response. Now, maybe the author of that answer did something else to reset their eGit installation, but... If so, they didn't mention it. As you also noted, the answer was very *short*.

So, in addition to fixing the grammar, you could've left a comment asking the author to elaborate on what, if anything, they did differently from the asker that might've made their effort more productive. That, at least, would've given them a chance to save face (if, as is likely, *they* didn't fully read the question either).

And, of course, trying to do either of those things would've passed the audit.

Comment: Which means that you don't go on review answers blindly. Check the question too and decide from it, the quality of the post. @Cullub

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I guess I should've edited, but thanks for pointing out that the question already tried that!  I actually didn't notice that at all.  @weegee got it.