# Why is this an invalid answer, and why did I fail this review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers, late-answers, specific-audit

I selected "No Action Needed" on [this Late Answers review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24602668):

> You can try Swig ([Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Do_Go_programs_link_with_Cpp_programs)), you just need to include c headers and don't need to redefine every functions.

where Go FAQ is a live link.

The answer recommends to use one software solution that works, including C headers so it is not required to redefine every function. So the reply without the link is valid and it is a valid answer.

The link is just to help, but the answer is clear for me even without it.

It is a short answer and it is not the best one. Maybe the origin is the question itself. Maybe the question should be deleted as I understand that some people think that it has not enough information. But my issue is the answer, not the question.

Why is it not valid?

Comment: Because as @Andreas commented, ' Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.'

Comment: But it is not a Link-Only answer. In fact, without the link it is ok.

Comment: I agree with you, @David. Answer that still state what has to be done even if the link is deleted _are_ answers. With the link deleted this answer would still be an answer.

Comment: The question is not stellar. The answer is borderline NAA so I understand why it tricked you. When I take the question into account there is no value in this answer if you don't follow that link. Are you review banned due to this?

Comment: I am not banned but I need to have a criteria and I have seen many answers like that one that are ok. So it is just ti clarify myself. If it is not acceptable, next time I will recommend deletion

Comment: Remember kids, bad questions tend to generate bad answers.

Comment: Agree, but I was just checking the reply, not the question, and I want to have a clear criteria. I have some issues previously with almost Link-Only answers and depends on the moderator, they are ok or not. So the criteria should be common.

Comment: This was not the LQP queue - this is the Late Answers queue. In LA, just like in First Posts, unless the post looks *perfect*, you should probably not press "No Action Needed". This post does not look perfect - it's a single sentence with no example code or procedure description and no real elaboration, and you should have asked for the OP to improve it, if you can't do so yourself. If the post was a LQP audit, I might agree that it could be OK, but a review's approach to Late Answers should be *completely different*.

Comment: Why is this answer in the "Late Answers" queue anyway? The question is one day old and according to the help page the queue "contains answers which were posted by new users much later than when the question was asked".

Comment: @Tom Posts used for audits don't follow the same requirements that normal queue items need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't fail that audit because the answer was "link-only" and thus flaggable as "not an answer".

The post could be described as an answer, although a very poor one.

You failed the audit because you were on the "Late Answers" queue, and that queue is a bit more than a "delete or not" queue. Posts on that queue are **very** often in need of edits and/or comments (and votes).

A post like this one needs **some action** to be taken. When you say "No Action Needed", you are saying the answer should be pushed out of the review queue, making impossible that other reviewers act on the post, and depriving the answerer from valuable feedback.

If you do not feel qualified to act on a post (or simply do not want to engage for whatever reason), but the post is still not 100% fine, you should always choose "skip". Only click on "No action needed" if you are fully convinced the answer if beyond reproach and making the Internet a better place.

If you haven't read it yet: [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) is always very helpful in how to approach these review queues.

Comment: Yep. LA aint VLQ.