# Failed at FP review audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I just failed a FP review audit [review link here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25090408).

I tried to follow the [FP review guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) (below an extract of the relevant part)

> In either queue, if you see an answer that:
>
> - Looks pretty good, maybe even a little too good, especially on a question with an accepted answer already:
>
>   - **Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if it's plagiarism** (usually from the
>       accepted answer); if so:
>
>     - **Flag for ♦ intervention, and explain what it's plagiarized from**. Comment if it seems like it could be an honest mistake.

I opened the question in another tab and, since it appeared that a new user answer was copied-pasted from the accepted one, I flagged for mod intervention, reporting the reason of the flag (plagiarism).

I got the "STOP! Look and Listen" message explaining I should have leave the answer as it is.

I read in meta that this happened to other users also but **I wanted to know if in some way this audit failure could impact negatively in my review stats** (e.g. a future review ban if this will occur again). I think it would be unfair in this case, since I believe to have followed the guidelines correctly

Comment: As long as you only fail audits every so often it's fine.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25087208) last night. Reading that question (*"I used the following codes to do this, I wanted to know if these codes work well. Or should I try another way?"*), it was obvious to me that it should be closed. Apparently the community did not agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You interpreted the guidance correctly, but got confused by the audit.

There is no "new answer plagiarizing the accepted answer".

Simply the post you were shown was altered to make it look as if it were posted by a new user. But there is no other answer plagiarizing the one you got (at least on this question).

By following the link to the question, the idea is that you would have realized the answer you were shown was actually the accepted answer, was considered *good*, and didn't require any flagging.

Review items can be shown with fake details, to make sure reviewers are paying attention.

If you do not fail audits often, this won't impact in your future ability of continue reviewing, if you desire to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I've undestood the mechanics and motivation behind the fake infos, but regarding _you would have realized the answer you were shown was actually the accepted answer_ : how could you discern a copy-paste by a new user from the real accepted answer proposed by the system ?

Comment: Because the answer you were shown did not exist, and the link took you directly to an answer that did exist. Mind you, it would still be possible that it was an audit of a _known bad_ post. E.g. deleted answer for plagiarism, which you wouldn't see because have less than 10k reputation, chosen as a review audit. But the link still took you to the _existing_, not-deleted answer. But in that case flagging was moot, and since you couldn't see the post you thought was plagiarizing the accepted answer, the safest path was simply to skip.