# Should code screenshots and unformatted posts be flagged Very Low Quality?

Tags: support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, flag-ban

The **very low quality** flag says:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

But I got 6 of my **VLQ** flags declined by a moderator (and got flag banned 7 days):

**Code screenshots**:

- [How do i make open weather map API display weather 5 days of the week in javascript(Apache cordova)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532298/how-do-i-make-open-weather-map-api-display-weather-5-days-of-the-week-in-javascr)
- [Forming mongoDB query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531295/forming-mongodb-query)
- [Running Corda 3.3 in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527496/running-corda-3-3-in-docker)

I commented to explain not to use screenshots and the comments got upvoted, however it didn't trigger any edit from the author, it seems then that a comment is not sufficient.

So it seemed to me that it should be flagged so a moderator can close the question until the author improves and reopen his question.

**Severe formatting**:

- [git: patch does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply/61517749#61517749)

**Less severe formatting**:

- [Hadoop installation Issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533748/hadoop-installation-issue/61530398#61530398)
- [JS partial Text Search in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971526/js-partial-text-search-in-mongodb/61530469#61530469)

For the 3 formatting problems, it seemed to me that they should go in the Low Quality Queue so that reviewers can edit and improve the posts or recommend deletion if they can't edit so that the author himself could improve his post.

In these posts, code if written without code block, or code block is wrongly used, and that's what I see in the Low Quality Queue even is these ones are more severe than what I saw until now in the review queue.

---

So should I not flag them?
Have I used the wrong flag?
Or maybe the moderator didn't pay attention?

Comment: The VLQ flag is broken and confusing. I and others have spilled lots of virtual ink over hte years on this topic. You will almost never go wrong if you remember this: **a "very low quality" flag means "this post needs to be deleted by a moderator ASAP"**. In the cited cases, those posts were in need of an edit, not necessarily immediate deletion.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know about these 3 posts: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work) and [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing). Please note that the wording has been changed. The new "needs improvement" used to be called "should be closed..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **questions**, flag for closure, not as VLQ. This kind of thing can be handled by regular community members, do not need moderator attention.

VLQ is mostly for garbage/gibberish (think someone mashing their keyboard with their forehead repeatedly). Stuff that needs to be deleted directly, not closed so that the post author can edit their post into shape for reopening.

The kind of question you link to should be closed. Since you cannot cast close votes yet, just raise the appropriate "close" flag.

---

For **answers**, you can use that flag if the answer really needs to be deleted. The examples you linked to do not qualify. They may be poor answers, but they are not unqualified garbage that needs to be deleted ASAP.

If you believe they are poor answers, you can use your votes to express your opinion. You are also free to edit the posts so they are not so bad. Many of the issues on those answers could be fixed by third parties.

Comment: I didn't asked for moderator intervention, I flagged for the low quality queue. What's the closure flag ? Is it in `needs improvement` for questions ?

Comment: Flagging as "very low quality" is asking for moderator intervention. The closure options are now inside "needs improvement", yes.

Comment: i believe you need a bronze batch and or 3000 Rep for seeing the closure option

Comment: @nbk that's actually voting to close.  Flagging for closure is available with a much more modest reputation, I believe it is either 250 or 10.

Comment: @nbk I mention "flagging", not "voting to close". And as psubsee mentions, flagging has much more [modest requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: it is hard to tell, i don't remeber, i got bronze and could vote to close since then, but i got 3000 rep at the saem time, so i couldn't tell.

Comment: I don't have a `close` option but I can chose `need more focus` or `need details or clarity` and they are the ones that closes the question I think.

Comment: On [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029) and [Can flags send a post into the Low Quality Posts review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639) it is said that the VLQ flag sends post in the LQQ. Maybe they need to be updated if it as changed since then.

Comment: @MickaelB. The VLQ flag sends a post to the LQP queue **and** to us moderators, but by default posts with a VLQ or NAA flag are kept hidden from us for the first hour (but we can tick a checkbox to not hide such posts); your flags had been active for 5.5-6 hours each before being declined. The meaning of the VLQ flag doesn’t change either way however.