# No, I don't understand your audit. Please explain!

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

Offender: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26827589

- I checked the code
- I checked the text
- I checked the link
- I checked the dates

So what else do you want from me?

What *is* the infraction here and how should I have found out about it?

Please explain (in simple terms because obviously I do *not* understand)

---

[image]

Comment: It was judged to be spam, that user posted numerous answers that included a similar link and they were found to work for the company they were linking. Not easy to tell from a single answer. If you look at the user's profile they are currently suspended.

Comment: It was also plagiarised from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145983) which you _could_ have seen

Comment: I'm going to guess that with the exception of the link, and changing the word "count" to "tally", it's a copy and past of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145983/250725

Comment: Well, that makes it a really *terrible* audit question. This information is not available to the reviewer, telling me I did it wrong based on data I wasn't given in the first place is really stupid. By everything I was given to see, it looked fine.

Comment: @Nick Regarding the plagiarism: Since NAA/VLQ flags shouldn't be used for plagiarism, we aren't obliged to check the other answers in this thread. Plagiarism should've been mod flagged instead.

Comment: @janw I'm aware of that, but to say *"By everything I was given to see"* is just incorrect, opening the answer in another tab would've shown it's an audit, checking the posters account would've shown it's an audit, there is _plenty_ more information than just date/content/links. The recommendations to check the post and account themselves are already described in the [LA/FP guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506) under subtle stuff, I'd expect them to be there in an LQP guide as well if there were one

Comment: @Nick "Opening the answer in another tab would have shown it's an audit" is **not** good reviewing, it's simply cheating the auditing system. For good reason, because it's shitty, but it's still not good reviewing. Good reviewing means you come to the correct conclusion with the facts the reviewing tools presents you.

Comment: I get that audits have to be generated this way, but it's not optimal that the only way to be sure you're not about to fail one of these is to open everything that's put before you in a new tab. The good news is that just one single failed audit isn't going to cause much harm.

Comment: @nvoigt That only really applies if the reviewing tools are _good_, which we know they're not. The point stands that you didn't look at _all_ of the information available to you

Comment: @Nick I absolutely agree. And I want people to see that they are crap and this is a perfect example. I feel insulted when an automated system tells me I failed a test because I didn't cheat on it. That is not AI, that is AS.

Comment: Well I won't argue with that :p

Comment: @ivarni Do you know how many of those "unfortunate single bad apples" you hit when you review 11386 posts? Too many.

Comment: @nvoigt Do note that I wasn't defending the audit. I've only done a little over 6000 reviews so I've no clue on the issue.

Comment: Crap audits exist; it's a fact of life that has burned plenty of people over the years and quite some to the point where they stop reviewing. You can do a search on meta and learn quickly that you're now member of a club. They will never go away, so it is the sacrifice of the reviewer to learn to eat these situations for lunch. I suggest a thick layer of ketchup so at least you can pretend it is a bloody mess.

Comment: *"Good reviewing means you come to the correct conclusion with the facts the reviewing tools presents you."* ... No it doesn't. Good reviewing means that you consider as much information as needed to perform the correct action/decision. If the information in the review screen aren't enough to do that, then you can gather more by looking at the question and/or researching meta about rules and do's and dont's. Believing that the review screen will always provide all needed information and relying on a sub-set of the available information is "good reviewing" is nonsensical.

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question. You failed the audit for a reason, a good one. We shouldn't be encouraging spam on the site, and we need to protect the mechanisms in place which fight it.

Answer (score 19):

Yeah, this one isn't obvious unfortunately. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145983). Does it look familiar? It's the same code verbatim. This user posted a bunch of copy-paste answers and added a promotional link afterward (which is why the user is suspended).

Good audit? No. I hate contextless audits for this reason. But it's definitely spam. When in doubt, click into the answer.

Comment: It's always easy to explain it afterwards, when you *know* you have to go through it with a fine-tooth comb. What would have been my signal to actually open the context view? The only thing I have learned from all the audits is that I just have the binary choice between "total crap, delete" and "skip". Anything else is a minefield of so called "audits" that audit my willingness to cheat the system.

Comment: @nvoigt FWIW, most of the consoles SO provides to do moderation (regular and diamond) provide no context either. That's my gripe with how this is done. SO expects you to bring your own context, and the only help they give you there is the link to the post. The unwritten rule of moderation is to check the post directly, and most people learn it by grabbing the live wire and getting shocked. Not a fan and never have been.

Comment: @nvoigt - Why are you not always opening the context view?

Comment: @SecurityHound Why would I? If I *should always* open the full view, why have the review view at all? Why not load the full view by default?

Comment: @nvoigt - You are aware of the short comings of the review process.  That is the primary reason.

Comment: @nvoigt "Why have the review view at all?" Indeed, good question. I never use it. Not in review, and not when handling moderator flags. It serves as nothing more than a list of flags for me. I always click through to the post. Context is very important to making the right decision, and just as important is me getting to use an interface I'm already more comfortable/familiar with. For what it's worth, when this spam was first brought to my attention in another capacity, I also missed that it was spam, because I evaluated it out of context. It was a whole mess I made that I then had to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this one was not an obvious one, but I think it makes it a good audit actually. You are the reviewer. Someone or something pushed that post into the review. Your role is to find out why.

If the information you are presented with does not help you understand the context, then open it in another tab and review other answers. Maybe other answers hold a key as to why this post was flagged.

This is exactly what I have originally done when we encountered this post. The system identified it as spam, and it was less than obvious, but after I checked other answers it became obvious to me that this is a spammer who copies other answers and adds a link at the end. When you check even further you would notice that they are affiliated with the site.

Try to always be as thorough as possible and don't rush through the reviews.