# Should one skip or flag if they suspect either plagiarism or audit question?

Tags: discussion, flags, review-audits, plagiarism

**Background**
So, I was evaluating a ‘First Answer’ on SO. The answer looked acceptable (rather good, in fact). But when I checked the link to the post and I noticed that the post had an identical answer provided by a different user. This made me think “Either I am being audited or this is ‘First Answer’ is plagiarism.” I decided to flag the post, asking for moderator intervention (which is consistent with the advice in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts/288506#288506) post. In the text of my flag I described my dual suspicions. Moments later I was notified I failed the audit.

**Question**
For me it would feel kind of dirty to do nothing about possible plagiarism. When I saw the different usernames, I was aware that this might just be an audit, but I wasn’t confident that I could be sure that it was not an audit. Was it a mistake for me to ‘flag’ in this case? Like, does this sound like a ‘when in doubt, skip’ case? Or should one err on side of flagging possible plagiarism? What’s the better practice?

Comment: [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Comment: These are the worst kinds of audits IMO, you check the question for plagiarised answers, find one, flag the review as such and then fail because you attempted to flag the very post you thought was being plagiarised. This is why I started abusing the vote breakdown to quickly check for audits in FP/LA and no longer review either queue.

Comment: Maybe a helpful tip: if you click the "link" link from the review, it should jump directly to the post... and for already deleted answers, the link won't jump to anywhere (for those who don't have the privilege to see deleted posts)... // relevant feature request: [Show a message if directly accessing a deleted answer or comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251236/241919).

Comment: A link to the audit would be helpful, as it can then be disabled from being used in further audits (as seems appropriate if I understand your post correctly). But I think moderators will be able to find it from your review history, by themselves.

Comment: So you didn't wonder at all that the answer you were reviewing didn't exist under the question? Isn't that the most obvious sign that this review is an audit?

Comment: Another way to find out if it's an audit or not is to do a search for the user, and then see if they wrote that answer. If you're not sure what the correct thing is to do, then skip.

Comment: plagiarism assumes there are _two_ (maybe partially) identical answers - first is original one and second is a copy. So, you clicked into the question and did not notice that there is indeed no copy of the suspected plagiarised answer?

Comment: @gnat No. I did look through the whole list of answers twice. And I did not see it. This is why I suspected it might be an audit question. The copy I saw was in the "First Answer" feed. My motivation for flagging the question was I was not confident in which of two suspicions was correct, and I erred on the side of flagging because I reasoned that a moderator could sort it out.

Comment: @Tom No. I did wonder about that. Have a look at may reply to gnat, as I think it was the same question.

Comment: this is common mistake, relying on a moderator sorting it out. Moderators don't have time to dig through vague suspicions, nor they are expected to. Next time, flag when you have something tangible and visible, something you can point finger at and tell "there seem to be something wrong here because of <reasons that can be understood by a moderator". If don't feel confident, right action is pointed in the very first comment here, [Skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403283/should-one-skip-or-flag-if-they-suspect-either-plagiarism-or-audit-question?noredirect=1#comment811542_403283)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You did a good investigation and that is exactly what an ideal review looks like - thanks for that.

But you should not have flagged the answer *from within the queue* because it is either

- already taken care of - if it was a real problem with the post it was likely deleted by the moderators. You would eventually be able to see deleted posts with 10K+ reputation to validate that. But before you get there you are not responsible for flagging deleted posts.
- audit - as valid answer on the site (just shown with a fake user name in review) it's should not be flagged as plagiarism from the review queue. If you find that the actual answer is really plagiarism you should flag it outside review as *the system does not yet know* that it is plagiarism/bad answer.

You can always open the actual question and flag posts there - in addition to not having problems with audit posts also not going to "disappear" (as in the review queue it always moves to the next review after completing one with a flag/edit/no action choice) as soon as you flag/edit it.

Comment: Why are you telling the user not to flag something that should be flagged? Why is the flag option present in the review queue then? The user is not the problem here.

Comment: @Myridium you should post your own answer explaining why this particular post should have been flagged as plagiarism and why that audit is wrong. If you find that my explanation of my reasoning is incomplete/unclear I'd be happy to clarify that.