# If post gets closed while reviewing, should I skip or No action needed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-post-review

I was reviewing first posts and came along one low quality post that I wanted to rise a flag for. However, this post got closed before I got to flagging, so I got popup that it was closed already. Fair enough, I clicked no action needed as it doesn't need any more actions in my opinion. But there comes the dilemma, is that correct action or should I have clicked skip instead? This is more like moral dilemma, maybe it was already asked before, I couldn't find anything.

[Here is the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27760172) if that add more info.

Comment: In case of doubt, skip is always a good option. Better to avoid dilemmas. The post is closed and your flag would be worthless, why overthink it?

Comment: "Remember: don't hit NAN if you should really be skipping!" If it got closed, it's unlikely that no action was needed.

Comment: When someone looks at that review the immediate instinct is that you did it wrong. Action was needed. It's not like the Question was posted, and no one needed to do anything. If a post is closed, you should have a "Reviewed" as an action on it or nothing at all :) If you don't want to miss out on counting it as a review at least uptick a good comment or some other "hack"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments under my post helped me to understand that my action is incorrect and why. Since others might be interested in this in future, instead of deleting I rather answer it with clarification:

The very important part I have misunderstood here is:

> No Action Needed is only if the post is fine, not if it's been marked to be handled later.

Thus No Action Needed doesn't mean there is no action to do anymore, but that the post is OK already.

[Thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) with more information, thanks @JeanneDark

Comment: so conclusion: you click **skip**. It is entirely normal if you click that button quite a lot, by the way. For all the reviews I see, probably 50% I skip because I lack the domain knowledge to be able to make a fair judgement. That's simply the default for "I'm not entirely sure what to do here..." -> SKIP!