# Is a plagiarism audit justified?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, plagiarism, specific-audit

Today I faced the following audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28321563

The question itself is one of the most popular Python question and the reply quickly summarizes what in fact a meta class is. I personally read through the answer and decided that, from a quality point of perspective, it is addressing the issue in a proper and explanative manner. ... it got declined - I failed the audit due to the reply in doubt being plagiarized from another website.

Now I wondered whether audits should include such specific cases of e.g. plagiarism. As this would imply that I would need to look up all review items on Google to find whether they have been copied from another website or not. Without any specific note like *"Check if the answer contains plagiarism."* a normal user shouldn't be expected to notice that there is something off (as it contains and addresses the question perfectly).

Is it the norm to investigate all review items as far as plagiarism is concerned? If not, is it justified that such a task is classified as an audit?

*As the question arose from the comment section: My motivation to post the question was a ban from the review queue due to this case.*

Comment: Related: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/1426539).

Comment: On Late answers checking for plagiarism is part of the deal.

Comment: @yivi *"Looks pretty good, maybe even a little too good, especially on a question with an accepted answer already"* - no, it didn't. It was a suitable and short reply, maybe just another approach to explain the topic. In these old question threads are often newer replies with basically a re-interpretation of said concept. Checking each and every one of them for plagiarism (outside of the question itself) seems like an overkill. I scrolled through the thread and didn't notice any significant plagiarized passages.. *(see your link)*

Comment: [2/2] *"Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if it's plagiarism"*. Within said question thread wasn't any plagiarism going on!

Comment: Then I guess that _'Seems relatively trite and not particularly thorough, especially if there are a number of other answers and the question is not new'_ would have applied. Which again, would have shown that the review was an audit. Opening the post in a new tab is not overkill. In many cases, is strictly necessary.

Comment: Note that I haven't voted to close your question as a dupe of the FAQ. I just offered the link in case you found it useful. It's a very good reading if one wants to spend time in either the LA or FP review queue.

Comment: @yivi See above, I mentioned that I opened the question and skimmed through it to look for any duplicates (to be fair, I didn't see the reviewed item as well - so it should have been clear that the answer has been deleted).. And yes, thanks for the link. Very useful for further reading!

Comment: FWIW, I don't see how this answer "contains and addresses the question perfectly". At least for me it feels like gibberish that makes little sense unless one already knows what it is *supposed* to convey. The last sentence seems particularly conversational, like the introduction it actually is. Did you fail the audit because the answer was plagiarism in particular, or bad in specific?

Comment: If you opened the question in a new tab, and didn't notice the answer was deleted, either you were not paying _enough_ attention, or this was a something new for you. In both cases, the audit is good because it teaches you to be more attentive to these situations.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The answer was deleted by a moderator with the comment *"plagiarized from datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-metaclasses"*, so I guess due to plagiarism.

Comment: @yivi Unfortunately, the first category. I was just skimming through the question and therefore was kinda shocked to be expected to check for plagiarism outside of SO. Didn't notice anything fishy going on (in hindsight I should have noticed the missing of said item).

Comment: Note that we are missing some temporal context here. The answer was deleted for plagiarism but also had 4 downvotes. The gap between the answer being provided and then being deleted was about 3 hours of presumably receiving downvotes. This means the answer was bad and should have been flagged as bad irrespective of whether the answer was plagiarised, so I don't think you should be expected to check for plagiarism, but I don't think this is the reason you failed the audit either

Comment: Looks like it had an unhandled spam or R/A flag. That's probably why it's in the queue

Comment: The post was spam-flagged as well as with mod attention flags. I marked the spam flag as disputed and the post should no longer be selected for audits.

Comment: “Now I wondered whether audits should include such specific cases of e.g. plagiarism.” - Honestly, it’s pretty obvious that answer was copied from an external resource, so audits should obviously contain some plagiarism examples.  You should perform any steps to avoid making the incorrect choice when performing reviews.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interesting - thanks for the information! Is there any chance that my review ban, which I received due to said (now deleted) audit, will be lifted under these circumstances?

Comment: Unfortunately, this one post wasn’t the only audit you failed to pass. The other audits also count!

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is correct, though the last audit I failed was on 16th of January. I'm still a "new player" on SO and as I gained the necessary permissions pretty quickly, I wasn't aware of the rules to a full extent and thus reviewed pretty poorly. A month has passed since then and my knowledge as far as the StackExchange (in general) is concerned has increased tremendously. I'd love to participate in further reviewing opportunities and therefore wanted to ask if my temporary ban could be lifted (considering the fact that the audit itself has been deleted as well).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should I open a new post to appeal for the ban?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I agree that checking for plagiarism from *external* (to Stack Overflow) sources *may* seem "beyond the scope" of reviewers, the Late Answers queue is a bit different from others insofar as checking for *internal* plagiarism (i.e. copies of other answers to the same question) ***should*** (IMHO) be an inherent part of the review process.

In this particular case, the review UI included the information that there were **20 other answers**; that, in itself, is a good reason to check that the new answer is not simply a copy of (or part of) one of the others. If you choose not to "Skip," then you should *always* click on the "link" link, to scan through the other answers.

Doing so in this case would have immediately revealed that it was an audit: the answer would be shown as deleted! Those with 10k reputation would have been able to see *why* it was deleted, from the comment left by a moderator:

> plagiarized from datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-metaclasses –
> Jean-François Fabre♦

However, even without seeing that comment, you would have known the review was an audit, that the answer had been deleted, and that the 'correct' course of action was to flag for deletion (any type of flag would pass the audit).

Comment: *"then you should always click on the "link" link, to scan through the other answers"* - As I mentioned above, I did. Though I wasn't paying 100% attention and just skimmed through the other answers to check for any sign of plagiarism. Apparently I missed the fact that the original answer itself couldn't be found. Thanks for your opinion on the matter! I'm happy that the particularly mentioned audit has been deleted from @Martijn Pieters though unfortunately my review ban still remains. Judging the case by "using" a weakness of the audit system itself isn't an original intention in my opinion.